# Loop não está repetindo como deveria

Tags: c#, .net, loop, lógica

Estou criando um código que lê o número digitado pelo usuário e, se for de 1 a 10, ele realiza a tabuada, apresentando valor a valor na tela, além de permitir o usuário escolher se deseja verificar alguma outra tabuada.

A primeira vez, roda tranquilamente. Entretanto, se o usuário opta por fazer uma nova consulta, o programa solicita o novo número mas não apresenta os novos valores, ficando travado no *loop* condicional.

Segue lógica utilizada por mim:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{    
    int cont = 1, valor, auxiliar, continuar = 1;

    while (continuar == 1)
    {    
        Console.WriteLine("Digite um numero de 1 a 10: ");
        valor = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());    

        if (valor <= 10)
        {
            while (cont <= 10)
            {    
                auxiliar = valor * cont;
                Console.WriteLine(valor + " X " + cont + " = " + auxiliar);    
                cont++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Deseja verificar a tabuada de algum outro número? Digite 1 para SIM ou 2 para NAO");
            continuar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Número inválido! ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É porque você inicia `cont` fora do `while` principal e não volta o valor dele pro inicial. Isso faz com que o `while` interno não seja executado, já que a condição dele é que a variável `cont` seja menor ou igual a 10.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int cont, valor, auxiliar, continuar = 1;
    while (continuar == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Digite um numero de 1 a 10: ");
        valor = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (valor <= 10)
        {
            cont = 1;
            while (cont <= 10)
            {
                 auxiliar = valor * cont;
                 Console.WriteLine(valor + " X " + cont + " = " + auxiliar);
                 cont++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Deseja verificar a tabuada de algum outro número? Digite 1 para SIM ou 2 para NAO");
            continuar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());                
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Número inválido! ");
        }
    }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no Repl.it](https://replit.com/@jfbueno/ptso220540)

Answer (score 5):

Este código é pouco legível, tem variáveis demais, e elas estão declaradas muito antes de serem usadas o que complica o entendimento levando a erros.

Na verdade tem várias coisas que pode ser melhorado nele, inclusive é uma situação clara para usar um `for` e não um `while`.

Já que está fazendo verificações se a digitação está correta, faça por inteiro, e se alguém digitar algo que não seja um número? No momento seu código irá quebrar. Não. basta testar se o código funciona. Tem que estar o que não funciona, isto é muito mais importante. Use um [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).

Também modernizei o código. A maioria do material que ensina por aí está obsoleto, então aprenda fazer do jeito que se faz hoje.

Dá pra melhorar mais.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {    
        int continuar = 1;
        while (continuar == 1) {    
            WriteLine("Digite um numero de 1 a 10: ");
            int valor;    
            if (int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out valor) && valor >= 1 && valor <= 10) {
                for (int cont = 1; cont <= 10; cont++) WriteLine($"{valor:D2} X {cont:D2} = {valor * cont:D2}");
                WriteLine("Deseja verificar a tabuada de algum outro número? Digite 1 para SIM ou 2 para NAO");
                if (int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out continuar)) continuar = 2;
            } else {
                WriteLine("Número inválido! ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9eG82X). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/brssom). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/MutiplicationTabale.cs).

Comment: Você saberia algum lugar onde eu possa aprender desse jeito utilizado nos dias de hoje?

Comment: Nada em lugar central, é ir acompanhando, perguntando aqui. Eu estou pensando em escrever um livro sobre isto.

Comment: Seria de grande contribuição para a comunidade, com certeza.
Entretanto, você poderia me explicar essa linha:
WriteLine($"{valor:D2} X {cont:D2} = {valor * cont:D2}");

Comment: @MateusBinatti aqui não cabe, faça uma nova pergunta mostra isso e dizendo o que não entendeu.