# Como usar if else no código abaixo

Tags: c#, if, else

Iniciando eu digito o id do artista e os demais dados, depois vou digitar o id do reparador, eu preciso que ao digitar o id do reparador, se for igual ao do artista ele não deve aceitar e pedir outro id, consegui fazer uma parte, mas ele não pede outro id e vai direto para o nome.

```
Console.WriteLine("Digite o ID do artista:");
int idArtista = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Digite o nome do artista:");
string nomeArtista = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Digite o sobrenome do artista:");
string sobrenomeArtista = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Digite o ID do reparador:");
int idReparador = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
bool condição = true;
if (idArtista == idReparador)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Id existente.");
}
if (!condição)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Digite o ID do reparador:");
}

Console.WriteLine("Digite o nome do reparador:");
string nomeReparador = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Digite o sobrenome do reparador:");
string sobrenomeReparador = Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua lógica, no bloco abaixo, não faz nenhum sentido.

```
bool condição = true;  // <- condição recebe o valor 'true'
if (idArtista == idReparador) // <- Aqui é comparado se os ids são iguais, certinho
{
    Console.WriteLine("Id existente."); // <- mostrar a mensagem. Certo!
}
if (!condição) // <- Chechar se condição é 'false', mas como poderia ser????
{
    Console.WriteLine("Digite o ID do reparador:");// <- Pede pelo ID, mas não lê a entrada
}
```

O código deveria ser algo assim:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Digite o ID do artista:");
    int idArtista = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Digite o nome do artista:");
    string nomeArtista = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Digite o sobrenome do artista:");
    string sobrenomeArtista = Console.ReadLine();

    int idReparador;

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Digite o ID do reparador:");
        idReparador = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if(idArtista == idReparador)                
            Console.WriteLine("Id existente.");            
    }
    while(idArtista == idReparador); 
    // (^) Repetir o passo acima sempre que os ids forem iguais

    Console.WriteLine("Digite o nome do reparador:");
    string nomeReparador = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Digite o sobrenome do reparador:");
    string sobrenomeReparador = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YkJXhc)

Answer (score 3):

Não é bem `if` que tem que usar, é `while` já que a pessoa pode digitar errado várias vezes, então tem que repetir até estar de acordo com o desejado.

Além disto tem um outro problema, se a pessoa digitar algo que não é um número e não puder ser convertido dará um erro, isto precisa ser tratado também. Fiz com o [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) que é o mais correto.

Aproveitei para modernizar o código e deixá-lo mais conciso.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var idArtista = 0;
        while (true) {
            WriteLine("Digite o ID do artista:");
            if (int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out idArtista)) break;
        }
        WriteLine("Digite o nome do artista:");
        var nomeArtista = ReadLine();
        WriteLine("Digite o sobrenome do artista:");
        var  sobrenomeArtista = ReadLine();
        var  idReparador = 0;
        while (true) {
            WriteLine("Digite o ID do reparador:");
            if (int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out idReparador) && idArtista != idReparador) break;
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando **ideone**](https://ideone.com/zy4iMH). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z7GWtm). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/Validation.cs).

Se quiser manter a mensagem de erro mude para:

```
        while (true) {
            WriteLine("Digite o ID do reparador:");
            if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out idReparador) continue;
            if (idArtista == idReparador) {
                WriteLine("Id existente.");
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Nossa, muito bem lembrado. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.