# Verificar se existe valor na enumeração pelo atributo e retornar seu valor

Tags: c#, .net, reflexão, enums, atributos

É possível produzir um código mais simples para essa função sem alterar o `enum`?

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public enum Velocidade
{

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("01")]
    Baixa,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("02")]
    Normal,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("03")]
    Rapida,

}
```

Abaixo um método para verificar se o valor existe:

```
private bool EnumHasValue(Type pTipoDoEnum, string valorDoEnum)
{

    foreach (var val in Enum.GetValues(pTipoDoEnum))
    {
        var member = pTipoDoEnum.GetMember(val.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
        var attribute = member.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<XmlEnumAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (valorDoEnum == attribute.Name)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

No método abaixo o valor correspondente à `string` é encontrado

```
private object EnumFromString(Type pTipoDoEnum, string valorDoEnum)
{

    foreach (var val in Enum.GetValues(pTipoDoEnum))
    {
        var member = pTipoDoEnum.GetMember(val.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
        var attribute = member.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<XmlEnumAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (valorDoEnum == attribute.Name)
        {
            return val;
        }                
    }
    throw new Exception("Não existe o valor " + Text + " para o tipo " + pTipoDoEnum.ToString() + ". Utilize o método EnumHasValue antes da conversão.");
}
```

Aqui está como o método é chamado:

```
string text = "02";

Velocidade velocidade = new Velocidade();
if (EnumHasValue(typeof(Velocidade),text)) velocidade = (Velocidade)EnumFromString(typeof(Velocidade), text);

// O resultado é: "Normal"
textBox1.Text = "O resultado é: \"" + velocidade.ToString() + "\"";
```

Comment: Será que um simples e objetivo método de extensão já não resolveria?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

A primeira grande mudança é tornar o método genérico e não vazar abstração.

Outra mudança é que eu juntaria os dois métodos em um só usando tuplas evitando exceções, mudanças entre a verificação e o uso, fora a duplicidade de código. Só pode usar o nome de o booleano for verdadeiro, caso contrário ele é inválido. Fiz isto porque o uso indicava que esta era a intenção.

Não entendi algumas coisas deste código, inclusive fazer um *loop* dentro de outro *loop* para varrer os mesmos dados. Então simplifiquei isto.

Fiz uma validação porque o que for passado pode não ser uma enumeração. Pena que o C# não deixa restringir isto no código em tempo de compilação. Aí faz sentido ser exceção porque é erro de programação. Nunca capture ela.

Fui direto nos membros do tipo e não na enumeração para simplificar.

Melhorei os nomes das variáveis e do próprio método.

Também usei *pattern matching*.

Simplifiquei outras coisas.

Eu faria assim:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        (var ok, var nome) = EnumFromXmlAttribute<Velocidade>("02");
        if (ok) WriteLine($"O resultado é: \"{nome}\"");
        (ok, nome) = EnumFromXmlAttribute<Velocidade>("05");
        if (ok) WriteLine($"O resultado é: \"{nome}\"");
    }
    private static (bool, T) EnumFromXmlAttribute<T>(string texto) {
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (!type.IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException("O tipo precisa ser uma enumeração");
        foreach (var item in type.GetFields())  {
            if (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(item, typeof(XmlEnumAttribute)) is XmlEnumAttribute attribute && texto == attribute.Name)
                return (true, (T)item.GetValue(null));
        }
        return (false, default(T));
    }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public enum Velocidade {
    [XmlEnumAttribute("01")] Baixa,
    [XmlEnumAttribute("02")] Normal,
    [XmlEnumAttribute("03")] Rapida,
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enum/GetAtributtes.cs). Como usa recursos mais novos, esses IDEs *online* não compilam este código, por isto não postei, mas testei no VS e está ok.

Se não quiser usar tupla pode usar um parâmetro `out`, assim como é em um [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101). Também pode tirar o *pattern matching* e tornar o código mais verboso, só não acho que faça sentido evitar essas coisas mais.

Comment: Valeu Maniero, fiz algumas alterações mas funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado