# Como pegar todas as propriedades públicas de uma classe na ordem que foram declaradas em VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, estrutura-de-dados

Estou criando uma biblioteca para validar o SPED Fiscal em VB.NET e para agilizar o processo de criação das linhas, cada classe já tem seus atributos pré-definidos e na ordem conforme a documentação, como está no exemplo abaixo:

```
' REGISTRO 0001: ABERTURA DO BLOCO 0
Public Class Registro0001

    ' Texto fixo contendo “0001”. 
    Public Shared reg As String = "0001"

    ' Indicador de movimento:
    '   0- Bloco com dados informados;
    '   1- Bloco sem dados informados.
    Public indMov As String = ""

    ' construtor
    Public Sub New(_reg As String, _indMov As String)
        reg = _reg
        indMov = _indMov
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"|{reg}|{indMov}|"
    End Function

End Class
```

Existe alguma forma de que eu possa pegar todas as propriedades que existirem dentro da classe na ordem que foram declaradas e e usar o conteúdo instanciado nelas dentro do meu método `ToString()`?

Estava pensando em algo perto [disso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531384/how-to-loop-through-all-the-properties-of-a-class) mas não consigo entender como.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nada a garante a ordem, então não pode fazer isso.

Se quiser muito, pode usar um atributo definindo a ordem manualmente e pegar esse valor em cada propriedade para usar como chave de classificação.

Na verdade quase sempre quando começa fazer isto C# não é a linguagem adequada para o problema. Ainda que eu ache que é, mas feito de outra forma. Tanto que não vejo agilização alguma nisso, pelo contrário, a performance sofrerá.

Você precisa aprender sofre reflexão e atributos:

- [O que são esses atributos nas propriedades?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44900/101)
- [Verificar se existe valor na enumeração pelo atributo e retornar seu valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/242632/101)
- [O que são metadados no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107111/101)
- [Como criar um Custom Attribute?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119024/101)
- [Reflection C#, como funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154462/101)

Comment: Há algo errado na resposta?