# GetProperties() exceto as NotMapped

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho um método que busca todas as propriedades do meu modelo, porém não gostaria de trazer as entidades que têm como `DataAnnotation` o `attribute` `NotMapped`.

Método

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetColumns()
{
    return typeof(T)
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(e => e.Name != "Id" && !e.PropertyType.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType)
            .Select(e => e.Name);
}
```

Modelo:

```
using LaioMVC.Core.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace LaioMVC.Core.Models
{
    public class Usuario : EntityBase
    {
        [Required]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Login { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [Required]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Algo assim? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/242745/101. De onde vem esse `T`?

Comment: Sim é isso mesmo, esse T vem da minha classe dona do método GetColumns() que é genérica. No caso seria o tipo da minha entidade dona das propriedades.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Verificar se existe valor na enumeração pelo atributo e retornar seu valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/242632/verificar-se-existe-valor-na-enumera%c3%a7%c3%a3o-pelo-atributo-e-retornar-seu-valor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como não foi postado tudo da classe eu fiz sem ser genérico, mas a questão aí é filtrar por atributo então seria isto:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        foreach (var c in GetColumns()) WriteLine(c);
    }
    private static IEnumerable<string> GetColumns() => typeof(Usuario).GetProperties()
            .Where(e => e.Name != "Id" && !(Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(e, typeof(NotMappedAttribute)) is NotMappedAttribute))
            .Select(e => e.Name);
}

public class Usuario {
    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Required]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bJTe1x).Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/FilterProperties.cs).