# Como limitar casas decimais usando C#?

Tags: c#, .net, formatação, arredondamento

Eu estou com alguma dificuldade em limitar as casas decimais em C#.

```
double x = 1,41293
```

Eu queria fazer o output só de `1.412` já testei o seguinte código:

```
Convert.ToDecimal(x).ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

e

```
Convert.ToDecimal(x).ToString("N3", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: troque a virgula por ponto: `double x = 1.41293`

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Não posso fazer isso , por isso é que eu uso CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Comment: isso é do C#, que assim como outras linguagens de programacao utilizam o . como separador decimal, inclusive essa primeira linha, dará erro de compilação, a menos que seja uma string

Comment: Mas eu não consigo mudar esse ponto

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se for uma string, com vírgula como separador decimal, coloque o `CultureInfo` no `Convert`:

```
decimal x = Convert.ToDecimal("1,41293", new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));

Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("N3"));    //Resultado: 1.413
```

Se for necessário, a saída também com separador decimal a vírgula, coloque o `CultureInfo` no `ToString()`:

```
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("N3", new CultureInfo("pt-BR") ));   //Resultado: 1,413
```

Comment: Mas assim vou obter o output de 1.41293 , eu preciso de obter só os primeiros 3 numeros  ou seja 1.412

Comment: o output está sendo 1.413 ou 1,413

Answer (score 3):

A pergunta é um pouco confusa e o código base que está escrito nem compilaria porque não existe sintaxe para parte decimal com vírgula. Eu vou tentar adivinhar o que está querendo.

Se quer só "imprimir" com 3 casas decimais já foi passado:

```
x.ToString("N3")
```

Se realmente quer limitar em 3 casas e manter o tipo `double` entenda que este tipo não tem exatidão, então não é possível achar um valor com 3 casas em todas as situações. Mas se quiser insistir nisso multiplique por 1000, pegue o inteiro e depois divida por 1000 novamente, ou seja, é pura matemática. Use o método `Round()` já existente que é bem mais fácil, [consulte a documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397):

```
Round(x, 3)
```

Se quer preservar realmente as 3 casas em qualquer situação aí só convertendo para `decimal`:

```
Round(ToDecimal(x), 3)
```

E finalmente se na verdade tem uma `string` com o número com a vírgula precisa converter para `decimal` antes de usar. E precisa fazer isto verificando se a conversão deu certo, porque se tem um valor assim, nada garante que ele veio certo, então não pode confiar se a conversão foi feita, tem que usar [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101):

```
if (!decimal.TryParse("1,41293", Number, new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), out var numero)) return;
WriteLine(Round(numero, 3));
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/bt0Y6G). E [no **repl.it**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nWDKp7). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/Decimal2.cs).

Answer (score 0):

*Boa Noite aconselho receber o valor direto e tratar na saída.*

> double x = 1.41293

```
 Console.Writeln("X={0;f3}",x);
 // f3 --> formatação de saída para float com 3 casas
```

*Espero ter ajudado*