# Casas decimais c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, decimal, number-format

tenho uma variavel do tipo decimal me retornando o valor `270.61864847349717630804948048` como faço pra retornar com somente 3 casas após a virgula, no caso passar `270.618` somente.

Desde já agradeço

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como limitar casas decimais usando C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243124/como-limitar-casas-decimais-usando-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode:

**Manter o valor, só mudar a exibição:**

```
decimal x = 270.61864847349717630804948048M;

Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("N3"));
```

> Resultado: *270.619*

**Arredondar o valor:**

```
decimal y = Math.Round(x,3);

Console.WriteLine(y.ToString());
```

> Resultado: *270.619*

**Ou Truncar o valor:**

```
decimal z = Math.Truncate(x * 1000)  / 1000;     //1000 para 3 casas decimais   

Console.WriteLine(z.ToString());
```

> Resultado: *270.618*

Coloquei no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8hyLoX)

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo, utilizei o Math.Round(x,3)