# Como limitar casas decimais em C#

Tags: c#, .net, formatação

Fiz uma aplicação para calcular a média aritmética de 3 notas. Meu formulário tem 3 TextBox que recebe a nota e um botão que calcula a média. O resultado é imprimido em um Label, como faço para limitar a quantidade de números após a ","?

```
 private void btnCalcular_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //DECLARAÇÃO DE VARIÁVEIS
        double num1, num2, num3, resultado;

        //CONVERSÃO DE STRING PARA DOUBLE
        num1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtN1.Text);
        num2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtN2.Text);
        num3 = Convert.ToDouble(txtN3.Text);

        //OPERAÇÃO DE CÁLCULO
        resultado = (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3;

        lblResult.Text = resultado.ToString();

        lblResult.Text = resultado.ToString();

        if (resultado >= 6)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Aluno aprovado!", "Status do aluno", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Aluno reprovado", "Status do aluno", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/290894/casas-decimais-c

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa formatar o texto a ser usado, não pode usar de forma direta, assim para duas casas:

```
$"{resultado:0.##}"
```

Mas se quiser mudar o valor e não só aprender, o que não é o que o código faz agora, aí teria que manipulá-lo (e pode dar um valor diferente do que deu na formatação, então tem que decidir qual é a melhor estratégia para seu cenário). Seria algo como:

```
Round(resultado, 2)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/smHdQ1). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7G0QW6). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/FormatDecimalPlaces.cs).

Tem outros problemas no código, ainda que funcione.