# Algoritmo recursivo não funciona

Tags: c#, algoritmo

Tenho que resolver um exercício, e nele diz:

> Faça um procedimento que receba um número n inteiro e positivo. O
>   procedimento deve imprimir todos os números do intervalo entre 0 e n
>   que são divisíveis por 2 e por 3 (simultaneamente).

Estou iniciando no momento, e tenho pouca bagagem em estrutura de dados. Eu desenvolvi o código abaixo, porém não me retorna os números que são divisíveis.

```
using System;

namespace revisao
{
class Program
    {               
        static void Imprimir(int[] vet, int indice)
        {               
            if (indice > 0 && indice < vet.Length)
            {
                if((vet[indice] % 2 == 0) && (vet[indice] % 3 == 0))
                {
                    Console.Write("{0,3}", vet[indice]);    
                    Imprimir(vet, indice + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("Números não divisíveis por 2 e 3 simultaneamente!");
                }
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i, tamanho;

            Console.Write("Digite o tamanho do vetor: ");
            tamanho = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int[] vetor = new int[tamanho];

            for(i = 0; i < vetor.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Digite o elemento {0}: ", i);
                vetor[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            Imprimir(vetor, i);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Melhorei algumas coisas para o código ficar mais no estilo do C#. Também resolvi alguns outros problemas que o código tinha que não estão no enunciado, mas se não tratar ele dá erro. Por falta de uma definição específica quando algo é digitado errado assumi o que eu quis para resolver.

Acho que a dificuldade é a função recursiva que o enunciado não pede e não há necessidade de uso aí. Este não é um caso claramente recursivo, ele é sequencial, então um laço é mais interessante.

Se estiver usando uma versão antiga tem que declarar a variável `tamanho` fora da função [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) antes de usar.

```
using static System.Console;

namespace revisao {
    public class Program {   
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            Write("Digite o tamanho do vetor: ");
            if (int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var tamanho)) {
                int[] vetor = new int[tamanho];
                for(int i = 0; i < vetor.Length; i++) {
                    Write($"Digite o elemento {i}: ");
                    vetor[i] = int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var valor) ? valor : 0;
                }
                Imprimir(vetor);
            }
        }
        private static void Imprimir(int[] vetor) {
            WriteLine("Valores divisíveis por 2 e 3 simultaneamente");
            foreach (var item in vetor) if (item % 6 == 0) WriteLine($"{item}");
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VbiMjH). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pd8UeB). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/Divisibles.cs).

Answer (score 1):

Pede-se que se imprima os números de 0 a `n`, `n` fornecido, que sejam divisíveis por 2 e 3 simultaneamente. Como o @Maniero percebeu, precisa ser múltiplo de 6.

Como a questão não fala nada em armazenar em um vetor, nem em entradas posteriores, só há uma leitura para cada instância do problema. Esse é o ponto que fiquei insatisfeito com a resposta dele e também com a tentativa do resposta do AP.

Como o número inicial é 0, e 0 por ser elemento absorvente no anel dos inteiros é múltiplo de todos os outros números, basta começar de 0 e incrementar de 6 em 6 unidades até chegar em `n` (estou assumindo intervalo aberto em `n`). Tomando por base o código do Maniero:

```
using static System.Console;

namespace revisao {
    public class Program {   
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            Write("Digite n: ");
            if (int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var n)) {
                WriteLine("Valores divisíveis por 2 e 3 simultaneamente");
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 6) {
                    WriteLine($"{i}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

São impressos apenas os múltiplos de 2 e 3 simultaneamente.

A função recursiva para isso seria meio tosca:

```
public static void imprimeRecursivo(int atual, int n) {
    if (atual < n) {
        WriteLine($"{atual}");
         imprimeRecursivo(atual + 6, n);
    }
}
```

A primeira chamada precisa passar como `atual` 0.

Se você quiser transformar em uma recursão de cabeça, só vai precisar de um parâmetro:

```
public static void imprimeRecursivoCabeca(int i) {
    if (i >= 0) {
        imprimeRecursivoCabeca(i-1);
        if (i % 6 == 0) {
            WriteLine($"{i}");
        }
    }
}
```

Se quiser o intervalo aberto em `n`, o primeiro parâmetro é `n-1`. Note que ele vai convergir até 0, onde então vai começar a retornar das recursões, imprimindo em ordem crescente os números múltiplos de 6 encontrados.