# Como substituir a vírgula de um número por ponto?

Tags: c#, .net, formatação, ponto-flutuante

Eu queria saber como posso substituir a virgula para um ponto final.

Por exemplo, tenho o seguinte número: 2,32. Queria que ficasse 2.32.

Como posso fazer isso?

Já tentei usar o `ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`, mas mesmo assim não alterou.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
double x = 2.32;
string texto = x.ToString("N", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

Referência: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8ztz0sa(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: mas assim o numero não vai ficar com "." ?

Comment: foi o que pediu, trocar a virgula por ponto

Answer (score 3):

Se você tem `2,32` então tem uma *string*. Números não possuem formatação, eles apenas expressam uma quantidade, não há ponto ou vírgula, só uma indicação que há parte decimal, quando você imprime o valor em algum lugar aí está vendo um texto formatado que representa a quantidade existente. Se tem vírgula é um texto formatado que mostra o que seria um número em uma notação específica, no caso a que usamos no Brasil.

Ao que tudo indica está trabalhando com valor monetário, ou mesmo algo que precisa de exatidão, então não pode usar `double`, veja mais em [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101). Se não for o caso, então não teria problemas.

Não use `replace()` para trocar a pontuação que deseja, isto é gambiarra, e em muitos casos não funciona como espera.

Antes de formatar como deseja precisa ter um número, depois formatar com a cultura específica, pode ser a americana, ao que tudo indica. Eu vou usar um `Parse()` porque estou considerando que você pode [garantir o formato que está e não vai dar erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).

Não esquece de dizer quantas casas decimais deseja que apareça, caso contrário, em alguns casos não obterá o que deseja, então use `N2` ou algo assim, veja as [formatações possíveis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Usei a cultura de forma simples, [veja a classe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Globalization;
                    
var texto = "2,32";
var valor = decimal.Parse(texto, new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));
var formatado = valor.ToString("N2", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
WriteLine(formatado);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aUZvrn). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Culture/DecimalBrToUs.cs).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o método `String.Replace(string1, string2)` ou `String.Replace(char1, char2)`, no 1 você coloca o que deseja retirar, e no 2 o que deseja adicionar, exemplo:

```
string num = 2,32
num = num.Replace(',','.');
```

Answer (score -3):

Quando você utiliza o **ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)**, logo após é necessário usar o namespace

> using System.Globalization;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]