# Converter String para double em Java

Tags: java, conversão-de-tipo

Eu estou lendo dados de um arquivo externo com o formato CSV. Porém esses dados estão vindo em formato de `String`. Existe um campo preço que eu preciso transformar em `double` para fins de manipulação.

Classe `Catalogs`

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Catalog {

private ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

public ArrayList<Product> getProducts() {
    return products;
}

public void setProducts(Product p) {
    products.add(p);
}


public ArrayList<Product> showProducts(){
    for(Product prod : products){
        System.out.println("id:"+ prod.getId());
        System.out.println("Price:"+ prod.getPrice());
    }

    return getProducts();
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\casa\\Desktop\\catalog.csv");
    String line = new String();
    Product p = new Product();
    Catalog c = new Catalog();

    try {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
        while(reader.hasNext()){
            line = reader.nextLine();

            String[] value = line.split(",");

            p.setId(value[0]);
            p.setPrice(value[1]);

            c.setProducts(p);

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    c.showProducts();
}

}
```

Classe Products

```
public class Product {
private String id;
private double price;
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(String p) {
    double price = Double.parseDouble(p);
    this.price = price;
}
}
```

Eu tentei usar o método `parseDouble()`pra transformar o atributo quando ele setado pelo método `setPrice`, porém ocorreu o seguinte erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input 
string: ""price""
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at Product.setPrice(Product.java:16)
at Catalog.main(Catalog.java:41)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A função está correta. Você pode utilizar tanto [Double.parseDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-), quanto [Double.valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-), porém ambos os métodos irão retornar a exceção [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) caso a *string* seja inválida, por exemplo, usando vírgula ao invés de ponto flutuante.

Por exemplo:

```
┌─────────────────────────────┬──────────┐
│ Double.valueOf("2");        │ Válido   │
├─────────────────────────────┼──────────┤
│ Double.valueOf("2.5");      │ Válido   │
├─────────────────────────────┼──────────┤
│ Double.valueOf("2.59");     │ Válido   │
├─────────────────────────────┼──────────┤
│ Double.valueOf("2.599");    │ Válido   │
├─────────────────────────────┼──────────┤
│ Double.valueOf("2,599");    │ Inválido │
├─────────────────────────────┼──────────┤
│ Double.valueOf("2.599,00"); │ Inválido │
├─────────────────────────────┼──────────┤
│ Double.valueOf("259:900");  │ Inválido │
├─────────────────────────────┼──────────┤
│ Double.valueOf("R$259");    │ Inválido │
└─────────────────────────────┴──────────┘
```

> A tabela também vale para o método Double.parseDouble()

Caso você possua caracteres inválidos em sua *string*, é necessário trata-la antes de tentar converter para *double*. Para isso você pode usar *RegEx* ou um simples `String.replace`, por exemplo:

```
String preco1 = "2,599"
    .replace("(?:[^\\d\\,])", "") //Remove todos os caracteres não numerais e nem a vírgula
    .replace(",", "");            // Substitui a vírgula pelo ponto

String preco2 = "2.599,12"
    .replace("(?:[^\\d\\,])", "")
    .replace(",", "");

System.out.println( Double.valueOf(preco1) );
System.out.println( Double.valueOf(preco2) );
```

No seu caso, você está tentando converter o valor `"price"`, e como este não é um valor numérico (com ou sem ponto flutuante), o algoritmo não consegue converte-lo.

Comment: O formato dos dados no arquivo está assim: `"4357590126397428","R$ 629.99"`, sendo que a primeira coluna é o `id` e a segunda é `price`. Eu não consegui usar o método `replace`para remover os caracteres (inclusive as aspas estão vindo junto).

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá nos problemas deste código:

- O produto não deveria receber um preço como `String` por padrão. Voc~e pode até ter um método auxiliar que faça isto como conveniência, é questionável se deveria estar na classe `Product`, mas pode ser feito como algo extra.
- Não use um preço como `double`, [este tipo não possui exatidão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101). Utilize um [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).
- A captura da exceção em `Catalog` não faz nada útil, então retire-a.
- Você adiciona um produto ao catálogo e não *seta* produtos nele. Parece bobo, mas se conceitua errado uma coisa, vai conceituar várias outras coisas. E torna o código menos intuitivo.
- O `Main()` não deveria estar nesta classe.
- Esse `split()` é bem gambiarra, mas não vou mexer nisto.
- Geralmente oque faz interação com o usuário também costuma estar fora, então `showProducts()` deveria estar em outra classe, e talvez ter outro nome. E é estranho e mostra e retornar os produtos.
- Se vai cadastrar um novo produto, crie um novo produto, o que fez não vai produzir o resultado que espera.
- O seu problema principal é poder validar a entrada de dados. [Em outra linguagem eu adotaria uma estratégia diferente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101), mas a cultura do Java é trata exceções. Não tente arrumar o dado, isto é arriscado, se a pessoa digitou errado mostre para ela que isto está ocorrendo e a ensine fazer certo, além de ser uma usabilidade melhor o risco de algo dar errado é menor.

Mais ou menos assim:

```
while (reader.hasNext()) {
    String line = reader.nextLine();
    String[] value = line.split(",");
    Product p = new Product();
    p.setId(value[0]);
    try {
        p.setPrice(value[1]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("valor digitado não é válido, tente novamente");
        continue;
    }
    c.addProduct(p);
}

private BigDecimal price;
public void setPrice(String p) {
    this.price = new BigDecimal(p);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/Conversion.java).

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver! eu adicionei essa linha de código `line = line.replaceAll("[\"R$ ]", "");` logo após a leitura de um linha do arquivo para remover todos os caracteres especiais.