# Double.valueOf(String).doubleValue()

Tags: java

Como não consegui converter uma String para Double, pois é decimal, usei Double.valueOf(String).doubleValue(). Mas ao converter uma String para Double com "." os números acima de 3 casas (1.000) não são armazenados em variável Double mesmo com o código acima, apenas números menores que (1.000) são armazenados. Como posso converter para decimal uma String para cálculos? -->campo formatado para valores monetários.

```
    Double vlprod=0.0;
    ArrayList<String> valorUnitario = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> quantidade = new ArrayList();
     if (lstProduto.isSelectionEmpty()) /*Verifica se foi selecionado um item na JList*/
           { 
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selecione um item na lista de produtos !");
           }
           else /*Se foi selecionado, pega o valor na posição do ArrayList referente ao índice da JList*/
           {
                int i= lstProduto.getSelectedIndex();
                Double vl=Double.valueOf(valorUnitario.get(i)).doubleValue();
                int qt=Integer.parseInt(quantidade.get(i));
                vlprod=Double.valueOf(vlprod+(vl*qt)).doubleValue();
                System.out.println(vlprod.toString());
           }

Erro no Console: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1914)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
```

Comment: Double.valueOf ou Double.parseDouble já fazem isso, nao entendi sua duvida. Apresente um **[mcve]** para demonstrar seu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Em tipos float e double, por padrão, o ponto(`.`) é separador decimal, e não separador de milhares. Se sua string utiliza ponto como separador de milhares, você não vai conseguir converter adequadamente para double, não sem antes aplicar algum tipo de formatação ou remover esses separadores.

Se você tem certeza de que **o ponto sempre será apenas separador de milhares**, simplesmente remova-o da string antes de converter:

```
    String str = "1.000";   
    System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(str.replaceAll("\\.", "")));
```

Veja funcionando: https://ideone.com/f6u5h2

Se você não te como garantir isso, edite a pergunta e apresente exemplos dos tipos de números que pode ocorrer na sua aplicaçao.

---

**Sugestão de leitura:**

- [Converter String para double em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/283662/28595)
- [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/219774/28595)

Comment: (Double.parseDouble(str.replaceAll("\\.", "")) só não funcionou pois os valores que tem de armazenar são monetários, quando se digita "0.50" (cinquenta centavos) ele se torna "50.0" (cinquenta reais). Estou trabalhando com uma textBox formatada para valores monetários.

Comment: @Rayra como é o formato de numero permitido no seu campo? Sem saber isso eu nao vou poder te ajudar e vamos ficar nessa enrolaçao improdutiva para voce e para mim.

Comment: 1.111.111,11 <-- Valor máximo. 0,00<-- Valor mínimo

Comment: Formata de acordo com os valores digitados

Comment: @Rayra então agora ficou mais claro, e sua pergunta já foi respondida no site, e eu inclusive sugeri ela nos links. Veja o link que marquei na sua pergunta, leia atentamente a resposta aceita e faça conforme ele explica.