# Não estou conseguindo preencher uma matriz

Tags: c#, .net, matriz, declaração-de-variável

Quando eu coloco valores fixos no tamanho da matriz consigo preenchê-la, mas quando tento capturar os valores em matrizes aparece uma mensagem assim:

> O índice estava fora dos limites da matriz

```
      ` int a = 0, b = 0;
        double[ , ] test = new double[a , b];

        Console.Write("Linha: ");
        a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Coluna: ");
        b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {  
            for (int j = 0; j < b ; j++)
            {
               Console.Write("Digite um valor: "); 
               test[i , j] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n\n ");

        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(test[i, j] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que declarar a matriz antes de estabelecer o valor, primeiro pede os valores, depois a declara. Não faz sentido criar o alicerce de uma casa que você não sabe qual é o tamanho e quantos cômodos terá.

O código tem outros erros. Uma versão melhorada, simplificando e dando nomes mais significativos, e seria assim (eu simplesmente encerrei se uma digitação for errada, mas pode fazer o tratamento de erro que quiser ali):

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Write("Linha: ");
        if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var linhas)) return;
        Write("Coluna: ");
        if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var colunas)) return;
        var matriz = new double[linhas, colunas];
        for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {  
            for (int j = 0; j < colunas; j++) {
                Write("Digite um valor: ");
                if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var valor)) return;
                matriz[i, j] = valor; 
            }
        }
        WriteLine("\n\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < colunas; j++) Write(matriz[i, j] + " ");
            WriteLine(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/e0v2Te). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2ZiHGB). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/DynamicDeclaration.cs).

Veja a [importância de usar o `TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).

Comment: Muito obrigado, não achei nenhum tutorial que ensinasse isso, muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Porque o ideal não é seguir tutorais, é aprender de forma estruturada. É entender tudo o que está ocorrendo no código, é conquistar o conhecimento passo por passo. E tutorais são criados para queimar etapas, o que é péssimo para o aprendizado.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica.