# Qual motivo o "falta()" no final do programa me envia um erro no qual não é possível nem compilar?

Tags: c#, .net, método, parâmetros

#### Main

```
Nota estudante = new Nota();
            estudante.Matricula = Console.ReadLine();
            estudante.Nome = Console.ReadLine();
            estudante.Idade = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            estudante.Prova1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            estudante.Prova2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            estudante.Trabalho = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            estudante.print();
```

#### Class

```
public string Matricula { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public int Idade { get; set; }
        public double Prova1 { get; set; }
        public double Prova2 { get; set; }
        public double Trabalho { get; set; }

        public void media()
        {
            double mfinal;
            mfinal = ((Prova1 * 2.5) + (Prova2 * 2.5) + (Trabalho * 1.5)) / 6.5;
            Console.WriteLine("Sua media foi igual a: {0:0.00}", mfinal);
        }
        public string falta(double mfinal)
        {
            double pfinal;
            if (mfinal >= 6.0)
            {
                pfinal = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                pfinal = 6.0 - mfinal;

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Nota para passar: {0:0.00} pontos",pfinal);
            //string txt;
            //txt = "Nota para passar:" + pfinal + " pontos";
            //return txt;
        }
        public void melhor()
        {
            double mnota;
            mnota = Prova1;
            if(Prova2 > mnota)
            {
                mnota = Prova2;
            }
            if(Trabalho > mnota)
            {
                mnota = Trabalho;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Sua maior nota foi: {0:0.00} pontos", mnota);

        }
        public void print()
        {
            media();
            falta();
            melhor();

        }
```

Comment: E qual é o erro?

Comment: Tem como postar o erro, fazendo favor?

Comment: quando tento compilar o Public void print()
        {
            media();
            falta();
            melhor();

        } o meu programa fica com uma marcação vermelha no falta()

Comment: Gravidade Código Descrição Projeto Arquivo Linha Estado de Supressão
Erro CS7036 Não há nenhum argumento fornecido que corresponde ao parâmetro formal necessário "mfinal" de "Nota.falta(double)" ConsoleApp56 C:\Users\Matheus\source\repos\ConsoleApp56\ConsoleApp56\Nota.cs 59 Ativo

Comment: 1- O método `public string falta(double mfinal)` não retorna uma `string`. se não retorna nada, então mude para `void`. 2- No método `public void print()` a chamada para o método `falta()` não está passando o parâmetro. Enfim... o problema está na base...!!!

Comment: "a chamada para o método falta() não está passando o parâmetro".                              
Como eu poderia fazer para passar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade o código tem vários problemas, inclusive conceituais, mas para um exercício muito básico só de mecanismos a maioria não é um grade problema. Também tem problemas de organização e nomenclatura de nomes que não segue o padrão do C#. Não dá erro mas acostume-se fazer de uma forma melhor. Note que eu simplifiquei bastante o código, faz tempo que não precisa escrever o código de forma tão complexa. Podia ter simplificado mais. E dei nomes mais corretos para o que o método faz, assim o código fica mais legível.

Uma coisa que eu não fiz foi validar a entrada de dados, o correto é validar. Por exemplo na hora de converter para número pode dar erro, não deveria deixar isto ocorrer, então deveria usar o [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) e não o `Parse()` que só deve ser usado em locais onde você pode garantir que o dado está correto, o que não é o caso de uma entrada de dados.

Também não me preocupei se a classe deveria ter um [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101), talvez.

Também não entrei no mérito se devia [usar um `decimal` para notas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101), em muitos casos não precisa, mas exatidão pode ser um requisito.

O problema central é que está chamando um método que exige um parâmetro sem passar um [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101). Mas tem um outro conceito errado ali. O certo é fazer isso em cima da média já existente e decidir se a pessoa passou ou quanto falta de nota. Pelo menos é o que o código dá a entender que deve fazer.

Enfim, resolvi o problema, mas pode ensinar errado se achar que está bom para usar em aplicações reais.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var estudante = new Nota {
            Matricula = ReadLine(),
            Idade = int.Parse(ReadLine()),
            Prova1 = double.Parse(ReadLine()),
            Prova2 = double.Parse(ReadLine()),
            Trabalho = double.Parse(ReadLine())
        };
        estudante.MostraDadosDeNota();
    }
}
public class Nota {
    public string Matricula { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }
    public double Prova1 { get; set; }
    public double Prova2 { get; set; }
    public double Trabalho { get; set; }
    public double Media { get => (Prova1 * 2.5 + Prova2 * 2.5 + Trabalho * 1.5) / 6.5; }

    public void MostrarMedia() => WriteLine($"Sua media foi igual a: {Media:0.00}");
    public void MostrarNotaFaltante() {
        if (Media >= 6.0) WriteLine("Passou");
        else WriteLine($"Faltou {6.0 - Media:0.00} pontos para passar");
    }
    public void MostrarMelhorNota() {
        double nota = Prova1;
        if (Prova2 > nota) nota = Prova2;
        if (Trabalho > nota) nota = Trabalho;
        WriteLine($"Sua maior nota foi: {nota:0.00} pontos");
    }
    public void MostraDadosDeNota() {
        MostrarMedia();
        MostrarNotaFaltante();
        MostrarMelhorNota();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/AfafI1). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vwDogk). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/AverageGrade.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução simples para seu problema é passar um valor como parâmetro quando você chama o método, e adicionar um `return` ao final do método.

Exemplo:

```
public string falta(double mfinal)
{
    double pfinal;
    if (mfinal >= 6.0)
    {
         pfinal = 0;
    }
    else
    {
         pfinal = 6.0 - mfinal;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Nota para passar: {0:0.00} pontos",pfinal);
    string txt;
    txt = "Nota para passar:" + pfinal + " pontos";
    return txt;
}

public void print()
{
    media();
    falta(10);
    melhor();
}
```

Você precisa passar um valor `Double` como parâmetro na hora de chamá-lo, pois você definiu na criação do método, e, pelo mesmo motivo você precisa ter um `return` no final do método.

Definindo tipo de retorno:

> public `string` falta(double mfinal)

Definindo parametrização:

> public string falta(`double mfinal`)

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer dúvida só comentar.