# Não existe mapeamento do tipo de objeto System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripTextBox para um provedor gerenciado de tipo nativo

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tipagem

Estou com uma problema pra tentar fazer um consulta em um `Select` e trazer as informações no `TextBox`.

> Não existe mapeamento do tipo de objeto System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripTextBox para um provedor gerenciado de tipo nativo.'

Código:

```
if ((Keys)e.KeyChar == Keys.Enter)
        {

               SqlConnection con = ConectDAO.abrir();

                SqlCommand conexao = new SqlCommand("SELECT RAZãO_SOCIAL FROM BANCODEDADOSCENTRAL WHERE CNPJ = ? ", con);
                conexao.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNPJ", SqlDbType.Int);
                conexao.Parameters["@CNPJ"].Value = toolStripTXT_Pesq_Cnpj;
                conexao.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                SqlDataReader dr;
                dr = conexao.ExecuteReader();
                dr.Read();

                txt_razao.Text = dr.GetString(0);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem que pegar o valor do objeto de GUI para um objeto simples, não dá para ter certeza porque não tem informações suficientes na pergunta. Pode ser:

```
toolStripTXT_Pesq_Cnpj.Text
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/GetText.cs).

Mas aí tem que fazer uma conversão e com cuidado porque o dado pode ser digitado errado, veja mais em [Diferenças entre Parse() vs TryParse()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).

Existem outros problemas no código, ainda que ele funcione.

Comment: era isso mesmo .text no final. obg resolvido