# Como usar o Enum.Parse()?

Tags: c#, enums, parse

Meu código exibe erro ao usar o `Enum.Parse<enum>(Console.ReadLine());`

Estou pedindo para o usuário digitar o nível do cargo ocupado, porem para receber os dados digitados pelo usuário o Parse<> exibe erro, não passa para o `Level`.

```
 Classe program


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter client data: ");
        Console.Write("Name: ");
        string clientName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Email: ");
        string email = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Birth date (DD/MM/YYYY): ");
        DateTime birthDate = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter order data: ");
        Console.Write("Level: (Junior/MidLevel/Senior) ");
        OrderStatus Level = Enum.Parse<OrderStatus>(Console.ReadLine());

    }



classe Enums


enum OrderStatus : int
{
    Junior = 0,
    MidLevel = 1,
    Senior = 2
}
```

> Erro CS0308 O método não genérico "Enum.Parse(Type, string)" não pode ser usado como argumentos de tipo SalesOrde

https://github.com/thuliomariano/Exercicio

Comment: Erro CS0308 O método não genérico "Enum.Parse(Type, string)" não pode ser usado como argumentos de tipo SalesOrder

Comment: O seu código aqui não tem `SalesOrder`. O código no Github não tem enumeração.

Comment: desculpe, corrigido

Comment: o Enum está dentro do Entitie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não deveria usar o `Parse()`, isto está explicado em [Diferenças entre Parse vs TryParse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101). Usando o `TryParse()` ficaria assim e funciona:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    static int Main() {
        WriteLine("Enter client data: ");
        Write("Name: ");
        string clientName = ReadLine();
        Write("Email: ");
        string email = ReadLine();
        Write("Birth date (DD/MM/YYYY): ");
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var birthDate)) return 1;
        WriteLine("Enter order data: ");
        Write("Status: ");
        if (!Enum.TryParse<OrderStatus>(ReadLine(), true, out var status)) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
enum OrderStatus {
    Junior = 0,
    MidLevel = 1,
    Senior = 2
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Pwtamx). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lNaUJG). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enum/Parsing.cs).

Ainda acho preocupante essa coisa de deixar a pessoa digitar o nível, mas como solução simples até passa se usar o `TryParse()`, sem ele não pode usar em hipótese alguma, não é robusta.

Comment: Estou estudando enumeradores e quando uso o git clone o código do professor executa normalmente e quando faço o mesmo código exibe erro, segue o git do professor: https://github.com/acenelio/composition1-csharp.  obs:  não consegui fazer da maneira que você mencionou, mesmo com o tryParse o erro persiste

Comment: Eu respondi o que está na pergunta e posso colocar *link* mostrando funcionando. Você está fazendo algum erro que não está na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

```
//class program main ----------------------------------------------

using System;   

 namespace Worker
 {
      class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
               Console.WriteLine("Enter client data: ");
               Console.Write("Name: ");
               string clientName = Console.ReadLine();
               Console.Write("Email: ");
               string email = Console.ReadLine();
               Console.Write("Birth date (DD/MM/YYYY): ");
               DateTime birthDate = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
               Console.WriteLine("Enter order data: ");
               Console.Write("Level: (Junior/MidLevel/Senior) ");
               Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out OrderStatus level);
                      
          }
      }
 }
    
    
    
 // enums ----------------------------------------------

 namespace Worker.Entities.Enums
 {
     enum OrderStatus : int
     {
          Junior,
          MidLevel,
          Senior
     }
 }
```