# Como fazer um calculo interno no Textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, conversão-de-tipo, textbox

Preciso calcular um valor inserido no `Textbox` e esse valor que eu insiro é multiplicado por `9,81`. Logo, todos os números que eu inserir neste Textbox será multiplicado por `9,81` e terá que me mostrar o resultado no próprio `Textbox`.

***Exemplo:*** eu digito no `Textbox`: `6000` e esse `6000` será multiplicado por `9.81`. E o mesmo textbox terá que me mostrar `58.860`.

***Observação:*** os valores que eu inserir serão aleatórios, apenas o `9.81` será fixado no cálculo.

```
private void txtCalcular_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Calcular = double.Parse((txtCalcular.Text).ToString());
    ResultadoCalcular = double.Parse(
         (txtCalcular.Text = (Calcular * 9.81).ToString())
    );
}
```

Tentei fazer dessa seguinte maneira também, mas sem sucesso:

```
Calcular = double.Parse((txtCalcular.Text = (Calcular * 9.81).ToString()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O primeiro problema é que está considerando que a pessoa sempre vai digitar algo certo, o que não dá para garantir e quebrará a aplicação, tem que tratar isso.

Com um dado válido é só fazer a conta simples, converter isso para texto e armazenar no campo onde você já tinha o valor. Não precisar dar voltas, ficar repetindo as coisas. Principalmente não pode atribuir o valor ao campo no meio de uma operação que fará outra coisa.

Respondi o que está na pergunta.

```
private void txtCalcular_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!double.TryParse(txtCalcular.Text, out var resultado)) {
        //faça alguma coisa aqui para indicar que houve erro de digitação;
        return;
    }
    txtCalcular.Text = (resultado * 9.81).ToString());
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/ChangeFieldWF.cs).

Veja [Diferenças entre Parse() vs TryParse()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).

Comment: Muito obrigada pelo rápido retorno! Acabei de inserir o código, não deu nenhum erro, mas no momento da compilação quando eu começo a digitar ele aparece o número que estou digitando e o símbolo do infinito (6000∞) e quando pressiono "enter" não acontece nada. O que poderia ser?

Comment: Aí é outro problema, precisa de mais informações, em outra pergunta, mostrando com clareza tudo o que for importante para ver, com o postado não tem como saber.

Comment: Entendi, o estranho é que não aparece nenhum erro, nem antes e nem no momento da compilação. 
Irei abrir outra pergunta então, mostrando o que acontece.

Obrigada!