# Como criar um array de tamanho fixo?

Tags: c#, array, .net, campos

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
struct Pessoa {
    required string Nome;
    required int Idade;
}
```

Gostaria de criar um `Array`, mas que tenha um tamanho fixo, ou seja, não pode ser redimensionado em *runtime*, algo como:

```
public Pessoa[4] pessoas;
```

Mas isso não é possível. Eu posso instanciar um *array* com um tamanho fixo, como:

```
public Pessoa[] pessoas = new Pessoa[4];
```

O comportamento desejável é que não seja possível alterar o tamanho do *array* posteriormente, por ex:

```
pessoas = new Pessoa[2];   // erro
pessoas = new Pessoa[6];   // erro
pessoas = new Pessoa[];    // erro
pessoas = new Pessoa[4];   // ok
```

Por suma, é possível criar um *array* em que seu tamanho seja estrito a sua declaração?

É possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não vou falar sobre o que pode ser errado nessa ideia, porque depende da situação, e vou entender que sabe o que está fazendo.

Exatamente o que parece desejar não é possível, mas se quer mesmo, considere redesenhar o tipo para não expor o *array* de forma direta e controlar o que pode fazer ou não dentro da classe, validando se está fazendo algo que você aceita.

Se não quer poder mudar o tamanho nem o objeto é só fazer o *array* ser `readonly`.

Se não quiser deixar passar batido nem gerar exceção se tentar fazer algo não permito, mas quer aviusar se deu certo, tem que fazer um método usando o [padrão TryCan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).

Vou demonstrar as duas possibilidades expondo o campo e usando uma propriedade (vou ignorar o tipo `Pessoa` porque ele é irrelevante para o problema):

```
using static System.Console;

Teste teste = new();
//teste.array = new int[5];
teste.array[0] = 1;
teste.Array = new int[5];
WriteLine(teste.Array.Length);
teste.Array = new int[4];
WriteLine(teste.Array.Length);

public class Teste {
    public readonly int[] array = new int[4];
    private int[] array2 = new int[4];
    public int[] Array { get => array2; set {
            if (value.Length == 4) array2 = value;
            //decide se quer gerar uma exceção no else
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/BlucLv). E [no **repl.it**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YE1v5d). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/OnlySpecificSizeArray.cs).

Ainda existe a possibilidade de fazer uma ferramenta externa ligada ao *pipe* de compilação para analisar o código e indicar que está tentando fazer algo não permitido e não deixar a mudança sem ter que recorrer ao tempo de execução (o que também impediria usar uma variável para determinar o tamanho do *array*), mas é muita complexidade, duvido que valha a pena.