# Prática errada?

Tags: c#

Bom dia, estou voltando a estudar programação, mais especificamente C#, e queria saber se a prática de atribuir um valor pra mais de uma variável é algo feio.

Exemplo do código que estou escrevendo:

```
     int lucroAbaixo, lucroEntre, lucroAcima = 0; // <-- isso é algo feio?
     double totalCompra, totalVenda, lucroTotal = 0.0;

     int quantMercadorias = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     double[] compra = new double[quantMercadorias];
     double[] venda = new double[quantMercadorias];

     for (int i = 0; i < quantMercadorias; i++)
     {
         string[] vet = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
         compra[i] = double.Parse(vet[1]);
         venda[i] = double.Parse(vet[2]);
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < quantMercadorias; i++)
     {
                
     }
```

Acabei ficando com essa dúvida pois em todos os vídeos ou códigos de outras pessoas eu nunca vi essa prática.

Comment: Vc não está atribuindo o valor para mais de uma variável. Somente `lucroAcima` é inicializada com `0`, as outras são somente declaradas, mas ainda não foram inicializadas. Se fosse pra atribuir todas de uma vez seria `lucroAbaixo = lucroEntre = lucroAcima = 0;`, mas teria que ser em outra linha, separado da declaração. De qualquer forma, nenhuma dessas coisas é "feia", vc faz conforme a necessidade.

Comment: Nossa, na minha cabeça eu estava atribuindo para todas, por algum motivo eu acabei supondo que era assim que funcionava, bem, obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Conforme o @hkotsubo apontou, o entendimento do uso está errado, não atribui, agora no caso de algo como `int a, b, c;` contra `int a; int b; int c;`, nem é questão de prática, pode ser questão de gosto ou necessidade, se for documentar ou comentar as variaveis, separa-las talvez será melhor, dependendo de como está comentando ou documentando, o que acaba caindo no critério de opinião pessoal de como organiza seus projetos.

Comment: "*por algum motivo eu acabei supondo que era assim*" - Desculpe se parecer rude, mas programação não deve se basear em achismos ou suposições. Qualquer coisa sobre o funcionamento da linguagem (seja sintaxe, comportamento de tal função, etc) vc esclarece lendo a documentação, tutoriais, etc. E claro, testando também. Tente fazer um programa que só tem 2 linhas: `int lucroAbaixo, lucroEntre, lucroAcima = 0;` e `Console.WriteLine(lucroAbaixo);` pra ver o que acontece. Dá erro, veja: https://ideone.com/ULcOew - e a mensagem de erro diz que a variável não foi inicializada.

Comment: Entendo. Realmente, depois da sua resposta, eu fui testar e o próprio visual studio sublinhou como erro. Durante algum tempo eu acreditava que isso funcionava, mas como achava que era algo feio por não ver as pessoas usando, eu evitava de usar também, mas como você mostrou, o fato de eu nunca ter visto alguém fazendo isso, era porque estava errado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece um pouco gosto. Algumas pessoas fazem outras não. Não parece ter problema em si, pelo menos para o que quer saber. Permite fazer assim porque pode fazer sentido. Muita gente não faz por outros motivos, que só poderíamos falar com mais contexto do código.

Vejo vários outros problemas no código.

Está declarando as variáveis no começo para usar depois? Sim, isso é ruim. Declare o mais próximo do uso possível. Inventaram isso nos anos 70 porque isso dá mais legibilidade ao código. Aí talvez não faça sentido colocar 3 na mesma linha com a mesma atribuição.

Especialmente é um problema porque duas delas só estão sendo declaradas, e não receberão valor. Você vai atribuir, certo? Caso contrário receberá erro. Por isso seu código só compila se atribui depois.

Se vai atribuir depois, cai no que eu disse acima. Atribuir separado da declaração é bom em casos bastante raros. Você está pedindo para fazer besteira.

Sem o código completo só podemos supor o que fez.

[`double` para valores que são monetários ou que exigem exatidão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101)? Nunca mais faça isso, nem pra exercício bobo. Qual a dificuldade de escrever `decimal`? Ou nem isso e usar `var` e sufixo `M` de literal.

`Parse()` em *input*? [Pense de novo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101). Experimente digitar algo errado

Não vou reclamar do uso direto do *array*, em vez de um [`List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Não é o fim do mundo, mas não vejo vantagens nele, uma abstração melhor pode ser mais útil e treina mais o certo para sistemas mais bem pensados (tem caso para usar o *array* puro). E poderia até pensar nas versões somente de leitura ou imutáveis.

`Split()`? Pra que colocar mais uma coisa para dar errado e piorar a situação do `Parse()`. è é ensinado por quem tem preguiça. Não é que não pode, mas para fazer certo dá mais trabalho, só é mais simples se feito de forma relaxada.

Essas preocupações são muito mais sérias.