# Exceções devem ser usadas para controle de fluxo?

Tags: exceção, estilo-de-codificação, design-de-linguagem, controle-de-fluxo

Quando estudei Java, aprendi que exceções somente deveriam ser usadas em situações, bem, "excepcionais" (i.e. um erro, uma condição não prevista, etc), *jamais* para controle de fluxo normal. Não só por ser menos performático (criar uma exceção envolve montar um *stack trace*, dentre outras coisas) mas por ser menos "elegante" e "correto" - o ideal sendo testar as (pré-)condições antes de se fazer uma operação ou chamar um método. Ou, para *sinalizar* um erro ao chamador, usar um [código de erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/215) ou similar. Somente nos casos realmente imprevisíveis é que seria adequado se usar um `try...catch`.

Entretanto, ao aprender Python me deparei com uma filosofia bastante diferente: nessa linguagem há muitos casos em que o modo recomendado (e às vezes o único modo) de se tratar uma condição indesejada é tentar executá-la e, se algo der errado, capturar a exceção. Não há menção a performance, e muitas vezes justifica-se essa abordagem para se prevenir condições de corrida (ex.: em vez de testar se um arquivo existe antes de abri-lo, simplesmente abra-o de uma vez! Afinal, ele poderia ser apagado entre o teste e o uso, e se o programa não está preparado para isso seu comportamento nessa situação pode ficar incorreto).

Entendo que se uma linguagem/plataforma segue um determinado paradigma, é aconselhável se ater a ele, nem que seja por questões de consistência. Mas assumindo-se que não só linguagens novas possam ser criadas, como as existentes possam ser aprimoradas, pergunto: existem vantagens claras de um desses paradigmas sobre o outro? Ou talvez situações específicas em que se justifique usar um ou outro padrão, mesmo que contrarie as recomendações "oficiais"? Que parâmetros eu devo observar ao decidir entre uma abordagem e outra? (a título de exemplo, há muitas situações em que o argumento da condição de corrida não se aplica - quando os dados envolvidos na operação são imutáveis, por exemplo.)

Por fim, há algum meio termo razoável que combine os benefícios de ambos sem que o ônus caia no programador? (por exemplo, poderia testar se o arquivo existe *e* usar um `try/catch` em seguida, mas isso seria redundante) Nota: peço que esse último ponto, caso abordado na resposta, venha acompanhado de fontes confiáveis, para evitar mera especulação.

> P.S. Algumas referências demonstrando que esse uso "corriqueiro" de exceções é de fato bastante recomendado na comunidade Python, em oposição à maioria das outras:
>
> - ["Better to 'try' something and catch the exception or test if its possible first to avoid an exception?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7604636/520779)
> - ["Is it a good practice to use try-except-else in python?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16138232/520779)
> - ["How do I check if a string is a number in Python?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/354038/520779)
> - ["Python Exception Handling Techniques"](http://doughellmann.com/2009/06/19/python-exception-handling-techniques.html)
> - [*"Look Before You Leap"*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-lbyl) vs. [*"Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission"*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-eafp)
> - [Exceptions and File Handling](http://www.diveintopython.net/file_handling/) - Dive Into Python

Comment: Testando os limites do site (e da computação) como sempre @mgibsonbr hehehe. Não sei como responder sua pergunta além de dizer que existe todo tipo de religião e todo tipo de brinquedo no mundo. Python e Java são [brinquedos muito diferentes](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/compare.php?lang=java&lang2=python3), o pessoal de Python tende a buscar soluções limpas do ponto de vista de LOC e legibilidade; o pessoal de Java tem preocupação mais voltadas a arquitetura *enterprise* e fluxos bem definidos.  O padrão para o tratamento de erro seguem a cultura do ecossistema.

Comment: Dito isso, já vi projetos Python recheados de testes para evitar `try / except` e projetos Java onde nada é testado e todas as exceções são embrulhadas em `RuntimeException`... Acho que vamos acabar caindo em uma verdadeira discussão sobre escolas de fluxo de exceção :).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Hehe não duvido, mas isso só ajuda a legitimar a pergunta: afinal, não é *óbvio* que embrulhar tudo em `RuntimeException` é uma má prática? Já fazer testes para evitar exceções, não tão óbvio... Há de existir um ponto ideal, mas me carecem parâmetros mais objetivos para identificá-lo do que simplesmente meu *feeling* caso a caso. Eu próprio me sinto estranho, sempre recomendando aos programadores de Java (com a qual trabalhei tempos atrás) evitar o abuso de exceções, ao passo que no dia-a-dia trabalhando com Python eu me vejo forçado a usá-las de um modo bem diferente... :P

Comment: @mgibsonbr Será que não é o caso de adicionar a tag **Python**? Ou mesmo **Python E Java**? Os problemas que são resolvidos com fluxo de exceção nestas linguagens são resolvidos de maneira muito distinta e mais expressiva (independente de certo ou errado o código simplesmente fica mais bacana) em **C#** ou **Ruby**, por exemplo.

Comment: @Caffé Pessoalmente, eu preferia uma resposta mais independente de linguagem, não só pra evitar um "gorilla vs. shark" mas principalmente porque meu interesse é em algo que eu possa aplicar em um contexto mais amplo (daí a tag `design-de-linguagem` e não `característica-linguagem`). Uma comparação/explicação sobre como as exceções se encaixam na filosofia dessas linguagens, somente, é de pouca serventia pra mim (a menos que os argumentos apresentados sejam passíveis de serem extrapolados). Entretanto, se a comunidade achar que da forma como está fica muito amplo, não faço objeção a elas.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Não sei se o contexto desta questão pode ser mais amplo que o de uma única linguagem. Minha sugestão é justamente para reduzir o escopo de modo a evitar cair em comparações. Se o estilo Python é usar exceções (de repente mais por falta de recursos pontos na linguagens do que por estilo), este não é o caso de outras linguagens. Onde em Python fica mais prático usar exceções, em outras linguagens há recursos prontos muito mais práticos e expressivos. Também há diferença de custo por exeção entre as linguagens - não é em todas elas que lançar uma exceção custa caro.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, também cheguei a tomar (e para ser sincero, ainda tomo) essa questão de embrulhar `RuntimeExceptions` genéricas por *anti-pattern* óbvio. Fui reclamar [na fonte](http://www.guj.com.br/java/216655-excecoes-de-banco-embrulhadas-em-runtimeexception-generica) (nossa, já fazem 4 anos) e tomei uma invertida. Como disse, escolas de pensamento :).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Lançar exceções é legal!

### Abordagem bacana 1 - evitar exceções porque elas representam o mal:

```
public Resultado baixaEstoque(Produto produto, int quantidade) {

    Resultado resultado = new Resultado();
    
    if (!produtoDisponivel(produto, quantidade)) {
        resultado.isSucesso(false);
        resultado.setMotivoFalha(
            String.Format("Não há %d items de %s disponíveis em estoque.", 
            quantidade, produto.getNome()));
        return resultado;
    }
    // ... (baixa o estoque de fato);
    resultado.isSucesso(true);
}
```

O consumo no mais alto nível da aplicação fica assim:

```
Resultado Resultado = estoque.baixaEstoque(produto, quantidade);
if (Resultado.isSucesso()) {
    mensagens.Add("O produto foi baixado do estoque");
} else {
    mensagens.Add(Resultado.getMotivoFalha());
}
```

Eu gosto do código acima. Nenhuma exceção lançada, nenhum `try-catch` foi usado.

Agora considere uma operação um pouco mais complexa como o fechamento de uma venda:

```
public Resultado fechaVenda(Carrinho carrinho, Cliente cliente, FormaPagamento formaPagamento) {

    Resultado resultado = crediario.reservaCredito(cliente, 
        carrinho.valorTotal(), formaPagamento);
    
    if (!Resultado.isSucesso()) {
        return resultado;
    }
    
    for (CarrinhoItem item : carrinho.getItems()) {
        resultado = estoque.baixaEstoque(item.getProduto(), item.getQuantidade);
        
        if (!Resultado.isSucesso()) {
            return resultado;
        }
    }
    
    resultado = crediario.debitaCliente(cliente, carrinho.valorTotal(), formaPagamento);
    
    if (!Resultado.isSucesso()) {
        return resultado;
    }
    
    resultado = despacho.ordenaDespacho(cliente, carrinho.getItems());
    
    if (!Resultado.isSucesso()) {
        return resultado;
    }
    // ... (mais operações de baixa de venda);
    return resultado;
}
```

Então, informando sucesso ou falha como retorno do método me deixou com vários **if**s e bastante código repetido que não expressa a regra de negócio mas  está ali apenas para o caso de acontecer algo que não permita ao sistema seguir o seu caminho padrão.

### Abordagem bacana 2 - usar exceções racionalmente para um design mais limpo e expressivo:

Agora considere esta mesma operação de fechamento de uma venda usando exceções, onde cada processo lança exceção de negócio nos casos de exceções previstas (como um produto não estar diponível no estoque). Nesta abordagem, a baixa de estoque, por exemplo, fica assim:

```
public void baixaEstoque(Produto produto, int quantidade) {

    if (!produtoDisponivel(produto, quantidade)) {
        throw new BusinessException(
            String.Format("Não há %d items de %s disponíveis em estoque.", 
            quantidade, produto.getNome()));
    }
    // ... (baixa o estoque de fato);
}
```

Cada processo segue este mesmo padrão, de modo que o processo completo de fechamento de venda fica assim:

```
public void fechaVenda(Carrinho carrinho, Cliente cliente, FormaPagamento formaPagamento) {

    crediario.reservaCredito(cliente, carrinho.valorTotal(), formaPagamento);
    
    for (CarrinhoItem item : carrinho.getItems()) {
        estoque.baixaEstoque(item.getProduto(), item.getQuantidade);
    }
    
    crediario.debitaCliente(cliente, carrinho.valorTotal(), formaPagamento);
    
    despacho.ordenaDespacho(cliente, carrinho.getItems());
}
```

E o consumo no mais alto nível da aplicação fica assim:

```
try {
    vendas.fechaVenda(carrinho, cliente, formaPagamento);
    mensagens.Add("O produto foi baixado do estoque");
} catch (Exception e)
    mensagens.Add(e.getMessage());
}
```

Idealmente a aplicação dispõe de um tratamento genérico de exceções que já vai logar e adicionar a mensagem de erro, então o código fica ainda mais limpo:

```
vendas.fechaVenda(carrinho, cliente, formaPagamento);
mensagens.Add("Venda concluída.");
```

Nesta segunda abordagem eu eliminei dezenas de **if**s (seriam muitos mais num código completo) e ao mesmo tempo não incluí nenhum `try-catch` em nenhuma parte do meu código de negócio, mesmo lançando exceções úteis!

Em tempo: **apesar de serem exceções previstas, ainda assim são exceções**. Por exemplo: um processo de venda não chega até o seu fechamento se o produto não estiver previamente disponível em estoque, eventualmente foi reservado ao ser adicionado no carrinho virtual. O produto não estar mais disponível no momento da sua baixa é uma exceção que pode ocorrer no caso de um processo de vendas com *overbooking* ou em caso de vendas concorrentes quando duas reservas de um mesmo produto já expiraram e a compra ainda assim foi levada até o fim. Então, **pode acontecer, mas é uma exceção**. Além disso, esta exceção não está determinando o fluxo do programa - ao contrário, ela está interrompendo o fluxo do programa.

### Conclusão 1:

Lançar exceções não é errado. Ao contrário, pode ajudar a fazer um código mais expressivo.

<sub>Uma premissa destas duas primeiras abordagens é que existe um controle de transação em torno da chamada de nível mais alto, e que este controle de transação garante a consistência do estado do sistema (executa um *rollback*) no caso de falha. A segunda abordagem, por exemplo, poderia contar com o gerenciamento automático e implícito de transações de um container EJB, onde nenhum código adicional seria necessário. Na primeira abordagem seria necessário incluir uma chamada explícita ao rollback.</sub>

### Abordagens esquisitas:

Existe também o tratamento de exceção por ele mesmo, sem qualquer objetivo ou que **tenta** adicionar robustez ao código. Exemplo:

```
try
{ 
    // ... (código de negócio);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// ... (continua com mais código de negócio ignorando completamente que houve exceção!);
```

Ou ainda:

```
try
{ 
    // ... (código de negócio);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;
}
```

E existe também o tratamento de exceção que controla o fluxo do programa de maneira esquisita:

```
public Pessoa obtemPessoa(String cpf) {
    try
    { 
        // ... (busca pessoa);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("CPF não cadastrado.");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Na minha segunda abordagem, de certa forma **eu usei exceções para controlar o fluxo do programa** pois eu lancei exceções para interromper este fluxo, e isso não está errado. Foi um exemplo de boa utilização dos recursos da linguagem.

Neste código aí acima a exceção também está sendo usada para controlar o fluxo, mas para dar um fluxo alternativo em vez de simplesmente interrompê-lo; e ainda faz isso usando um código bem esquisito que mistura apresentação com regras de negócio.

### Conclusão 2:

Em várias linguagens, lançar e capturar exceções sem entender por que e sem estar certo neste porquê (muitos porquês são apenas mitos ou falta de conhecimento) é que é o problema. Não as exceções em si.

### Abordagens necessárias:

Algumas vezes não fazemos questão de uma exceção mas este é o recurso mais simples ou o único recurso de performance aceitável ou ainda a única forma possível que a linguagem nos oferece.

Exemplo em **Java**:

```
    int valor;
    try
    { 
        valor = Integer.parseInt(str);
        // ... (usa o valor);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        // ... (código alternativo para string não válida);
    }
```

Quando em **C#**, eu prefiro fazer assim:

```
var numeroValido = Int32.TryParse(str, out valor);
if (numeroValido) 
    // ... (usa o valor);
else
    // ... (código alternativo para string não válida);
```

O código em Java não está errado porque este é o jeito Java de fazer isso. Quando houver um jeito tão expressivo quanto o do C#, eu vou usá-lo.

### Conclusão 3:

Gostando ou não de lançar e capturar exceção, se este for o jeito de resolver determinado problema naquela linguagem, não há o que discutir - simplesmente vamos lançar e capturar a exceção.

### Respostas aos seus pontos específicos:

> Quando estudei Java, aprendi que exceções somente deveriam ser usadas em situações, bem, "excepcionais" (i.e. um erro, uma condição não prevista, etc), jamais para controle de fluxo normal.

**Incorreto.** Exceções em Java estão lá para serem utilizadas. Nenhuma das minhas duas primeiras abordagens está incorreta em determinado cenário. Então em vez de "*utilizar jamais*" eu prefiro "*utilizar de maneira criteriosa*".

> Lançar exceção é menos performático (criar uma exceção envolve montar um stack trace, dentre outras coisas)

**Correto.** Na minha abordagem usando exceções, apenas 1 exceção eventualmente será lançada a cada execução do processo, e em um processo que depende da interação do usuário este custo não é sensível. Se você tiver um grande lote de chamadas a uma função, como por exemplo em uma integração, não é uma boa idéia lançar milhões de exceções. Acontece que do ponto de vista de design também não será uma boa idéia, pois numa integração em lote você não precisa de exceção mas sim de um log. Em tempo: de qualquer modo já vi integração falhando e lançando milhões de exceções e ainda assim o fim do mundo não veio.

> Usar exceções como fluxo normal pode ser menos "elegante" e "correto".

**Verdadeiro.** Mas eu usei exceções na minha segunda abordagem e ela não está deselegante, tampouco incorreta. Então, novamente, o problema não é com as exceções, mas sim com o uso que podemos fazer dela - como com qualquer outro recurso de uma linguagem de programação. Mesmo o recurso mais básico da maioria das linguagem, o **IF**, é extremamente mal utilizado, e não se vê muita gente dizendo para jamais utilizá-lo.

> O ideal sendo testar as pré-condições antes de se fazer uma operação ou chamar um método. Ou, para sinalizar um erro ao chamador, usar um código de erro ou similar.

**São decisões de design**, que consideram requisitos inclusive não funcionais, não dá para generalizar o que é certo ou errado. Na minha primeira abordagem eu usei código de erro, na segunda usei exceções. Na minha opinião, a segunda abordagem é melhor (código mais limpo e expressivo). E na sua?

> Somente nos casos realmente imprevisíveis é que seria adequado se usar um try...catch.

**Pelo contrário**, é justamente quando você prevê um erro que você deve se preocupar com a captura do erro, seja no nível mais alto da aplicação para mostrar uma mensagem ou de maneira mais localizada, no código de negócio, para trilhar um caminho alternativo.

Se você não sabe que erro esperar, é melhor nenhum `try-catch`. **Deixe a aplicação estourar ou mostre no nível mais alto da aplicação uma mensagem** amigável para o usuário e ao mesmo tempo informativa para o suporte.

> Entretanto, ao aprender Python me deparei com uma filosofia bastante diferente: nessa linguagem há muitos casos em que o modo recomendado (e às vezes o único modo) de se tratar uma condição indesejada é tentar executá-la e, se algo der errado, capturar a exceção.

Se este for o jeito Python, por diversos fatores que desconheço, ou nas vezes em que é o único modo, simplesmente **não há o que discutir - terá que ser feito desta maneira**.

> Mas assumindo-se que não só linguagens novas possam ser criadas, como as existentes possam ser aprimoradas, pergunto: existem vantagens claras de um desses paradigmas sobre o outro?

**É a linguagem quem vai dizer.** *Go* (ou *go lang*) não tem exceção mas tem outros sofisticados recursos que o Java e C# ainda não tem. Se a discussão puder ser trazida para uma linguagem específica, daí sim podemos descrever as vantagens de um paradigma sobre o outro.

> Que parâmetros eu devo observar ao decidir entre uma abordagem e outra?

Quando você puder escolher a abordagem, **o único parâmetro é a expressividade do código**. Acontece que qualquer bom julgamento de design algumas vezes simplesmente é jogado ao lixo por um outro que algumas vezes manda mais: performance. Que isso não sirva de licença para jogar todo o bom design no lixo porque o sistema precisa ser ultra performático. Existem padrões, justamente de design, para garantir que os requisitos não funcionais de um processo crítico não afetem o design de todo o sistema.

> Por fim, há algum meio termo razoável que combine os benefícios de ambos sem que o ônus caia no programador?

Generalizando esta pergunta um pouco mais que o propósito original dela, a resposta é **não**. O ônus da decisão sempre vai ficar com o programador. Não há uma recomendação matemática que sirva para todos os casos. Eu não tenho muitas dúvidas sobre lançar ou como tratar exceções, entretanto tenho enorme dificuldade de repassar esta segurança. Cada programador precisa se preocupar em fazer as coisas de um jeito sempre melhor de modo a desenvolver uma experiência que lhe leve a um bom e simples design, usando ou não exceções.

## Conclusão final

Talvez o livro [The Pragmatic Programmer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161622X) entregue o ouro de maneira simples e simétrica entre todas as linguagens que dispõem de exceções:

Segundo o livro ([referenciado por Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/articles/replaceThrowWithNotification.html)):

> Nós acreditamos que exceções raramente deveriam ser usadas como parte do fluxo normal de um programa: exceções deveriam ser reservadas para eventos inesperados. Assuma que uma exceção não capturada vai terminar o seu programa e pergunte a si mesmo: "Este código continuará a rodar se eu remover todos os tratamentos de exceção?" Se a resposta é "não", então talvez as exceções estejam sendo usadas em circunstâncias não excepcionais.

#### Exemplo de código que atende esta premissa:

```
public synchronized void baixaEstoque(Produto produto, int quantidade) {
    if (!produtoDisponivel(produto, quantidade)) {
        throw new BusinessException("Produto não disponível nesta quantidade");
    }
    // ... (baixa o estoque de fato);
}
```

Código consumidor no nível mais alto do aplicativo:

```
if (estoque.produtoDisponivel(produto, quantidade)) {
    ReservaProduto reserva = estoque.reservaProduto(produto, quantidade);
} else {
    mensagens.add("Produto não disponível nesta quantidade");
}
// e, em outra requisição:
try { 
    estoque.baixaProduto(reserva.getProdutoReservado(), reserva.getQuantidadeReservada());
} catch (BusinessException e) {
    mensagens.add(e.getMessage());
}
```

O estoque espera que não seja baixado o que não estiver disponível, mas como é sua função tratar concorrência, ele sabe que há a infeliz possibilidade de o produto não estar mais lá quando da efetiva baixa.

Todavia, se eu remover o tratamento de exceção (remover tanto o `throw` quanto o `catch`), no caminho feliz (o caminho padrão e mais provável) o código continuará a funcionar.

#### Exemplo de código que NÃO atende esta premissa:

```
public Cliente obtemCliente(String cpf) {
    Cliente cliente = db.find(Cliente.class, cpf);
    if (cliente == null) {
        throw new CpfNaoCadastradoException(cpf);
    }
    return cliente;
}
```

O e-commerce acabou de entrar no ar. O primeiro usuário encheu um carrinho e quando mandou fechar a compra o seu CPF foi solicitado. E então o seguinte código foi invocado:

```
try {
    Cliente cliente = obtemCliente(cpf);
} catch (CpfNaoCadastradoException) {
    redirecionaParaCadastroCliente(cpf);
}
solicitaLogin(cliente);
```

No exemplo acima, se eu remover o tratamento de exceções o código não vai rodar nem na primeira tentativa de uso do sistema.

Comment: Boas considerações! Porém a minha interpretação da citação final é oposta à sua. O caminho infeliz é razoavelmente provável, e a aplicação não pode quebrar pela indisponibilidade do produto.

Comment: @bfavaretto O ponto é o código rodar ou não rodar. O código roda sem as exceções e dependendo dos requisitos de negócio pode nunca vir a quebrar (considere um estoque mínimo amplo e baixo volume de vendas; ou um tempo de expiração longo do carrinho associado ao perfil do público alvo que conclui rápido as suas compras). Agradeço seu comentário - adicionei um exemplo de código que se utiliza de exceções e que quebrará imediatamente se elas forem retiradas.

Comment: Entendi Caffé, vai depender da situação. Obrigado pelo retorno.

Comment: Tenho um código similar ao seu fluxo de fechamento de venda só que cada etapa consiste em enviar um comando a um dispositivo remoto e processar a resposta recebida. Tratar a perda de conexão como caso excepcional torna o código bem mais expressivo, porém eu hesito em classificar essa situação como excepcional, pois a conexão é perdida com frequência; se fosse aplicado o critério do Pragmatic Programmer o programa eventualmente cairia, isto é, "talvez seja uma não-exceção". Mas se entendi bem a questão não é se cai ou não cai e sim se a queda é regra ou exceção (ainda que frequente), correto?

Comment: @Piovezan O que determina se é exceção não é a frequência com que ocorre, tampouco se era esperado ou não, mas sim se **deveria** ou não acontecer. É difícil falar pelo projeto alheio, mas pelo que você disse eu acho que o sistema conta que uma conexão estabelecida é necessária; então eu faria um código que expressa que a conexão está lá disponível, e trataria a perda de conexão como exceção, assim como você fez.

Answer (score 15):

## Maturidade do *Design*

*Design* de código depende muitas variáveis: experiência, contexto, suporte da linguagem e provavelmente outras.

Particularmente, em várias situações acabo experimentando formas diferentes de implementar uma certa funcionalidade até chegar a uma que seja suficientemente "limpa e robusta o suficiente" para mim.

Porém, ideias de diferentes abordagens e o conhecimento sobre as consequências das decisões de *design* só vêm com o tempo, com a experiência de ver o código quebrando e entendendo os motivos disso ocorrer. (Por empresas boas procuram desenvolvedores que colocam o código em produção e não apenas os que codificam e deixam para outros corrigirem).

## Há uma certa convergência

Quanto ao uso de exceções nas diferentes linguagens, não creio que efetivamente haja uma diferença tão gritante entre o que programadores consideram um bom código, seja em Python, C# ou Java. Talvez se possa chegar a um consenso mais ou menos independente dos recursos oferecidos pela linguagem.

Primeiro, exceções não são apenas para erros em Java. Existe, por exemplo a exceção `InterruptedException` que pode ser disparada em determinados eventos de uma *thread*. Também podemos considerar as asserções de frameworks como JUnit como uma forma de indicar o estado do sistema.

## Controle de Fluxo

É preciso tomar cuidado com regras absolutas. Em geral, quando dizemos que *é errado tratar fluxo com exceções* na verdade deveríamos definir quais tipos de fluxos, pois muitos deles são inerentemente excepcionais.

Quando falamos em casos de uso, geralmente podemos subdividir um caso em um cenário principal, cenários alternativos e cenários excepcionais. Um trecho de código pode analogamente ser dividido da mesma forma. Há um fluxo principal do código, podem haver condicionais para determinar alternativas e tratamentos excepcionais que fazem parte do que é esperado pelo sistema.

### Fluxos condicionais

Imagine um sistema que exibe um campo que pode ou não ter valor:

```
try
    cliente.imprimeNome()
catch NomeVazioException e
    print "sem nome"
```

No exemplo, a função `imprimeNome()` lançaria uma exceção caso o campo não estivesse preenchido. Isso é ruim porque não faz sentido lançar uma exceção para verificar uma condição, é totalmente contra-intuitivo.

Um condicional seria bem melhor:

```
print cliente.isNomeEmpty() ? "sem nome" : cliente.getNome()
```

### Problemas de *Design*

Outro fator que leva a uso indevido de `try/catch` é um *design* ruim do código.

Considere:

```
try
    tentativa1();
catch Erro1 e1
    try
        tentativa2();
    catch Erro2 e2
        try
            tentativa2();
        catch Erro2 e2
            print "não deu"
```

O exemplo acima é "feio" em qualquer contexto, não porque seja uma tentativa de controlar o fluxo, mas porque cheira a problemas de *design* (*code smell*).

### Fluxos excepcionais

Existem situações onde exceções são boas para controlar o fluxo, afinal são fluxos naturalmente excepcionais.

Imaginemos um caso de validação:

```
try
    assertValid(cliente);
    cliente.save()
catch ValidationError e
    print e.errors()
```

O mesmo exemplo funcionaria perfeitamente com condicionais:

```
e = validate(cliente)
if e.hasErrors()
    cliente.save()
else 
    print e.errors()
```

Porém, seja Java ou qualquer outra linguagem, o primeiro exemplo é bem mais legível.

Além disso, não me parece "natural" retornar objetos de erro em métodos. Se um determinado cenário de erro retorna precisa retornar valores, então uma exceção deve ser cuidadosamente considerada para conter esses valores.

## Usando boas práticas quando não se devia

O exemplo de testar se um arquivo existe antes de acessá-lo ilustra perfeitamente o problema de tentar aplicar uma boa prática quando isso não deveria ser feito.

Considere o código:

```
if exists(file)
    read(file)
else 
    print "cannot read file"
```

Embora seja bem legível, há dois principais problemas:

1. O arquivo pode deixar de existir na segunda linha
2. O arquivo não existir é um cenário excepcional, então estaríamos fazendo o contrário: **tratando fluxo excepcional com condicionais**.

Portanto, é mais adequado fazer:

```
try
    read(file)
catch SomeFileException e
    print "cannot read file"
```

A vantagem de tratar exceções dessa forma também possibilita o tratamento múltiplo de várias condições simultaneamente. Não importa se o arquivo não existe, se está vazio ou se não há permissão de leitura ou de gravação, todos esses fluxos (em alguns casos) podem ser tratados especificamente num bloco `catch`. Um condicional aqui seria verboso e desnecessário.

## Granularidade das exceções

Particularmente, não gosto de exceções muito granulares ou específicas. Pelo menos até eu precisar que elas o sejam.

Também sou contra métodos que começam com um `try` e terminam com um `catch`, capturando qualquer exceção.

A melhor forma que eu conheço de codificar é definir grupos de exceções. Se for necessário um tratamento para um tipo específico de caso excepcional, então esse caso merece uma exceção própria.

Um exemplo comum disso refere-se a argumentos inválidos. Exemplo:

```
if param1 == null
    throw new IllegalArgumentException
```

Outro comum refere-se a erros de validação de campos. Muitas vezes fazemos validações assim:

```
if cliente.nome == null
    throw new ValidationError("name cannot be null")
```

Mas em certos casos um dos fluxos excepcionais merece tratamento isolado:

```
if findByCpf(cliente.cpf)
    throw new CpfJaCadastradoException
```

Nesse caso, um CPF já cadastrado poderia tomar alguma ação específica, como carregar os dados do cliente através do CPF.

## A visão do problema

Dependendo de como o domínio é modelado, podemos ter mais de uma implementação correta e coerente tanto do ponto de vista de regras de negócio quanto de codificação.

Exemplo 1:

```
try 
    transferencia(cliente1, cliente2, 10)
catch FundosInsuficientesException e
    print "sem saldo"
```

Exemplo 2:

```
if temSaldo(cliente1, 10) 
    transferencia(cliente1, cliente2, 10)
else 
    print "sem saldo"
```

Considerando que ambos os exemplos contém blocos transacionais e não permitem acesso concorrente às contas, então temos duas implementações válidas.

A primeira considera a falta de saldo como um cenário excepcional. Isso faria sentido, por exemplo, em funcionalidades onde o usuário já teria o saldo validado em uma tela anterior. Imagine que o sistema só mostra os valores para transferência que sejam menores do que o saldo atual. A possibilidade do usuário tentar fazer uma transferência maior que o saldo é um caso raro da conta ser movimentada enquanto ele selecione o valor a ser transferido.

A segunda considera que a falta de saldo é um cenário alternativo e esperado.

A diferença é mais semântica, relacionado ao entendimento do que é "alternativo" ou "excepcional". Em resumo, depende de como se enxerga o problema.

Answer (score 13):

## Exceções não devem ser usadas para controle de fluxo

Não há dúvida que exceções não devem ser usadas para controle de fluxo. Existe bastante literatura sobre isto. Inclusive todo programador Java deveria saber disto porque todos leram o livro do Joshua Bloch, [Effective Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch#Effective_Java) que deixa isto muito claro, ainda que a API nem sempre respeite este aspecto. Em C++ muitos guias de estilo proíbem o uso de exceções, até por questões técnicas específicas da linguagem. Em C# as pessoas mais envolvidas com a linguagem e programadores experientes costumam dizer o mesmo, mesmo que alguns livros e artigos menos respeitáveis digam o contrário.

## Exceções são controle de fluxo

Mas não vamos nos enganar. Exceção não é um controle de memória e não é um cálculo. É um controle de fluxo. E um dos mais difíceis de acompanhar e prever o que vai acontecer na aplicação, especialmente quando precisa depurá-la. Então não há essa dicotomia que a pergunta indica. Embora seja compreensível que ela exista. Existem muitos culpados por essa interpretação, inclusive eu ajudo um pouquinho.

## Vamos entender esta inconsistência

Eu resolvi responder porque eu [falo muitas vezes sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101%20exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20controle%20fluxo). O problema é que a definição é propositalmente bem vaga e não pode ser interpretada ao pé da letra. Ela é vaga porque não dá para definir muito bem o que é uma situação efetivamente excepcional e o que é um simples controle de fluxo que **pode ser melhor manipulado** sem o mecanismo de exceção. O segredo é definir se a situação é excepcional ou não.

É aí que provavelmente o Python é menos seletivo. É possível definir que qualquer coisa que não produza exatamente o resultado desejado é uma situação excepcional. E toda vez que um resultado não é o esperado tem que, no mínimo, considerar que haverá um controle de fluxo.

O problema é que em muitos casos é realmente esperado que o resultado seja fora do normal. Isto é excepcional ou não? Eu gostei da pergunta porque me fez refletir o quanto esta afirmação tão decantada é ideal para passar a ideia que se deseja. Veja bem, não estou dizendo que o conceito está errado, pelo contrário. O problema talvez esteja na frase simplista. Eu sei o que ela quer dizer, mas é fácil uma pessoa que ainda não entende totalmente o seu significado ter uma ideia equivocada do que ela significa.

## Performance também é importante

Existe uma questão de performance que deve ser considerada também. A exceção é um mecanismo lento, até o momento, em todas as linguagens. Cada uma com um compromisso diferente mas todas custam bem caro quando usadas. A maioria só tem um custo mais alto quando ela é lançada, embora, nenhuma tem custo zero só para marcar quando ela pode ser capturada. Quando o código que está sendo criado será usado, mesmo que potencialmente, em algo que exija o máximo de performance, fica claro que a exceção não pode ser usada. Inclusive se uma API é necessária e usa exceção, provavelmente o programador terá que criar uma alternativa personalizada. E convenhamos que qualquer coisa que tenha apenas um processamento básico e genérico tem potencial para ser usado em algo que exija performance.

Quando estamos lidando com recursos externos, quando a operação desejada envolve IO, incluindo UI, mesmo que indiretamente onde vai usar a exceção, a performance se torna menos relevante.

Performance é *feature*. Para algumas linguagens isto não é tão verdade. Em Python e outras linguagens dinâmicas e/ou pseudo compiladas não tem filosofia de ter o máximo da performance, então um dos motivos, que é a performance, para não usar exceção é irrelevante.

Todo mundo já sabe, ou deveria saber, que a performance não deveria ser buscada até que ela seja necessária. Eu imagino que Python parte do princípio que se você precisa evitar o custo da exceção então você está lascado com tantas outras coisas que a linguagem impõe ao seu código que esta não causará maiores problemas.

Java usa exceções em muitos casos em que a performance pode ser importante, por isto muitas vezes, se ela importar, provavelmente o programador terá que escrever uma nova API evitando o uso da exceção nela.

## Código expressivo

No par de pergunta e resposta citada acima na pergunta do autor original eu falo como existem outros mecanismos para lidar com resultados diferentes do normal e de como os outros mecanismos de controle de fluxo podem ser usados sem problemas. Mas tanto aqui na pergunta quanto lá, é mostrado que há casos que a exceção se torna fundamental, ou pelo menos torna o código mais expressivo quando ele a usa. Eu mostro no exemplo do acesso ao arquivo como é mais simples controlar a exceção do que ficar verificando cada erro para dar continuidade ao fluxo normal. Até porque não só pode ser necessário um `if` para cada linha, mas pode exigir que as linhas sejam quebradas para lidar com todos os problemas individualmente, o que provavelmente não é necessário.

Então se o uso da exceção torna o fluxo mais **eficaz** quando ocorre uma situação diferente, não é um problema em usá-la.

Também é preciso analisar se a **eficiência** não será comprometida em níveis impróprios.

O problema passa existir quando o programador não está usando ela de forma consciente. Ou quando ele cria uma exceção quando não sabe como ela será manipulada. Por isto algumas APIs de Java não são as mais adequadas. A linguagem tem a filosofia de ter performance, embora não no extremo, e também que não deve ser necessário o uso de outras linguagens auxiliares quando a performance é fundamental - ao contrário de Python que prega o auxílio de linguagem secundária nestes casos, provavelmente o C. Java tem APIs que que não garantem performance em coisas que exigem performance. Em muitas APIs especializadas em diversas linguagens isto ocorre também. Este é o erro.

Python também incentiva muito as coisas serem resolvidas em *runtime*, o que contribui para adotar esta filosofia. Linguagens como esta, para o bem ou para o mal, pensa na flexibilidade, o que traz imprevisibilidade, que é algo natural em exceções. Não adianta a linguagem dizer que preza pela previsibilidade quando ela possui mecanismos imprevisíveis em sua essência, começando por tipagem dinâmica. Então é mais um ponto que corrobora contra a filosofia.

Em resumo, exceções devem ser usadas quando você quer que elas sejam capturadas e manipuladas. Quando você está criando um mecanismo onde a exceção é mais adequada para lidar com o fluxo do que outros mecanismos mais simples. Repito o que sempre digo: faça o que você precisar, desde que saiba o que está fazendo, que entenda porque está fazendo, que tenha um ganho real sem ter um perda relevante. Não decore regras e sim entenda todo o processo.

## [Só tenho o martelo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument)

E não vamos nos enganar. Exceção é um mecanismo complicado. Ele é um [`goto`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101) na sua pior forma. O que me impressiona é a atitude de contrariedade de alguns programadores em relação ao `goto` que te manda ir para o centro da sua cidade, mas eles não se importam em te mandar para o centro de alguma cidade que sequer você sabe que existe e terá que descobrir em qual centro vai parar de acordo com o que a empresa de transportes te levar. Então, sim, ele deve ser evitado. Não à qualquer custo, mas conscientemente. Ele deve ser usado sempre que ele é a melhor solução, assim como no `goto`. Como o `goto` é mais simples, e talvez por ser algo mais antigo, existem mais formas de substituí-lo.

Mas linguagens mais modernas estão criando outros mecanismos para tornar a semântica do que se deseja mais expressivo. Mesmo hoje usamos a exceção quando a situação poderia ser manipulada de outra forma só porque falta uma ferramenta melhor.

Eu entendo que a pergunta tem um objetivo colateral de procurar melhores soluções para controlar o fluxo em situações que não sejam verdadeiramente excepcionais. Inclusive algumas linguagens possuem soluções melhores que exceções para controlar fluxo quando precisa ter uma ação consolidada para vários passos possíveis, como mostra o exemplo na resposta aceita. Ou seja, muitas vezes usamos exceções para controlar fluxo porque a linguagem não dá alternativa melhor.

Nem vou entrar na discussão que erros de programação não são situações excepcionais de fato. Java quase acertou em tratar isso de forma um pouco diferente. Não que iria mudar muita coisa mas seria interessante ter um mecanismo separado para tratar erros de programação que só podem ser detectados em tempo de execução.

Então novamente, não devemos usar exceções para controle de **fluxo normal**, até que a linguagem usada não ofereça uma ferramenta melhor. Aí somos obrigados a martelar com chave de fenda. Quando for criar uma linguagem considere isto. E considere também que ter diversos mecanismos para cada semântica possível no código complica a linguagem. Escolha seu *trade-off*.

## Conclusão

Só o programador pode definir se a situação é excepcional ou não. A mesma situação pode ser em uma aplicação e não ser excepcional em outra. Não será comum acontecer isto se houver consistência mas pode ser válido ter um tratamento diferente. Um dos problemas das APIs genéricas é que elas não consideram isto. Então ela pode ser muito adequada para usar em um código e inadequada em outro. Neste ponto faz sentido ter um [`Parse()` e um `TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101), apesar de ter esta "duplicação" também ser um problema.

Aprenda o porquê do mecanismo existir e evite o [*cargo cult*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

## Mecanismo alternativo

Por fim, por curiosidade, quero apresentar um mecanismo pouco conhecido que foi implementado na linguagem [Clipper](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper_(linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) que eu trabalhei boa parte da minha carreira e ainda uso indiretamente com o [Harbour](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harbour_(compilador)). Ela possui alguns mecanismos para lidar com situações que não é o fluxo normal, inclusive possui exceções, embora elas quase nunca são usadas.

O Clipper criou um mecanismo de tratamento de erro centralizado que funciona muito bem para o seu propósito. Clipper nunca teve intenção de resolver todos os problemas, mas resolver bem alguns. Por isto mesmo, com algumas limitações aparentes, ele funciona bem em aplicações de milhões de linhas e softwares escritos nele sobrevivem por décadas. Esse mecanismo usa uma espécie de *singleton* de erro que sabe como tratar cada tipo de erro. A linguagem não incentiva ficar criando tipos especializados. Então sempre que ocorre um erro, esse objeto é chamado para saber o que fazer. Muito provavelmente o que deve ser feito com um tipo de erro deve ser igual para toda aplicação, então ele funciona muito bem. E quando precisa de uma manipulação mais específica, é possível *setar* uma *lambda* com uma manipulação específica deste subsistema. O que, se pensar bem, pelo menos nesta parte, é parecido com o que o `try-catch` faz, ou como funciona outros mecanismos de outras linguagens, como o `scope` de D ou `defer` de Go. Então em vez de um `throw` que faz o *unwind* da pilha, ele chama uma ação personalizada. Isto é útil na imensa maioria das situações em que você precisa fazer algo próximo do erro, ou seja, você quer apenas executar algo, não quer desmontar a aplicação. Este sistema de erros permite continuar a execução, retentar ou abortar e aí sim fará o *unwind*, se necessário.

É possível usar algo semelhante na maioria das linguagens, apenas criando uma biblioteca e adotando certos padrões. Claro que nem todas linguagens permitirão isso funcionar da melhor forma possível.

Reforço que esse mecanismo não substitui a exceção mas cria uma forma para lidar com certos problemas. O fato é que se a linguagem tem mecanismos melhores, eles devem ser usados e a exceção deve ser deixada só quando ela realmente é a melhor solução.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

É uma questão muito relativa (linguagem, cultura, comunidade, ...) e, com base no meu conhecimento, minha resposta tende a ser: depende. Há casos e casos, por exemplo, posso responder por Java:

Não preciso checar com uma expressão regular (ou um monte de ifs) se uma string qualquer pode ser transformada em uma data, posso simplesmente tentar formata-la e capturar a exceção `ParseException` em caso de problemas. Mas, sim, preciso checar se um elemento é nulo ao invés de genericamente capturar `NullPointerException`´s pelo meu código, afinal manter o contrato de uma API ajuda na manutenção do código, em sua testabilidade e potencializa sua qualidade (evitando erros). Como tu mesmo disse, lidar com pré e pós condições é uma forma de resolver esse problema e, usando seu exemplo, você pode sim testar se o arquivo existe e, ainda assim, tratar a exceção, não é redundante:

- arquivo não existe; testa a pré condição -> código não é executado
  e exceção não é gerada
- arquivo existe; testa a pré condição; arquivo é apagado durante o
  teste -> código é executado e exceção é gerada
- arquivo existe; testa a pré condição; arquivo não é apagado
  durante o teste -> código é executado e exceção não é  gerada

são 3 possibilidades e apenas em uma delas a exceção é gerada, sem o teste, seriam 2.

Isso é design. Lidar com try/catchs é design. A comunidade (Java) aprendeu que código limpo é importante, que quantidade de linhas de código não são desde que favoreçam o design.

Mas, como disse, depende. E isso tende a gerar [muito mais especulação](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=eafp%20versus%20lbyl) por não ser algo exato e sim uma boa prática que varia conforme a linguagem e sua comunidade.

Comment: Gostei do exemplo da data, em suma você quer dizer que "se o custo do teste é mais alto que o *overhead* da exceção, mais simples usar a exceção" (além do código ficar mais limpo, é claro). Quanto ao arquivo, o problema que vejo é de DRY: meu código para tratar do caso em que o arquivo não existe, terei de repeti-lo tanto no `else` quanto no `catch`? Há muitos casos em que a repetição é uma coisa sensata (ex.: `if(x) synchronized { if(x) { ... } }` mas em geral eu vejo valor em se manter o código conciso e expressivo.

Comment: E em C# você usa **DateTime.TryParse**, não precisa usar um fluxo de exceção.

Comment: @Caffé Bom contraponto, vejo que unir um código de erro com um parâmetro de saída leva vantagem sobre ambas as abordagens. De novo, é esse tipo de argumentação que estou buscando, detestaria que o enfoque excessivo nas duas linguagens citadas nos cegasse para a consideração de uma terceira alternativa.

Comment: @mgipsonbr, mais ou menos, mas podemos concluir que a ordem de relevância deve ser primeiro o design e depois o overhead - quando este não seja impactante. A linguagem Java me diz (através da diferença de exceções checadas e não checadas) que eu posso me recuperar de um ParseException, tratando. Mas que um NullPointerException será sempre um erro de programação.