# Tratar regras de negócio no model é uma má prática?

Tags: java, mvc, design-pattern, arquitetura-de-software

Isso é algo que pode parecer simples, mas não é. Afinal como definir se um regra deve ficar na camada de serviço ou no próprio model?

Para exemplificar, pense no seguinte:

Temos uma matriz onde se encontra um jogo de xadrez. Toda vez que o usuário movimenta uma peça (X, Y) é necessário validar se a peça em questão está dentro do tabuleiro. Aí vem a questão: Temos a situação de lançar uma exceção caso o usuário esteja efetuando um movimento inválido.

O ideal seria lançar essa exceção pelo model e ir capturando em toda a pilha até o usuário? Ou então efetuar essa regra na camada de serviço? A questão é que temos toda a parte de incremento e movimentação dos eixos X, Y dentro do model, logo seria necessário repetir parte da lógica na camada de serviço.

**A pergunta: Nesse caso é conveniente deixar essa regra no model, ou replicar parte da mesma para o serviço seria o ideal?**

Comment: Mas o que é "camada de serviço" aqui? Você está falando do *Controller* (o *C* do *MCV*)?

Comment: Isso exatamente, é a camada de controller ou serviço.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Esqueça os padrões (por um momento)

Certos problemas específicos são resolvidos melhor se não tentarmos encaixar tudo em algum padrão. MVC não é uma bala de prata, é um modelo, um guia que nos ajudar a organizar melhor sistemas complexos. Camadas consistem numa divisão lógica de responsabilidades, mas às vezes é melhor considerar melhor a interação entre objetos sem usar papéis e estereótipos fixos.

Porém, existem muitos cenários, como acredito ser este em questão, em que o problema é resolvido mais adequadamente com pura orientação a objetos. Jogos e outros casos específicos comumente caem nesta categoria, com exceção, obviamente, da interface com o usuário.

No fim, quase sempre isso acaba no `Model`, mas vamos esquecer disso por um momento.

## Crie sua API

Uma forma de pensar no problema é utilizando uma abstração, no caso, uma interface que funcione como uma API e disponibilize a funcionalidade necessária para o restante do sistema.

Vamos fazer um exercício de modelagem!

Bem, estamos falando de um **jogo**, composto por um **tabuleiro** e suas **peças**, jogado por dois **jogadores** (mesmo que sejam virtuais). Parece razoável pensar nas classes:

- `Jogo`
- `Tabuleiro`
- `Peca`
- `Jogador`

Para começar um novo jogo, poderíamos requerer os dados dos jogadores ou, se for necessário continuar um jogo salvo, requerer também um tabuleiro. Por exemplo:

```
class JogoBuilder {
    Jogo comecar(Jogador j1, Jogador j2);
    Jogo continuar(Jogador j1, Jogador j2, Tabuleiro t);
}
```

Aqui entra uma questão de gosto. Eu poderia omitir o primeiro método e considerar que para começar um novo jogo somente seria necessário passar um tabuleiro no estado inicial. Por exemplo:

```
class JogoBuilder {
    Jogo iniciar(Jogador j1, Jogador j2, Tabuleiro t);
}
```

Poderia ainda haver um parâmetro para definir de quem é a vez:

```
enum QuemJoga { J1, J2 }

class JogoBuilder {
    Jogo iniciar(Jogador j1, Jogador j2, Tabuleiro t, QuemJoga q);
}
```

Precisaríamos de uma forma de construir o tabuleiro:

```
class TabuleiroBuilder {
    Tabuleiro carregar(JogoSalvo j);
    Tabuleiro criarNovo(); //tabuleiro na posição inicial
}
```

Pensando em termos de API, a classe `Jogo` precisa disponibilizar determinados serviços para um código cliente, que pode ser um sistema web, desktop, mobile ou mesmo um web service. Algo assim:

```
class Jogo {
    Tabuleiro getTabuleiro();
    Jogador getJogador1();
    Jogador getJogador2();
    QuemJoga getQuemJogaAgora();
}
```

A interface de `Jogo` agora nos permite saber qual o estado do tabuleiro, quem são os jogadores e quem pode fazer o próximo movimento. Tudo o que é necessário para representar o jogo. Porém, falta algo para que se possa efetivamente jogar.

Bem, o responsável pelas posições das pessoas é claramente o `Tabuleiro`. Mas, para representar bem o tabuleiro, precisamos saber o que tem em cada **posição**.

```
class Posicao {
    byte getLinha();
    byte getColuna();
    Optional<Peca> getPeca(); //pode ou não haver uma peça
}
```

Para representar o tabuleiro, poderíamos chegar a algo assim:

```
class Tabuleiro {
    Posicao[][] getPosicoes(); //permite imprimir o tabuleiro
    Posicao getPosicao(byte linha, byte, coluna); //permite olhar uma posição específica
}
```

Na hora de movimentar, o jogador precisa selecionar a peça e a posição para onde vai movimentá-la. A seleção da peça é uma questão de UI e não devemos abordar isso na API. Vamos imaginar que a UI guarda a referência para a peça na posição selecionada e depois ela pode informar nossa API qual peça será movimentada.

No entanto, como a UI pode determinar para onde a peça pode ser movimentada? Devemos fazer uma nova chamada para a API a cada tentativa e emitir um alerta em caso de erro. Uma abordagem diferente seria listar as possibilidades de movimento. Por exemplo:

```
class Tabuleiro {
    ...
    Posicao[] getPossibilidadesMovimento(Posicao p);
}
```

O método acima recebe a posição selecionada pelo usuário e determina quais os possíveis movimentos. Agora, a UI pode fazer algo mágico como destacar os possíveis destinos assim que o usuário seleciona uma peça para mover.

Caso haja necessidade de testar se um movimento é válido, a API pode fornecer outro método:

```
class Tabuleiro {
    ...
    boolean ehMovimentoValido(Posicao atual, Posicao desejada);
}
```

Mas em geral não é necessário fazer isso.

Por fim, para movimentar a peça:

```
class Tabuleiro {
   ...
   void movimentarPeca(Posicao atual, Posicao nova) throws MovimentoInvalidoException;
}
```

Note que na modelagem acima, eu tomei duas decisões importantes:

1. Não encapsular o movimento. Uma alternativa seria criar uma classe `Movimento` para encapsular as posições. Não fiz isso porque não vejo outro atributo que possa ser requerido, mas se no futuro o movimento pudesse ter algo a mais do que as duas posições pode ser uma vantagem ter um novo objeto.
2. Tratar um movimento inválido como erro. Fiz isso neste caso porque minha API foi projetada para dar as opções de movimento, então, em teoria, um movimento inválido não deveria ocorrer e é um erro. Sem, por outro lado, eu deixar o jogador ficar tentando mudar a posição da peça em qualquer lugar do tabuleiro, talvez seja melhor trocar isso por um retorno de sucesso ou fracasso.

Para colocar a cereja no bolo, um último passo seria atualizar a classe `Jogo` com o método que permite o jogador efetivamente jogar:

```
class Jogo {
    ....
    void jogar(Jogador atual, Posicao atual, Posicao nova) throws MovimentoInvalidoException, NaoEhAVezDesseJogadorException;
}
```

O método acima deve validar se o jogador atual é o dono da peça. Se tudo estiver ok, ele move a peça e muda a vez para o outro jogador.

Um possível problema dessa implementação é que `Tabuleiro` é mutável, então alguém poderia fazer isso:

```
jogo.getTabuleiro().movimentarPeca(...);
```

Isso poderia afetar o estado do tabuleiro sem que `Jogo` faça as validações adequadas e atualize o estado do jogo atual. Há duas formas de resolver isso:

1. Fazer o método `Jogo.getTabuleiro` retornar um tabuleiro imutável. Isso faz com que somente seja possível afetar o tabuleiro pela interface de `Jogo`.
2. Fazer com que cada mudança no `Tabuleiro` crie um outro tabuleiro. Essa abordagem é mais "custosa" e termos de memória, mas permitiria, por exemplo, que tivéssemos o histórico dos movimentos.

No caso da segunda abordagem, poderíamos mudar o método `movimentarPeca` de `Tabuleiro` da seguinte forma:

```
class Tabuleiro {
   ...
   Tabuleiro movimentarPeca(Posicao atual, Posicao nova) throws MovimentoInvalidoException;
}
```

Assim, a cada movimento, um novo `Tabuleiro` é retornado com o novo estado e o Jogo passa a apontar para esse novo objeto, talvez armazenando o anterior numa lista, que permitiria fazer o *replay* do jogo posteriormente.

Tudo pronto! E ao mesmo tempo nada pronto! Agora é ***só*** implementar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Agora volte aos padrões

Depois que o *core* do jogo estiver bem modelado podemos voltar a pensar em como modelar o sistema em camadas e aplicar o padrão MVC, criar a lógica de controle e o visual do aplicativo.

Comment: +1 pelo troll face :D

Comment: +1 Bacana demonstrar uma linha de raciocínio para desenvolver o core do jogo, por assim dizer (para "esquecer a palavra *modelar* por um momento" hehehe).

Answer (score 15):

Correndo o risco de estar dando uma resposta opinativa, eu diria que o ideal é colocá-la no model, pois o model é a camada que representa (ou deveria representar) o estado da sua aplicação, o seu domínio e as suas regras de negócio, enquanto que a finalidade da camada de serviços é apenas prover um canal de integração entre o seu modelo/domínio e o mundo externo a ele.

Ou seja, na minha opinião isso não é uma má prática. Muito pelo contrário, não fazer isso é que é uma má prática.

Comment: Toda e qualquer resposta desse tópico será opinativa. Mesmo pessoas quem trabalham a milhares de anos pode descordar, não existe resposta exata. Por isso até a dúvida

Comment: A questão é temos o model Peça, por exemplo, esse possui os seus atributos, uma série de get e set e etc... e ai começamos a incluir código relacionado a negócio nele. Existe uma preocupação minha que mais cedo ou mais tarde, com o aumentar da complexidade esse model fique grande demais, com muito mais código relacionado a regra do que propriamente do objeto. Por mais que a regra seja do objeto... rsrs é um tema polêmico

Comment: @EmirMarques Acho que você está começando a entrar nisso: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model

Comment: +1, e bom ver você participando novamente.

Answer (score 13):

Vou confirmar o que disse o Victor. E complementar que *model* não significa uma classe que engloba tudo o que precisa em um *controller* ou uma *view*. Se começar modelar pensando em como será usado no *controller* ou *view* numa relação 1:1, estará fazendo errado ou acertará por coincidência.

O modelo deve facilitar o acesso às informações que precisa, mas não retratar tudo o que precisa. Este é um erro que começou ser adotado por muitos por causa da regra pela regra. As pessoas aprendem que "*em orientação a objeto devemos colocar tudo relacionado ao objeto junto dele*". Isto não é verdade. Você pode ter regras na mesma classe mas isto engessa o sistema. Você precisa ter formas de acessar as regras, não importa como eles tenham sido montadas.

Na verdade quase toda modelagem OO que vemos por aí está errada. Às vezes funciona. Às vezes parece que funciona e o programador nem se dá conta, passa anos sem perceber o rolo onde está metido. E às vezes dá muito errado e o programador, quando tem uma mínima percepção de que aquilo está ruim vai procurar ajuda, onde receberá boas e más orientações. Com sorte ele aprenderá padrões de projeto úteis, e tem uma chance aplicá-los como deve ser e não de forma *formulesca*.

O que eu posso garantir é que [se for replicar algo no código, estará fazendo algo muito errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101)<sup>1</sup>.

E quando começa ter camada demais, tem outro problema também. Muitas vezes a replicação só é necessária por arquitetura errada. Mas sem ver o caso concreto, é difícil dizer.

É uma pena que vai lançar um exceção para um caso de movimento inválido. [Isto não é uma situação excepcional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101). Mas em Java as pessoas acham que qualquer coisa é excepcional, não sei se tem muito como mudar isto na cabeça das pessoas se a linguagem incentiva isto.

<sup>1</sup> Claro que há uma situação terrível onde a duplicação é necessária. Se está fazendo algo para web e precisa fazer uma validação, por exemplo, no cliente, além da verificação no servidor, por se tratar de linguagens diferentes, terá que replicar código. O ideal seria usar uma ferramenta que automatizasse isto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 7):

## Tratar regras de negócio no Model é uma má prática?

Pelo contrário. O Model é o lugar certo para as regras de negócio.

## Sendo preciosista

A validação de se a peça foi parar fora do tabuleiro é uma regra de negócio e precisa estar no Model sob pena de o Model ficar em um estado inválido, e é função do próprio Model garantir o seu estado.

## Lançar exceção? Sendo ainda mais preciosista

O Model pode ter dois méotodos distintos para cada tentativa de movimento do usuário.

O primeiro método verifica se o movimento é válido.

Depois de consumir este primeiro método para testar se o movimento é válido, o Controller finalmente consome o método que executa o movimento de fato.

Mas, a rigor, este segundo método ainda deve lançar uma exceção no caso de movimento inválido pois, como eu disse, é função do Model garantir o seu estado. A não ser que você opte por um design todo baseado em código de erro. <sub>Tag Opinião: não vejo nenhuma vantagem. Fecha tag Opinião.</sub> Veja esta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48458/14584.

## Por que a regra estaria no Controller?

Se Controller e Model estão ambos no lado do servidor, não tem vantagem escrever uma regra de negócio no Controller em vez de escrever no Model.

Controller deve conter apenas regras de aplicativo.

## Replicar regras?

Sim, dependendo da experiência que você quer dar ao usuário. **Mas não replicar entre o Controller e o Model!** A não ser que eu não tenha entendido algum aspecto particular da sua arquitetura, replicar regras entre Controller e Model não faz sentido.

Eventualmente, você pode querer replicar regras do Model na camada mais alta do sistema - o navegador, por exemplo.

Digamos que você não queira gastar uma requisição ao servidor nem fazer o usuário esperar por esta requisição cada vez que ele solta sem querer uma peça em um lugar não permitido - você vai acabar tendo que fazer isso também no lado do cliente, embora a rigor esta seja uma regra do Model. Ou seja: terá código com o mesmo objetivo em dois lugares. Pois é.

Alguns frameworks geram automaticamente códigos de validação para o lado do cliente, baseado em validações declaradas no Model.

## Mas afinal, como fazer?

Depende do objetivo do seu projeto.

É um exercício escolar? Então aproveite para exercitar padrões e boas práticas e veja como é doloroso aplicá-los.

É um portal para aficcionados encomendado por um cliente real e que precisa entregar cedo? Você pode aproveitar para ignorar padrões e boas práticas e ver como é doloroso dar continuidade no projeto.

Enfim, há muitas maneiras de fazer, mas você não deve se arrepender de usar a forma padrão: regras de negócio estão no Model, regras de aplicativo estão no Controller e algumas validações podem estar replicadas no lado do cliente para melhorar a experiência do usuário.

Comment: O  que é regras de aplicativo? E qual é a diferença entre regra de aplicativo e regra de negócio?

Comment: @DenerCarvalho Acho que já expliquei isso algumas vezes em comentários - parece ser uma dúvida comum. Será que cabe uma pergunta nova aqui no SO?

Comment: Sim, seria melhor pergunta mesmo, vou fazer a pergunta.

Comment: Da uma olhada na [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117697/o-que-%C3%A9-regras-de-aplicativo-e-quais-s%C3%A3os-as-diferen%C3%A7as-em-rela%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-as-regras), se precisar editar deixa um comentário. Depois eu apagado meus comentários.

Answer (score 3):

Cabe no Model sim, o problema é que alguns frameworks equipararam o Model com o banco de dados, ou uma representação dele (ORM), aí automaticamente fica parecendo que o Controller deveria implementar as regras de negócio.

Assim que se precisar portar o aplicativo para outra plataforma (e.g. de mobile para Web) quaisquer regras de negócio implementadas no Controller teriam de ser reimplementadas...

Quando na verdade abaixo do Model continua havendo uma camada a mais que é o banco de dados ou armazenamento, afinal dificilmente alguém implementa um banco do zero. O Controller deve ser apenas um verniz que acopla Model e View.