# É correto um método lançar a mesma exceção por dois motivos diferentes?

Tags: java, exceção, engenharia-de-software, testes-de-unidade, tdd

Estou praticando TDD simulando uma central de alarme. Centrais de alarme funcionam conectadas a sensores que detectam intrusão (abertura de uma porta ou janela, ou movimento dentro de uma sala, por exemplo). Elas possuem um número fixo de partições lógicas (representando diferentes locais a serem protegidos) e de *slots* para sensores. No ato da instalação os sensores são associados às respectivas partições. Então a interface da minha central de alarme inclui os seguintes métodos (obs.: "armar" uma partição significa protegê-la, isto é, a central irá disparar o alarme se um sensor da partição for acionado, e "desarmar" significa desproteger, isto é, ignorar o acionamento dos sensores da partição):

```
public interface InterfaceDeCentralDeAlarme {
    boolean armarParticao(int numero) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException;
    boolean desarmarParticao(int numero) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException;
    void associarSensorAParticao(int sensor, int particao) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException;
    void desassociarSensorDeParticao(int sensor, int particao) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException;
    ...
}
```

Aqui estão alguns dos possíveis testes unitários:

```
@Test(expected=IllegalStateException.class)
public void particaoSemSensoresAssociadosNaoPodeArmar() {
    InterfaceDeCentralDeAlarme central = criarCentralDeAlarme();
    central.armarParticao(1);
}

@Test(expected=IllegalStateException.class)
public void particaoJaArmadaNaoPodeArmar() {
    InterfaceDeCentralDeAlarme central = criarCentralDeAlarme();
    central.associarSensorAParticao(1, 1);
    central.fecharSensor(1);
    Assert.assertTrue(central.armarParticao(1));
    central.armarParticao(1);
}
```

O método `armarParticao()` delega o arme para uma classe chamada `Particao`. Até aí, nada de mais:

```
@Override
public boolean armarParticao(int numero) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException {
    Particao particao = particoes.get(numero);
    if (particao == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    return particao.armar();
}
```

Na classe `Particao` criei um método público `armar()` que pode lançar `IllegalStateException` por dois motivos distintos, isto é, duas situações distintas em que o objeto se encontra num estado indevido. Uma é quando a partição já está armada; outra é quando a partição não possui sensores associados a ela (ou seja, não tem como detectar intrusão):

```
public class Particao {

    private final Map<Integer, Sensor> sensores = new HashMap<>();
    private boolean armada = false;

    public boolean armar() throws IllegalStateException {
        if (armada) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Partição já se encontra armada");
        }

        if (sensores.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Partição não possui sensor associado");
        }

        for (Sensor sensor : sensores.values()) {
            if (sensor.isAberto() && false == sensor.isInibido()) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        this.armada = true;
        return true;
    }

    ...
}
```

Do ponto de vista dos testes unitários e do TDD, isso é ruim? Um colega disse que sim, pois se o método lançar uma `IllegalStateException` eu nunca vou ter certeza se é por causa de um motivo ou por causa do outro. A exceção lançada pode mascarar uma situação diferente da que estou tentando testar.

Porém, não tenho certeza se isso chega a ser um problema. Talvez seja se eu não tiver testes para todas as situações possíveis (incluindo as duas situações em que `IllegalStateException` pode ser lançada). Mas se eu tiver, talvez esse *overlap* não chegue a ser problemático. Na prática, ao se escrever testes unitários ou fazendo TDD as pessoas têm o costume de evitar isso (lançar a mesma exceção num método em duas situações diferentes)?

Segunda pergunta: se eu tiver que usar exceções distintas, convém criar exceções customizadas (novas classes) para cada uma das situações, ou essa é uma decisão mais ou menos arbitrária? A(s) exceção(ões) criada(s) devem ser subclasses de `IllegalStateException`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> A pergunta foi modificada depois da resposta

Tudo em engenharia precisa ser pensado para o que está fazendo. Pra variar a resposta é um enorme DEPENDE.

A primeira coisa é se perguntar se realmente fará diferença ter situações diferentes. Muitas vezes só precisa saber que a exceção ocorreu, não precisa saber a situação exata, então pode conviver com isto. Se for o caso, poderia, mas não necessariamente, reescrever assim:

```
 if (condicao1 || condicao2) throw new IllegalStateException("Falhou devido à condição");
```

## O teste precisa ser adequado

Se não pode facilitar sua vida, uma das soluções é fazer o teste identificar os detalhes da exceção, se isso é importante.

Exemplo:

```
try {
    executarAcao();
} catch (Exception e) {
    assertThat(e).isInstanceOf(IllegalStateException.class)
                 .hasMessage("Falhou devido à condição 1");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/Assert.java).

O Junit tem o [`expectMessage()`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html#expectMessage(java.lang.String)) para isso. Acredito que a maioria dos bons *frameworks* possuem facilidades semelhantes.

Também pode usar anotação `expected=IllegalStateException.class, message = "Falhou devido à condição 1"`.

É normal que um método lance mais de uma exceção igual e precisa ser testado, por isso há facilidades para testar. Se o teste precisa fazer isso, faça e teste apropriadamente.

## O método está errado

Outra solução é lançar exceções diferentes mais personalizadas.

Há quem diga que isso sempre deveria ser feito, que exceções genéricas não são boas. Outros acham exagero. Depende do caso. Se for mudar um pequeno detalhe, pode ser exagero mesmo, mas se for coisa pouco relacionada, então pode ser o caso. Pode estar usando uma exceção genérica por "preguiça". Lembre que tem gente que só lança `Exception`, aí o problema é outro. Lançar `IllegalStateException` pode cair no mesmo problema, mesmo não sendo tão aparente. Também pode ser o certo para o caso.

Se elas devem ser subclasses ou não, depende do caso. Esse pode ser um que deve, pelo que aparenta, mas é claro que é um exemplo bem hipotético. Eu não diria que é uma decisão arbitrária, é uma decisão individual.

Note que o problema aí é de *design* do método*. Se é isso, resolva esse problema. A solução anterior é resolver o *design* do teste, que deve ser o preferido se o seu método está correto.

Depois da edição da pergunta dá para perceber que o método tem problemas diferentes. No mínimo um deles não é um estado ilegal, é só um estado que impede a operação. O que remete que a exceção está sendo usada como **regra de negócio** (entendo que seja comum em Java fazer isso, mas eu iria por [outro caminho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101)). A outra pode, mas não necessariamente, existir por uma falha da classe, talvez não deveria existir o objeto com estado ilegal. Se tudo estiver certo, as exceções são completamente diferentes. O erro não é dificultar o teste, é especificação errada. Mas posso ter interpretado errado.

Acho um absurdo as pessoas mudarem seu código principal para atender uma demanda de teste. Você deve permitir o teste, eventualmente até facilitar, mas nunca ao custo da responsabilidade principal do seu código. Tem quem discorde, mas eu acho um erro programar para o teste. Fazer algo testável, ok, mas o código deve ser feito para atender a especificação.

## Conclusão

Até onde eu sei as pessoas não evitam lançar a mesma exceção não, se o método precisa, deve fazer. E vejo como algo bem comum. Não sei se tem outras soluções melhores.

O exemplo da pergunta mostra como TDD é um treco complicado. Ele funciona bem quando: (a) o problema é amplamente conhecido e possui especificação muito boa (raro); (b) um gênio da arquitetura o fez.

Teve a curiosidade de perguntar para o colega qual é a solução? Talvez ele não saiba do que está falando, mesmo acertando :). Lembre-se que muita gente lê sobre algo ser "boa ou má prática" em algum lugar, repete o que "viu", mas não entende o problema. Obviamente não sei se é o caso.

Comment: Essa recomendação _"Se for mudar um pequeno detalhe, pode ser exagero mesmo, mas se for coisa pouco relacionada, pode ser o caso"_ me soou um pouco vaga, por culpa da pergunta mesmo, que não mostrou um caso concreto. Vou detalhar mais o cenário para, se você achar que é o caso, deixar a resposta mais direcionada. Mas já estou bem satisfeito com ela.

Comment: Na verdade é complicado o que você fez porque apesar de ter mantido o assunto, a pergunta é completamente outra. Amanhã eu dou uma olhada.

Comment: Não era minha intenção mudar a pergunta, apenas especificar a situação. Tudo bem, amanhã a gente vê o que faz com ela. E respondendo sua pergunta, meu colega não especificou como lidar com as exceções e deixou isso ao meu encargo, apenas recomendou que eu lançasse duas exceções distintas.

Comment: A minha pergunta é retórica :)

Comment: No fim acho que a pergunta não mudou tanto assim, deu pra manter a maior parte da resposta original. :) Entendi que um código de erro pode ser melhor para o caso da partição já armada, enquanto que a outra situação pode nem precisar existir, na verdade não é requisito da classe que essas associações sejam dinâmicas; a classe poderia ser inicializada com os sensores associados às partições já na construção (acho que é isso que você queria dizer, não?). Essa fartura de `throws IllegalStateException` na interface pode até ser considerado um _code smell_.

Comment: Isso mesmo. Mas é óbvio que só você pode confirmar se isto é possível. Eu acho que é *code smell*, nem todos acham. Cada um com sua visão, né?... :) Embora *code smell* não signifique erro, claro. Mas o mais importante é que se quiser manter a classe assim, viu que dá para testar. Se a pergunta tivesse assim desde o princípio, eu poderia ter feito algo mais próximo de cara, não quis mexer muito no que já havia escrito.

Comment: Esticando a pergunta um pouco, e as `IllegalArgumentException`, você manteria? E quanto ao TDD estar errado, na verdade eu nem fiz o TDD direito, estou fazendo uma experiência misturando teste pós-design com um pouco de TDD e vendo como afeta meu design. Mas realmente é polêmico dizer que "se o TDD é a especificação, então ele está errado", porque eu tenho a impressão que é justamente isso que o TDD se propõe a ser.

Comment: Eu não, mas eu sou meio radical no uso de exceções :) Eu evitaria uma delas ser lançada garantido o estado adequado e a outra eu acharia um jeito de notificar de outra forma que já está armado, mas eu entendo que isto não é comum em Java, a exceção é preferida, as pessoas estão até mais acostumadas com isto. Eu sou contra TDD em quase todas situações. O seu TDD está errado :) Ele especifica algo que não deveria estar no método (publicamente). Claro que falo do caso de fazer o que eu acho que deve, não lançar estas exceções. O TDD as especificou, certo?

Comment: A `IllegalArgumentException` que eu falo no caso é quando chamo `armarParticao(int)` passando um número de partição inválido. E eu não tenho certeza se ela está na assinatura do método por causa do TDD, acho que não. As `IllegalStateException` sim, mas posso muito bem estar fazendo errado. Na verdade acho que eu deveria parar com esse negócio de fazer o TDD pela metade. Mas a discussão e os insights que isso gera são tão produtivos. :)

Comment: Mas TDD deveria especificar tudo que é público, não? Esse é mais um motivo pra eu não gostar de TDD, cada um acha uma coisa sobre o assunto :D

Comment: Sim, deveria especificar tudo o que é público. Não estou dizendo que o que eu fiz foi o TDD correto... eu não segui à risca o que propõe o TDD. Eu não sei se estou preparado para abraçar o TDD. Acho meio religioso esse negócio de "siga os três passinhos sem questionar e o seu código atingirá a iluminação". Meio mágico isso do design sair correto e a produtividade aumentar no longo prazo apesar de diminuir no curto. Mas a gente experimenta né.

Comment: Eu havia interpretado que no caso da partição já armada deveria usar código de erro porque é uma regra de negócio. Lendo mais sobre o assunto vi que na verdade isso não é um problema em si, o código de erro na verdade é recomendável por se tratar de uma situação prevista de acontecer. Exceções de negócio são aceitáveis desde que sejam exceção e não regra, e podem inclusive [melhorar a expressividade do código em fluxos com muitas etapas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48458/357).