# Por que fazer uso de exceções em Python utilizando o raise?

Tags: python, exceção

Por exemplo:

```
class ListaUnica(object):
    def __init__(self, tipo):
        self.tipo = tipo
        self.lista = []
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.lista)
    def __getitem__(self, p):
        return self.lista[p]
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.lista)
    def indice_valido(self, i):
        return 0 <= i < len(self.lista)
    def verifica(self, elemento):
        if self.tipo != type(elemento):
            raise TypeError('Tipo inválido !')
    def pesquisa(self, elemento):
        self.verifica(elemento)
        try:
            return self.lista.index(elemento)
        except ValueError:
            return -1
    def adiciona(self, elemento):
        if self.pesquisa(elemento) == -1:
            self.lista.append(elemento)
    def remove(self, elemento):
        if self.pesquisa(elemento) != -1:
            self.lista.remove(elemento)
```

- Por que subir uma exceção?
- O programador não deveria fazer de tudo para que uma exceção não ocorra?
- Qual a utilidade de subir uma exceção?
- A exceção não para a execução do programa?
- Logo, quando se faz necessária?

Comment: Quando você sobe uma exceção você está deixando para tratar ela na camada de cima da sua aplicação. Vamos supor que um método do seu DAO lança uma exceção, vc sobe ela e trata com o catch apenas quando o método for invocado.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Exceções devem ser usadas para controle de fluxo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48410/exce%c3%a7%c3%b5es-devem-ser-usadas-para-controle-de-fluxo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Por que subir uma exceção?

Essa é idêntica à última pergunta, vamos contextualizar as coisas primeiro.

> O programador não deveria fazer de tudo para que uma exceção não ocorra?

Na verdade, não. O programador deve fazer de tudo para que o programa não dê uma resposta incorreta. As exceções ajudam com esse cenário.

Então, vamos pensar, por exemplo, num script que o administrador do sistema rode manualmente para fazer um back-up. Se esse script parar com uma execeção, e vocẽ conseguir ler na mensagem apresentada que o disco de destino está cheio, isso é muito, muito melhor do que o script terminar sem uma mensagem de erro, mas não fazer o back-up.

Agora sim, via de regra, em algum ponto no seu programa deve haver um bloco do tipo "try:...except:" que captura todas as exceções possíveis, e apresenta uma mensagem apropriada para o usuário.

No exemplo que eu dei, de um script executado direto pelo administrador, isso é menos importante do que, por exemplo, num sistema Web, em que deve ser apresentado para o usuário uma página do tipo "ocorreu um erro interno no servidor, por favor contate o administrador", ou num jogo em que pode aparecer a mensagem "operação não realizada: tente novamente".

Em nenhum desses casos poderia acontecer da operação não ser bem sucedida e o usuário não ser informado.

Agora, dentro de um bloco "try: except:", dependendo da natureza da operação e da exceção, o próprio programa pode fazer uma tentativa de repetir a operação.(Por exemplo, numa requisição a um servidor externo que dê um timeout, o programa pode refazer a requisição).

> Qual a utilidade de subir uma exceção?

A maior utilidade é "desviar o código para outra camada, onde você tem que se preocupar com o erro". Basicamente é isso: uma exceção pode sair de vários "if" aninhados, de vários "for" e "retornar" de um número arbitrário de funções - até um ponto no código em que faça sentido relatar o erro ao usuário, ou tentar uma correção automática.

Vamos tomar por exemplo a linguagem C, que não tem exceções. Nela se convenciona que quando uma função não pode cumprir seu papel - por exemplo, não tem memória o suficiente, ela tem que retornar um valor pré-determinado para indicar esse erro.

Agora, vamos supor que eu estou fazendo um programa que codifica música em MP3 - ele tem essas funções em pesudo-código, uma chamando a outra. Eu poderia precisar então  das chamadas nessa ordem (com mais código em cada função onde estão os `...`:

```
interagir_com_usuario() {
    codificar_musica();
}

codificar_musica(...) {
    ...
    ler_arquivo_original(...);
    ...
}

ler_arquivo_original(...) {
   ...
   reservar_memoria(...);
   ...
}

reservar_memoria(...) {
   ...
   malloc(xxx);
   ...
}
```

Agora, se não há memória suficiente, é essa última chamada, à `malloc` que vai retornar erro. E nosso programa vai avisar o usuário disso na função "interagir_com_usuario". O código numa linguagem sem exceção tem que ser:

```
#define ERRO -1

interagir_com_usuario() {
    sucesso = codificar_musica();
    if (sucesso == ERRO) {
        printf("Não foi possível copiar a música!");
    }
}

codificar_musica(...) {
    ...
    sucesso = ler_arquivo_original(...);
    if (sucesso == ERRO) {
        return ERRO
    }
    ...
}

ler_arquivo_original(...) {
    ...
    sucesso = reservar_memoria(...);
    if (sucesso == ERRO) {
        return ERRO
    }

   ...
}

reservar_memoria(...) {
    ...
    memoria = malloc(xxx);
    if (memoria == NULL) {
        return ERRO
    }

   ...
}
```

Em linguagens que suportam exeção, bastaria a função "reservar_memoria" levantar uma exeção, e pronto, um `except` na função `interagir_com_usuario` poderia tratar isso: não há necessidade das verificações intermediárias.

Então, assim como a exceção pode ser gerada direto pelo sistema operacional, poderia ter sido algo que a função mais interna detectasse, por meio de um if... por exemplo, se o arquivo original não existisse, ou se o diretório de destino está sem espaço, *antes* de começar a codificação. Essa sequência de verificação de erros por valor de retorno se torna tediosa, *e* propensa a erros.

> A exceção não para a execução do programa?

Não. A exceção vai retornando de várias funções chamadas até encontrar um bloco `except` correspondente. O programa só para se não houver nenhuma cláusula `except` numa função mais externa.
As vezes nem é o próprio programador do sistema quem precisa escrever esse `except`. Por exemplo, se você está fazendo um código para Web com o framework Flask ou Django, e ocorre uma exceção no seu código, existe um `except` dentro do próprio framework, que vai gerar uma página de HTML com uma mensagem de erro genérica, gerar o log com os dados da exceção, e, sobretudo, manter o programa em execução para responder a próxima requisição de página.

> Logo, quando se faz necessária?

Creio que com o exemplo do que é necessário fazer quando a linguagem não tem exceção deixa claro o suficiente como ela pode ser conveniente.

Mas tem mais coisas: uma exceção não necessariamente é devido a um erro no programa - você pode criar uma exceção personalizada justamente para o caso de precisar sair de várias funções aninhadas.

Um exemplo que acontece sempre em código meu, é em programação de jogos. Quando o personagem do joguinho morre, por exemplo, isso é detectado numa função de verificação, dentro do loop principal do jogo - no meio de um monte de outro código. Em seguida viriam outras verificações, atualização da posição dos inimigos, etc... No entanto, quando o personagem morre, eu levanto uma exceção com o comando `raise`. E o `except` para ela já fecha a cena de jogo, e volta para o menu inicial, pronto para reiniciar a fase.  Gera código bem mais simples do que fazer uma sequência de `if`s para tratar o mesmo caso.

E por fim, vale notar que o programa que você pegou como exemplo, com uma única função de duas linhas "verifica" que levanta ou não uma exceção, é onde a coisa tem pouca utilidade. Por que de qualquer forma, quem for chamar o método verifica vai ter que sempre fazer isso dentro de um `try`, `except` quando na verdade, poderia querer fazer um `if`. Um design mais interessante poderia ser o método `verifica` do exemplo receber um outro parâmetro dizendo se uma exceão deveria ser levantada, ou só retornar um código de False caso a verificação dê errado:

```
def verifica(self, elemento, excecao=False):
    if self.tipo != type(elemento):
        if excecao:
            raise TypeError('Tipo inválido !')
        return False
    return True
```

E aí pronto, quem quiser que no caso da verificação falhar ocorra a exceção chama essa função com o parâmetro `excecao=True`. E nesse caso, a pessoa pode querer isso justamente para tratar o problema em uma outra função, de nível mais alto.

Comment: Um exemplo vem prático inerente à própria linguagem é o final da iteração `for`, indicada pelo lançamento de uma exceção específica