# python não consigo usar o break

Tags: python

Esse é um joguinho que simula uma corrida. No entanto, quando um jogador atinge o nível 3 quero que pare o *loop* e zere todos os dados, mas não consigo usar o `break` para que quando o nível de um dos jogadores seja 3, interrompa o jogo e termine.

```
import random
class Jogador:
    def __init__(self, nome):
        self.nome = nome
        self.nivel=0
        self.passos= 0
        self.passos_parcial=0

    def mostra_tudo(self):
        print 'nivel',self.nivel
        print 'passos', self.passos
        print 'bonus', self.bonus

    def andar(self):
            self.passos_parcial = random.randint(1,60)
            self.passos+=self.passos_parcial
            self.checknivel()
            self.victory()
            print self.nome, "Andou mais", self.passos_parcial, "e está a", (120 - self.passos), "do próximo nível"

    def checknivel(self):
        if self.passos>=120:
              self.nivel+=1
              self.passos= self.passos-120
              print self.nome, 'está no nível', self.nivel

    def victory(self):
            if self.nivel == 3:
                print self.nome, 'ganhou'
                self.nivel=0
                self.passos= 0
                self.passos_parcial=0
                break



a=Jogador('Jogador 1')
b=Jogador('Jogador 2')
while True:
    a.andar()
    b.andar()
```

Comment: Quando você chamar o método `andar`, o jogador andará uma quantia inferior a 60 passos e após é chamado o método `victory`, que possui um laço infinito: o `while` ficará executando para sempre, pois o jogador andou nem 60 passos e continua no nível 0. Qual a função deste `while`?

Comment: Na verdade eu tentei botar esse 'while' pq não tem como botar o break em laço 'if'.  Mas a duvida mesmo é essa... fazer quando o 'self.nivel == 3' parar o laço. Tentei fazer isso no 'victory'

Comment: Esse é o ponto: não precisa do laço, então no precisa do `break`. Tente deixar apenas o `if`. Já adiantando, as nomenclaturas dos métodos está um tanto estranhas. Não é uma boa prática misturar nomes em português e inglês.

Comment: Mas quando chamo a classe lá em baixo, vai acontecer que o só vai chamar uma vez o andar lá em baixo. Sendo que é para chamar até que o nivel seja igual a 3. Ai depois é para zerar os dados pq acabou o jogo.

Comment: quem deu downvote nessa questão? está perfeitamente respondível e boa.

Answer (score 2):

O `break` tem utilidade limitada para casos como esses: ele sai de um único laço na mesma função.

Você está criando o jogo com uma boa separação de o quê faz o quê, mas aparentemente o desespero para fazer `break` funcionar bagunçou seu código.

Todo jogo vai ter um trecho que é o que chamamos de laço principal - "mainloop": o trecho que tem que ser repetido a cada *frame*, ou  a cada interação com o jogador, para o jogo funcionar. Nesse código é fácil notar que o trecho que faz isso está na sua função `andar`, que atualiza posições, chama funções de atualização e verificação, e imprime o estado atual do jogo.  *Para esse código fazer sentido, é a função andar que é o laço principal, que precisa ser executada a cada interação do jogo*.

**Atualização** - só percebi depois de escrever que você de fato vai ter vários "jogadores". No caso, você vai ter um "laço principal" em outro ponto do programa, que chama a função `andar` em cada interação: é lá que deve estar o bloco `try...except` que descrevo no final. Se optar pela variável, tem que ser uma variável global, não um atributo então.

Então, o `while True` que foi parar na função `victory` deveria estar cobrindo todo o bloco que está em `andar`. E sim, daí, precisamos de um mecanismo para que a função `victory` possa interromper esse laço, e essa é a sua dúvida.

Existem duas formas: você pode manter uma variável com o estado global do jogo (no caso, simplesmente um atributo da classe Jogador): o `while` em `andar` verifica essa variável, e a função `victory` atualiza a mesma:

```
...
def __init__(...):
    ...
    self.vitoria_aconteceu = False
    ...
    self.andar()
...
    def andar(self):
        while not self.vitoria_aconteceu:
            self.passos_parcial = random.randint(1,60)
            self.passos+=self.passos_parcial
            self.checknivel()
            self.victory()
            print self.nome, "Andou mais", self.passos_parcial, "e está a", (120 - self.passos), "do próximo nível"

...
    def victory(self):
        if self.nivel == 3:
            ...
            vitoria_aconteceu = True
```

Agora, imagine que esse é um jogo complexo, com várias instâncias de `Jogador`, e vários testes para parar o jogo: um jogador pode morrer, ou achar o tesouro, ou ainda chegar num ponto em que há uma mudança de fase para um outro mapa.

As funções poderiam ter mais níveis - em um outro tipo de jogo,  a morte de um jogador pode acontecer na atualização de posição de um objeto de classe `Tiro`, em seu método `atualizar` (e esse método não teria acesso ao atributo na classe principal do jogo).

Então, uma forma comum de tratar o problema é criar exceções customizadas, e colocar o bloco do laço principal dentro de um `try...except`.

Criar uma exceção customizada pode soar complicado, mas é a coisa mais simples do mundo: são classes vazias que herdam de `Exception`.

Você pode até criar uma exceção para cada tipo de acontecimento que acarretaria uma saída do *loop* principal, e aí, um bloco de  `except` apropriado para cada uma:

```
class GameException(Exception): pass

class VicrotyException(GameException): pass

class LostException(GameException): pass

...

    def andar(self):
        try:
            while True:
                self.passos_parcial = random.randint(1,60)
                self.passos+=self.passos_parcial
                self.checknivel()
                self.victory()
                print self.nome, "Andou mais", self.passos_parcial, "e está a", (120 - self.passos), "do próximo nível"
         except VictoryException:
                print(self.nome, "ganhou")
                ...
...
    def victory(self):
        if self.nivel == 3:
            # Levanta uma excelççao de vitória,
            # que dsvia o código para o except correspondente:
            raise VitctoryException
```

As exceções não são de forma alguma algo ruim, como pode parecer - para maiores informações veja minha resposta sobre exceções:

[Por que fazer uso de exceções em Python utilizando o raise?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/250573/por-que-fazer-uso-de-exce%C3%A7%C3%B5es-em-python-utilizando-o-raise/250751#250751)

Mais duas dicas gerais para o seu código:

- você está suando Python 2 por que? É uma linguagem do milênio passado, com suporte cada vez menor - tente passar a utilizar Python 3.6
- Tente manter uma consistência de nomenclatura: você está usando variáveis e métodos com nomes em português e inglês meio ao acaso. Idealmente use em inglês: você nunca sabe quando seu projeto vai ficar legal, e você vai querer colocar no github e ter colaboradores internacionais.

Comment: Eu achei um tanto quanto _overpower_ usar exceção neste caso em específico. Particularmente eu faria no laço principal do jogo a verificação do estado da partida (vitória/empate/derrota/_the show must go on_). Mas é uma sensação minha, estou acostumado a **tentar** seguir um fluxo mais semelhante ao que a Unity faz

Comment: Você pode achar "overpower", mas em muitos casos é menos complexo, e é um pattern bastante usado. Não é algo como um "hack" - é usado para controle de fluxo em programação mesmo.

Comment: Eu sei, o final da iteração do `for` é indicado pelo lançamento de uma exceção. Mas acho que devido ao meu (pouco) costume eu acho _overpower_. Sensação de matar moscas com bazucas.