# Problemas na declaração de uma estrutura

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, modelagem

Estou criando um jogo de Poker simples, neste jogo defini que as cartas seriam *structs*. Segundo minhas regras de negócio, cada carta possui um **valor**, um **nome** e um **naipe**.

- A propriedade `Valor` corresponde ao intervalo de 2 a 14 (esta regra foi implementada no `set` da propriedade).
- A propriedade `Nome` é derivada de `Valor` e apenas faz a conversão de alguns números em letras. Ou seja, o intervalo de 2 a 9 terão como nome os seus respectivos valores, já o intervalo entre 10 a 14 terão os nomes T, J, Q, K e Ás).
- `Naipe` é um `char` que armazenará um caractere Unicode.

Como não faz sentido existir uma carta sem valor criei um construtor. Só que não consigo definir a propriedade Valor através deste construtor, a IDE acusa um erro que só é resolvido se eu definir um número a `_valor` no construtor (porém assim não passa pela validação e a propriedade Valor fica sem função). Como proceder?

O erro apresentado é:

> O objeto 'this' não pode ser usado antes que todos os seus campos sejam atribuídos a

```
 struct Carta
    {
        private int _valor;
        public int Valor {

            get {
                return _valor;
                }

            set {
                int ValorMaximoPermitido = 14;
                int ValorMinimoPermitido = 2;

                if (value < ValorMinimoPermitido || value > ValorMaximoPermitido)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"O valor definido para a carta está fora do intervalor entre {ValorMinimoPermitido} e {ValorMaximoPermitido}.");
                }
                else
                {
                    _valor = value;
                }
            }
        }
        public char Naipe { get; }
        public string Nome
        {
            get
            {
                if (Valor > 1 && Valor < 10)
                {
                    return Valor.ToString() + Naipe;
                }
                else if (Valor == 10)
                {
                    return "T" + Naipe;
                }
                else if (Valor == 11)
                {
                    return "J" + Naipe;
                }
                else if (Valor == 12)
                {
                    return "Q" + Naipe;
                }
                else if (Valor == 13)
                {
                    return "K" + Naipe;
                }
                else if (Valor == 14)
                {                    
                    return "A" + Naipe;
                } else
                {
                    throw new Exception($"O nome para {Valor} não foi definido.");
                }
            }
        }

        public Carta (int valor, char naipe)
        {
            Valor = valor;
            Naipe = naipe;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O conceito está errado. Uma carta é [imutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101), não faz o menor sentido existir um `set` nela. Se deseja que seja mutável deveria criar uma classe, embora ainda não faça sentido.

Retire esse `set` e funcionará. A validação deve ser feita no construtor.

na verdade tem uma série de outros erros conceituais e de estratégia de implementação neste código.

Seria bom C# ter ADTs, como não tem pelo menos a definição das cartas seriam melhor implementadas como `enum`, assim pouparia muitos problemas e seria mais fácil de programar.

Alguns detalhes:

- `Nome` não é derivada de `Valor`.
- Todos os caracteres em C# são Unicode.
- [O IDE não é responsável por analisar o código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101).
- usar `Exception` tem dois problemas, é [genérica demais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101) e está sendo [usada como controle de fluxo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101).
- Tem problemas de [nomenclatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101), tipagem e até os valores usados nas cartas.

Comment: Ah sim entendi, tem razão. Na verdade era para ser um `private set` acabei não colocando. Fiz a validação no set, pois ao meu ver já que ela diz respeito ao Valor, parecia ser uma boa ideia colocar a validação lá. Vou usar `enum` apenas para ajudar a definir os naipes. Fora isso acho que não tem como entrar dados inadequados com a regra de negócio.

Comment: Mesmo privado não faz sentido. Faz mais sentido ser uma enumeração, mas você pode fazer como desejar, eu não sou fã de complexidade.