# Tem algo errado em fazer todo o corpo de um método estar dentro de um try-catch?

Tags: c#, .net, exceção, método, try-catch

Por exemplo:

```
public void Metodo() {
    try {
        //código
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //manipulação
    }
}
```

Há algo errado em fazer assim? Deveria ter algo que não deveria estar dentro do `try`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviamente que trem casos que o código não deveria estar todo "protegido" pelo `try`, eventualmente deveria ter mais de um `try`. Não acho que esta seja a questão.

Você pode colocar todo o código do método dentro do `try` (além do `catch`, claro) se todo ele pode emitir exceções que você tem intenção e pode manipular ali. Inclusive pode ter vários `catch`es para isto.

É errado colocar qualquer código dentro de um `try` se ele não pode lançar exceções ou se lançar você não quer capturar. Não faz diferença se é todo o método ou não.

Se colocar um código que potencialmente lança uma exceção e você não pode manipulá-la adequadamente, terá que relançá-la, e aí está cometendo um erro, provavelmente.

Em paralelo o código que está no `try` tem mais dificuldade de ser otimizado já que o fluxo de execução torna-se imprevisível.

Fora isso fazer qualquer coisa sem ter um motivo que você possa justificar é uma prática ruim, mesmo que esse fazer seja só colocar ou não uma linha de código dentro de um `try`. Tudo é decisão, e precisa de justificativa.

Não adianta fazer discurso de fazer código fácil de dar manutenção e não escrever código sempre pensando nisso.

Nem vou entrar aqui que exceções só devem ser usadas em [casos realmente excepcionais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101) e [não deve capturar exceções muito genéricas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101). Em geral só capture ser pode fazer algo importante, caso contrário deixe para outro local tratar.