# Qual é o possível custo de utilizar blocos para tratamento de exceção em demasiado ?

Tags: c#, java, c, exceção, sistema-operacional

Como exceções são interrupções causadas na maioria das vezes pelo sistema operacional, gostaria de saber se há alguma custo de memória(pilha/heap) uma vez que, existindo tratamento de exceção o programa continua a executar mesmo com a interrupção. Essa proteção gera custo na memória de minha aplicação?

Comment: Exceções não são interrupções, isso é consequência e quem causa exceções na sua aplicação é você mesmo, não o SO. Sobre a pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5888/exce%c3%a7%c3%b5es-consomem-muito-processamento-verdade-ou-lenda

Comment: Acho que você esta confundindo os conceitos de interrupção, armadilhas e exceções.

Comment: @Caique C. você está correto, realmente me expressei mal, entretanto o sistema operacional também pode gerar interrupções.