# Lançar uma Exception personalizada

Tags: c#, .net, web-service, exceção

Tenho um método no meu Webservice que lança uma exceção caso o código do cartão já esteja em uso, ou seja, ao tentar liberar o acesso o sistema verifica se ele já está em uso e retorna a `Exception`.

Código no Webservice

```
... 
try
{
    if(ListaCartoes.Any(c => c.Codigo == cartaoParaAcesso)
       throw new Exception("CARTÃO JÁ ESTÁ EM USO");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  throw new ErroLiberacaoDeAcesso(ex.message);
}
```

Código no Cliente

```
...
try
  {
      Webservice.LiberaAcesso(informacoesAcesso);        
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.message);
  }
```

Código classe ErroLiberaAcesso:

```
 [Serializable()]
    public class ErroLiberaAcesso: Exception
    {
        public ErroLiberaAcesso() : base()
        { }

        public ErroLiberaAcesso(string message) : base(message)
        { }

        public ErroLiberaAcesso(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException)
        { }

        protected ErroLiberaAcesso(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
        { }
    }
```

Erro que está retornando:

> exception = {"System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: O servidor não pôde processar a solicitação. ---> Pca_Webservice_V2.ErroLiberacaoDeAcesso: NÚMERO DE CARTÃO EM USO\n

Ou seja, não é somente a mensagem "NUMERO DE CARTÃO EM USO" que está retornando. O que posso fazer neste caso ?

Comment: Poste o código do seu "ErroLiberacaoDeAcesso"

Comment: Se você só quer o texto, por que não retorna só um texto?

Comment: @jbueno se eu retornar um texto, tenho que ficar comparando string para saber qual foi o retorno do erro. Uma vez que pode ocorrer mais de um tipo de erro.

Comment: Seria interessante você lançar somente a sua exception e trabalhar com a mesma não?

Comment: @Shura16 perdoe-me mas não compreendi a sua sugestão.

Comment: Não há necessidade de lançar um nova `Exception` para capturá-la e lançar a sua `ErroLiberacaoDeAcesso`. Convenciona-se utilizar o sufixo Exception nas exceções.
Se você quer pegar apenas a mensagem tem que encapsular num `try/catch` e devolver apenas a mensagem da exceção.

Comment: @MFedatto como seria esse encapsulamento to try/catch, reconheço que é a primeira vez que vejo falar sobre isso.

Comment: Como o MFedatto disse, não precisa usar `try/catch` no seu WebService. Use apenas o `if ...` e dentro dele lance sua exception `throw new ErroLiberacaoDeAcesso("Mensagem de erro");`

Comment: @JcSaint o Webservice pode lançar outras exceções do mesmo gênero? Esta "exceção" é uma regra de negócio e não uma situação excepcional, certo?

Comment: @Shura16 entendi, eu fiz isso mas o erro foi o mesmo. :(

Comment: @bigown sim, por exemplo, eu verifico se a pessoa tem acesso ou não, se o cartão está dentro do prazo de validade ou não, se o número já está em uso, uma vez que a atendente pode digitar um número errado. Por isso estou usando exceptions, para não precisar usar if e comparar qual o tipo de erro foi retornado.

Comment: Se quer somente a mensagem retorne somente a mensagem e não Exception.

Comment: @JcSaint as `Exceptions` são exceções à regra. Não há nada de errado em utilizar exceções para tratar validação de negócio, mas seria interessante você utilizar um tipo específico para exceções de negócio, como `public class BusinessException : Exception` e no seu `try/catch` você verifica os dois tipos de exceção: `try { Foo(); } catch (BusinessException ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); } catch (Exception) { throw; }`.

Comment: @JcSaint é importante ter em mente que as exceções lançadas no seu serviço não chegam ao cliente como exceções normais. A comunicação entre o cliente e o serviço é totalmente baseada em solicitação e resposta, enquanto uma exceção é uma interrupção no runtime do processo, totalmente dentro do serviço. O que o cliente recebe é uma exceção de falta na comunicação com o serviço. No cliente você precisa tratar uma `SoapException`, não uma `ErroLiberacaoDeAcesso`.

Comment: @MFedatto ok, obrigado pela explicação, principalmente em como a exceção chega ao cliente. :)

Comment: @JcSaint Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi [você tem uma regra de negócio e não uma situação excepcional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101). Então não deve usar este mecanismo. A última coisa que você deve fazer nesse caso é substituir um `if` simples por um `catch` complexo.

Antes de usar um recurso da linguagem, [entenda para que ele serve](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/101).

Principalmente da maneira como está fazendo onde gera uma [exceção geral, em seguida a captura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101), o que não faz o menor sentido em fazer isso (é o pior abuso de exceção que eu já vi) e depois lançar uma outra que tem um nome equivocado (deveria ser `LiberaAcessoException`). Mas o nome nem é o problema, é [sua existência e o seu uso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101). Se é regra de negócio, trate no fluxo normal do sistema, gerando um [retorno que informe a situação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).

Então o *webservice* ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
 //faz o que tem que fazer aqui (se é que tem algo mais)
 return ListaCartoes.Any(c => c.Codigo == cartaoParaAcesso)
```

No cliente:

```
if (Webservice.LiberaAcesso(informacoesAcesso)) {
    //faz algo aqui se tiver que fazer
} else {
    MessageBox.Show("CARTÃO JÁ ESTÁ EM USO");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/Custom.cs).

Se tiver outros motivos de erros na regra de negócio, pode mudar um pouco a lógica. Neste caso provavelmente criaria uma classe para encapsular as informações de erro e enviaria ela como retorno, ao invés de um booliano.

Essa classe seria muito [parecida com uma exceção, mas não seria uma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101), evitando os desvios longos (`goto` na sua pior forma) e imprevisibilidade da ação, sem falar na [lentidão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5888/101) e a possibilidade de uso errado do mecanismo, como ocorre (note que o código atual está dizendo que o cartão já está em uso mesmo se tiver um erro de programação ou outra falha no sistema, como o `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException`).

Se a classe é algo exagerada para você, retorne outra forma de código/mensagem conforme eu [demonstro em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).

Fazendo o certo talvez descubra outros problemas no seu código que nem imaginava porque estava usando o recurso de um jeito errado.

Comment: Neste caso eu terei que criar um método para cada regra de negócio no webservice, ou seja, um método para verificar se  cartão está em um, um método para verificar a validade, um método para verificar se o número do cartão está correto ? E do lado do cliente usar um if para cada verificação também ?!

Comment: Provavelmente, mas isto é uma questão de organização. Claro que pode usar um só. Depende do que precisa. Seu código não deixa claro nada disto, então não posso falar de forma específica. Aí a verificação pode usar um ou vários `if`s, depende de como você vai fazer. Na verdade segue o mesmo esquema da exceção. Se você precisa de vários `catch`s, precisará de vários `if`s, se iria usar apenas um `catch`, então dá para usar apenas um `if`. A única diferença entre um e outro é que no `if`você sabe quando ele será executado, com o `catch`, você não sabe. E causa o problema relatado na pergunta.