# Erro ao criar uma Exception Personalizada

Tags: c#

Estou tentando simular uma exceção personalizada, mas ao compilar obtenho um erro.

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExerciciosTratamentoErros
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numero;

            Console.WriteLine("informe ate que numero devemos contar");
            numero = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());


                try
                {
                    numero = 5 / numero; // coloco 0 (zero) para entrar no CATCH
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw new ValorMuitoBaixoException( "Erro personalizado");
                }


        }
    }
}
```

Classe Exception personalizada

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExerciciosTratamentoErros
{
    class ValorMuitoBaixoException: Exception
    {
        public ValorMuitoBaixoException(string mensagem)
             : base(mensagem)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: "ao compilar dá erro", você deve estar tentando rodar o programa, não compilar...  e ao rodar, dá erro porque o código do programa está gerando a exceção... fora isso, me parece que está tentando usar a exception de forma errada, para um objetivo errado... poderia até considerar isso um problema xy: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1202/69359

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não está tratando o erro, apenas dando um throw

```
throw new ValorMuitoBaixoException( "Erro personalizado")
```

Faça isso:

```
                try
                {
                    numero = 5 / numero; // coloco 0 (zero) para entrar no CATCH
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                   //Retorna a mensagem de erro tratada para o console
                   Console.WriteLine(Erro.TratamentoException(e));
                }


               public class Erro
               {
                   public string TratamentoException(Exception e)
                   {
                       //Verifica se a exceção é referente a divisão por zero
                       if(e.InnerException is DivideByZeroException)
                       {
                         return "0";
                       }
                       else if(e.InnerException is System.FormatException)
                       {
                         return "Você não informou num número válido";
                       }

                       [...] // Inclua outras verificações

                       else 
                       {
                         return "Valor incorreto.";
                       }
                   }
               }
```

Answer (score 3):

Você deve estar rodando o programa, não apenas compilando. Ao rodar o programa e digitar 0, é gerada a exceção mostrada como exceção não tratada pelo debug do visual studio.

Como comentei me parece que está tentando usar exceção de forma errada, que poderia até considerar um problema XY.

Esse problema deveria ser solucionado simplesmente com um `IF`:

```
public static void Main()
{
     int numero;
     Console.WriteLine("Informe um número");
     string line =  Console.ReadLine(); 
     //string line  = "0"; //Simula que o usuário digitou 0 na linha do console.
     if (int.TryParse(line,out numero))
     {
         if (numero != 0)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("5 dividido por " +numero+ " é: " + (5/numero));
         }
         else
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Não é possível dividir por 0");
         }
     }
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Valor informado não pode ser convertido para inteiro.");
     }
}
```

Coloque no [.NETFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mUDH5v)

Mas se quer utilizar Exception (para fins didáticos), esse código ficaria assim:

```
public static void Main()
{
     int numero;
     Console.WriteLine("Informe um número");
     string line =  Console.ReadLine(); 
     //string line  = "0"; //Simula que o usuário digitou 0 na linha do console.
     if (int.TryParse(line,out numero))
     {
         try
         {
             Console.WriteLine("5 dividido por " +numero+ " é: " + (5/numero));
         }
         catch (DivideByZeroException)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Tentativa de divisão por 0");
         }
         catch (ArithmeticException)
         {
              Console.WriteLine("Erro Aritimético");
         }
         //... 

     }
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Valor informado não pode ser convertido para inteiro.");
     }
}
```

Coloquei no [.NETFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5MKEhu)

> Recomendo a leitura: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/97856/69359 e nesta resposta tem referências para outras.

---

Edit:

Voltando ao ponto de criar sua Exception, Considere o seguinte código:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         int numero;
         Console.WriteLine("Informe um número");
         string line =  Console.ReadLine(); 
         //string line  = "0"; //Simula que o usuário digitou 0 na linha do console.
         if (int.TryParse(line,out numero))
         {
             try
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("5 dividido por " +numero+ " é: " + (5/numero));
             }
             catch (MinhaExceptionDivisaoPorZero ex)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
             }
             catch (DivideByZeroException)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("Tentativa de divisão por 0");
             }
             catch (ArithmeticException)
             {
                  Console.WriteLine("Erro Aritimético");
             }
             //... 

         }
         else
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Valor informado não pode ser convertido para inteiro.");
         }
    }

}

public class MinhaExceptionDivisaoPorZero : DivideByZeroException
{
    public MinhaExceptionDivisaoPorZero() : base("Você tentou dividir por zero")
    {

    }
}
```

Este código cria a `MinhaExceptionDivisaoPorZero`, porém ao tentar dividir por zero, é gerada uma `DivideByZeroException` e esta, não é uma `MinhaExceptionDivisaoPorZero` (apesar de que toda `MinhaExceptionDivisaoPorZero` será uma `DivideByZeroException`) logo não irá cair no Exception que você espera. Para isso, deveria ter um código assim (que por sua vez, será absurdamente ruim):

```
///Perdoai o código abaixo. Amém
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         int numero;
         Console.WriteLine("Informe um número");
         //string line =  Console.ReadLine(); 
         string line  = "0"; //Simula que o usuário digitou 0 na linha do console.
         if (int.TryParse(line,out numero))
         {
             try
             {

                if (numero != 0)
                {
                     Console.WriteLine("5 dividido por " +numero+ " é: " + (5/numero));
                }
                else
                {
                     throw new MinhaExceptionDivisaoPorZero(); //Você vai ter que gerar uma exceção
                }
             }
             catch (MinhaExceptionDivisaoPorZero ex)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); //pra mostrar a mensagem dela. Não é mais fácil só mostrar a mensagem lá em cima ?
             }

         }
         else
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Valor informado não pode ser convertido para inteiro.");
         }
    }
}

public class MinhaExceptionDivisaoPorZero : DivideByZeroException
{
    public MinhaExceptionDivisaoPorZero() : base("Você tentou dividir por zero")
    {

    }
}
```

Portanto não vejo como aplicar isso que está querendo, sem que seja uma gambiarra, além do detalhe que `ValorMuitoBaixoException` não faz sentido para um cálculo de divisão.

> Recomendo novamente a leitura da resposta acima linkada.

Comment: O meu objetivo é criar uma exceção personalizada. uma Exception criada por mim com o nome  ValorMuitoBaixoException e que essa exception receba uma mensagem e mostre em um caixa de texto por exemplo.

Comment: @DanielleArrudatorres entendeu o problema ?

Comment: @DanielleArrudatorres A exceção você criou, o que não está fazendo é tratá-la. Leia com atenção a resposta do Rovann, pricipalmente observando os `catch{}`