# O restante do código dentro do Try é executado após encontrar Exception?

Tags: c#, .net, exceção, try-catch

O resto do código existente dentro de um `try` é executado após encontrar uma `exception` ou pula direto pro código dentro do `catch(Exception e)`

```
try{
  x = 10;
  //alguns erro de try catch
  x = 20;
} catch (Exception e)
{
  x++;
  MessageBox.Show("Valor de x: " + x);
}
```

No caso a mensagem mostraria 11 ou 21?

Comment: Se a `Exception` ocorrer na linha que você está comentando o resultado seria `11`, pois o `x` sairia do bloco com valor `10`.

Comment: Concordo com o Fernando, o valor de X será impresso como 11.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Resposta curta:

Exibirá o valor 11. O valor 21 nunca seria exibido, pois o bloco catch é executado **apenas** quando houver uma exceção.

### Resposta longa

Vamos lá, diretamente do [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/0yd65esw.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> When an exception is thrown, the common language runtime (CLR) looks
>   for the catch statement that handles this exception. If the currently
>   executing method does not contain such a catch block, the CLR looks at
>   the method that called the current method, and so on up the call
>   stack. If no catch block is found, then the CLR displays an unhandled
>   exception message to the user and stops execution of the program.

Isto é, quando uma exceção é levantada, o CLR procura pelo catch mais próximo de onde esta exceção foi levantada e executa seu bloco de código. Isto significa que caso o bloco atual de código onde a exceção foi levantada não possui um `catch`, este `catch` será procurado nos métodos que o chamaram até chegar no topo da pilha de chamadas, onde será levantada uma exceção do tipo `Unhandled Exception` para o usuário, parando a execução do programa.

Então...

> O resto do código existente dentro de um try é executado após
>   encontrar uma exception ou pula direto pro código dentro do
>   catch(Exception e)

O bloco `try` contém o código que pode levantar uma exceção, e ele será executado **enquanto não houver uma exceção** ou **até que seja finalizado**. Em outras palavras, caso uma exceção ocorra, ele irá procurar diretamente pelo catch mais próximo sem executar o restante do código dentro do bloco `try`.

> The try block contains the guarded code that may cause the exception.
>   The block is executed until an exception is thrown or it is completed
>   successfully. For example, the following attempt to cast a null object
>   raises the NullReferenceException exception:

### Por que este comportamento?

Uma exceção indica que algo fora do comum ocorreu durante a execução do seu código. Se "algo de errado" ocorreu durante esta execução, você quer que o restante de seu código seja executado normalmente? O bloco `catch` deve ser utilizado justamente para executar um código específico para estes casos anormais, quando você **sabe que eles podem acontecer**.

O bloco catch pode ser utilizado de várias formas, como pode ser visto abaixo:

```
catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
{
  //Deve ser executado quando uma exceção do tipo InvalidOperationException seja levantada
}
catch(SqlException ex) when (ex.Message.Contains("TIMEOUT"))
{
   //Deve capturar uma exceção do tipo SqlException e que contenha no message a palavra TIMEOUT
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   //Deve capturar uma exceção que não seja uma InvalidOperationException ou **SqlException que não contenha** no message a palavra TIMEOUT
}
```

Evite capturar exceções genéricas `(Exception ex)` em códigos específicos da sua aplicação, a menos que você saiba o que está fazendo (registro de log no ponto mais alto do sistema, por exemplo), ou levante ela novamente com um `throw` ou colocando-a como uma `Inner Exception`. Por fim, existem algumas [categorias de exceções](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.exception(v=vs.110).aspx) que você pode utilizar para se guiar sobre o seu tratamento:

- **Usage errors:** Um erro de uso representa um erro na lógica do programa
  que pode resultar em uma exceção. Contudo, este tipo de erro não deve
  ser resolvido com um bloco `try catch`, e sim com uma modificação no
  código a ser executado. É um erro que **você sabe que vai acontecer e
  que pode ser evitado**.
- **Program error:** Um erro em tempo de execução que não pode ser evitado na construção do código pode se enquadrar nesta categoria. Imagine que você precisa ler um arquivo em um diretório específico. Para não cair no **Usage error**, você verifica antes se este arquivo existe para poder então utiliza-lo. Contudo, embora a verificação tenha retornado verdadeiro para a existência do arquivo, no momento da leitura ele encontrou-se indisponível *(foi deletado ou está sendo utilizado por um outro processo)*, levantando uma exceção de `FileNotFoundException`, ou similar.
- **System failures:** Falhas no sistema são exceções que podem ocorrer em tempo de execução e que normalmente não podem ser tratadas de forma muito útil. O que você como desenvolvedor pode fazer caso seja levantada um `OutOfMemoryException`? Você pode contudo, registrar as informações desta exceção em um log antes que a aplicação seja finalizada, para uma posterior análise de forma a evitar que este erro ocorra novamente.

### Leituras recomendadas

- ["Boas práticas com exceções"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15263/4539)
- [Exceções consomem muito processamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17632/4539)

Answer (score 4):

A execução do código é interrompida no momento em que a exceção é encontrada, portanto, a resposta é **não. O restante do código abaixo da exception não é executado.**

Este é um dos objetivos da estrutura `try/catch`. Você pode prever algum erro (exceção) que o código possa gerar e trata adequadamente, sem que o programa trave e exiba erros na tela do usuário.

```
try{
  x = 10; //Aqui está atribuindo valor 10 a variável x
  // exceção capturada pelo try/catch
  x = 20; // Essa linha não é executada por causa da exception.
} catch (Exception e)
{
  x++; //x está recebendo ele mesmo (10) mais 1;
  MessageBox.Show("Valor de x: " + x);
}
```

Portanto a mensagem impressa seria `Valor de x: 11`

Answer (score 4):

Coloquei um [exemplo completo e verificável no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ZI0XCp). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jYS2wv). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/Flow.cs). Veja [também no **SharpLab**](https://sharplab.io/#f:%3Eil/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmFK5bgG4B7MABMYAWSqQAFAEpmrdssjIYADxgBeGAAYcy5cgBOCRYcOadARn1KLbZAAtjQgO4wIqDwFF1pVFx+IQh5Awc2KxgAJjsIgF8KPlInGBk/AKCwEIUWCMiAagLwiPoQkCEiVAA6AHVjMDQAGUhUGQASACIANSoiIWMYUVQNAC5mdXjOuRLDePsYefigA==).

Note que a linha do `x = 20;` tem um *warning* indicando que ela nunca será executada. Claro que se p `throw` estivesse dentro de um método ou em algo condicional isso não ocorreria. Mas o exemplo é justamente para o caso de ser certo que o lançamento da exceção será executado. O próprio compilador informa que é garantido que o código não será executado nessa circunstância.

```
using System;
public class C {
    public static void Main() {
        int x = 0;
        try {
          x = 10;
          throw new Exception();
          x = 20;
        } catch (Exception) {
          x++;
          Console.WriteLine($"Valor de x: {x}");
        }
    }
}
```

Para quem tem um conhecimento mais avançado pode ajudar ver o IL:

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldc.i4.0
IL_0002: stloc.0
IL_0003: nop
IL_0004: ldc.i4.s 10
IL_0006: stloc.0
IL_0007: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Exception::.ctor()
IL_000c: throw
IL_000d: pop
IL_000e: nop
IL_000f: ldloc.0
IL_0010: ldc.i4.1
IL_0011: add
IL_0012: stloc.0
IL_0013: ldstr "Valor de x: {0}"
IL_0018: ldloc.0
IL_0019: box [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_001e: call string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string, object)
IL_0023: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_0028: nop
IL_0029: nop
IL_002a: leave.s IL_002c
IL_002c: ret
```

Answer (score 3):

Em adição ao que já foi dito, 
se quiseres que um bloco de código seja executado apesar de ser apanhada uma excepção, podes incluir o `Finally` a seguir ao `Catch`.

```
   try 
   {
        // Código a executar
   }
   catch(Exception)
   {
        // Código para tratar a excepção
   }
   Finally
   {
        // Código a executar mesmo que seja accionada uma excepção
        // Exemplo: Fechar um ficheiro que tenha sido aberto pelo System.IO.StreamReader 
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

O valor de X será 11 se a exceção for disparada entre:
X = 10 e X = 20.