# Como prevenir um System.NullReferenceException dentro de um if

Tags: c#, .net, exceção, nullpointerexception

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web onde um fotografo faz *upload* de uma imagem. Após upar a imagem, vou varrer todo o *metadata* da imagem afim de capturar algumas informações dos diretórios (Exif,IPTC,XMP,JFIF,PNG,BMP,JPG etc.), estou utilizando a biblioteca [Metadata Extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor). Ok, aprendi a usá-la. Primeiramente eu preciso receber os diretórios:

```
 IEnumerable<MetadataExtractor.Directory> directories = iptcReader.ReturnMetadataFile(Path.Combine(StorageRootPOOL, imagePool.File_name[i]));
```

Aqui eu já tenho todos os  diretórios da minha imagem, após isso preciso declarar variáveis de cada diretório que preciso capturar no meu caso:

```
var IPTCDirectory = directories.OfType<IptcDirectory>().FirstOrDefault();
var JPEGDirectory = directories.OfType<JpegDirectory>().FirstOrDefault();
var JFIFDirectory = directories.OfType<JfifDirectory>().FirstOrDefault();
var EXIFDirectory = directories.OfType<ExifIfd0Directory>().FirstOrDefault();
var EXIFSubDirectory = directories.OfType<ExifSubIfdDirectory>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Todos os valores dos diretórios NÃO SÃO NULOS mesmo que não exista o diretório na imagem, o problema está nas *tags* que existem dentro deles. Para capturar as *tags* dentro dos diretórios eu utilizo o seguinte código:

```
imageFileInfo.Keywords = IPTCDirectory.GetDescription(IptcDirectory.TagKeywords);
```

`imageFileInfo` é a classe onde estarei guardando todos os dados. O meu problema é, se por exemplo não existir a **TAG** `IptcDirectory.TagKeywords` eu irei receber um NullException, até ai nada fora do comum, porém se eu vou prevenir esse erro com um if por exemplo:

```
 if (IPTCDirectory.GetDescription(IptcDirectory.TagKeywords) == null)
 {
 }
```

Eu recebo um outro `NullException`, aí está o problema, eu queria definir um valor padrão para as tags que não existem, por exemplo:

```
if (IPTCDirectory.GetDescription(IptcDirectory.TagKeywords) == null)
{
      imageFileInfo.Keywords = "valor padrão";
}
```

Lembrando que não adianta eu utilizar o seguinte código, porque eu preciso saber quais *tags* são nulas e não quais diretórios, pois os diretórios sempre existe, mas algumas *tags* não:

```
if (EXIFDirectory != null && ExifIfd0Directory != null) {
    //Os diretórios nunca são nulos e sim as tags, então esse exemplo não iria se aplica ao meu problema.
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não faça em hipótese alguma o que está na outra resposta engolindo a exceção. Isto não resolve problema algum, só piora a situação. Isto é até mais terrível que [capturar `Exception`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101). E usar `goto` é pior ainda.

Só capture exceção se precisar mesmo. [Ela é lenta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5888/101) e só deve ser usada em situações excepcionais, não para controle de fluxo.

Se está recebendo um `NullReferenceException`, tem um erro de programação aí. Tem que consertar o erro. Capturar e engolir as exceções não está fazendo o código ficar certo, a solução é ele ser consertado.

Verifique com um `if` o que pode ser nulo e trata da forma que deseja, se quer atribuir um valor padrão, faça isto. Então pode nem precisar do `if`.

Você tem que ver o que está gerando a exceção e verificar exatamente isto antes do erro acontecer. Que fique muito claro sempre que recebe `NullReferenceException` é um erro de programação que deve ser resolvido, não se deve capturá-la. E verificar o erro antes dele ocorrer é a solução. Por isso ainda considero que a resposta aceita agora não é adequada, apesar de não ser o absurdo que a outra propunha.

Talvez seja isso que deseja:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProcessAvailable; i++) {
    var IptcDirectory = directories.OfType<IptcDirectoryBase>().FirstOrDefault();
    imageFileInfo.Keywords = IptcDirectory.TagKeywords == null ? "padrao keywords" : IptcDirectory.GetDescription(IptcDirectory.TagKeywords);
    imageFileInfo.LensModel = IptcDirectory.TagLensModel == null ? "padrao lensmodel" : IptcDirectory.GetDescription(IptcDirectory.TagLensModel);
    imageFileInfo.TagMake = IIptcDirectory.TagMake == null ? "padrao make" : IptcDirectory.GetDescription(IptcDirectory.TagMake);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/manaiero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/AvoidNull.cs).

Leia isto: [Como melhor tratar exceções em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/101). Mesmo sendo outra linguagem, vale igual.

Comment: Bigown, tudo bem, irei rever o que está correto ou não, porém o problema nesse caso é que existem certas tags por exemplo do `EXIFDirectory ` que não existe, e eu caio nesse problema entende? Tem imagem que tem e imagem que não tem, para as que não tem por exemplo a tag "DateTimeOriginal"  eu quero definir um valor padrão no meu `imageFileInfo`, você tem alguma ideia de como posso resolver isso sem usar o tratamento citado como errado?

Comment: O que eu quero dizer é, o diretório em sí nunca é null, mas algumas tags dentro dele sim, e eu não consigo trata-las com if pois dentro da expressão do if eu recebo uma exception null.

Comment: Nada disto está na sua pergunta, se dissesse o valor padrão eu colocaria no meu código. Eu dei uma base deixando de processar o item que está nulo. Seu `if` está completamente errado, o meu provavelmente está certo, só não garanto porque a pergunta não tem detalhes, não tem como eu testar. Conserte o `if` em vez de usar o mecanismo errado.

Comment: Estou reformulando a pergunta de forma mais clara, desde já agradeço (de verdade), prefiro seguir pelo lado mais trabalhoso e correto :)

Comment: Não tem nada de mais trabalhoso, a não ser que esteja se referindo ao trabalho de aprender fazer o certo, o que recomendo fortemente, exceção quase nunca é a solução, a maioria dos programadores não sabem disto, a maioria acredita ser boa prática botar exceção em tudo, o que já questiono a ideia de boa prática (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101+boas+pr%C3%A1ticas), quanto mais isso ser bom.

Comment: Concordo Bigown, inclusive questionei o cara da pergunta "certa", porém ja corrigi meu erro. Reformulei a pergunta, por gentileza, veja se ficou mais claro, a sua resposta não resolveu o meu problema(talvez porque não tinha deixado claro o problema).

Comment: Você deu uma bela mudada na pergunta, não só adicionou detalhes. Tem coisas novas que não existiam antes e até sumiu o que tinha. Estou pensando em fechar como não clara, porque está ficando mais confuso, talvez o problema seja a confusão.

Comment: Não existe a função, GetProperty nessa library: github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor

Comment: Eu mudei porque a outra resposta usou ela e você a aceitou. Então achei que era isso o correto no seu código. Se você aceita uma resposta que não funciona, está criando uma informação errada para a comunidade. O jeito antigo (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/221991/5) que eu fiz estava certo? Eu mudei porque achei que eu tinha feito o certo, mas a outra aceitação me fez ver que eu eu estava errado.

Comment: eu realmente confundi as bolas, desculpa, o antigo também não funciona, pois cai naquele IF que me retorna null. Por enquanto só funciona com o try catch, estou voltando atrás porque não quero que tenha resposta errada para a comunidade.

Comment: Não cai em `if` algum porque não tem `if` na minha resposta. Se nada disso funciona acho melhor fechar a pergunta porque você não consegue fornecer informações suficientes para podermos ajudar. Você está fazendo muita confusão e por isso não tem uma resposta que te ajude.

Comment: Cara, eu deixei claro na edição da pergunta, inclusive, a sua resposta como eu ja disse 300x não resolve, essa comparação `== null` ativa a excessão nullException como eu já disse.

Comment: è a única solução correta, se não resolve, ou falta informações na pergunta, ou está fazendo errado.

Comment: Não, não é a solução correta, se me retorna um erro porque seria correta? Eu não quero ser rude, mas simplesmente não está correta. Vou inclusive testar novamente e postar o print.

Comment: ok, então, se você sabe mais que eu, faça como quiser. Todo mundo que sabe programar em C# sabe que está é a solução correta, que usar exceção não é correto. Se não funciona para você é porque sua pergunta não diz corretamente o que está está fazendo ou está implementando de forma errada. Quando você perceber isso terá a solução correta, se não quiser fazer desta forma, faça do jeito errado, é o seu código que ficará ruim e é um direito seu fazer errado. Certo e funciona são coisas bem diferentes, o que funciona um dia tem problemas porque não era o certo. Todo programador deveria saber disto.

Comment: Fica aí o código, bem votado para quem quer aprender fazer o certo. Que pode não funcionar s´porque a a pergunta não diz claramente onde está dando o erro.

Comment: Bigown, eu não disse que um if é melhor que um try catch, ou algo do tipo, eu disse que esse trecho que você passou, não está correto, ele me retorna o mesmo erro quando eu faço `if (IPTCDirectory.GetDescription(IptcDirectory.TagKeywords) == null)
 {
 }` Você entende milhões de vezes mais que eu, só estou dizendo que não está solucionado com aquela resposta.

Comment: Porque a pergunta não está clara, por isso eu a fechei, se ela estivesse clara eu colocaria o código que previne isso.

Comment: Se isso não for pergunta clara, eu não sei mais o que é... mas beleza.

Comment: Se não tem a informação necessária para te dar uma resposta adequada, ela não é clara, mas você não quer ouvir isso então beleza, o único prejudicado será você, só você não terá o código adequado para o que precisa. Eu respondi o que foi perguntado, se precisa de algo que não está na pergunta não tem como responder.

Answer (score 1):

Havia entendido sua pergunta a primeira vez de uma maneira diferente.

No seu caso o motivo da `NullReferenceException` é **claro** e **conhecido** por você e é um comportamento esperado quando uma `tag` não existe. Nesse caso é de seu interesse capturar a exceção para atribuir um valor padrão às `tags` inexistentes.

Não há nenhum problema nesse caso em você usar:

```
try {
    imageFileInfo.Keywords = IPTCDirectory.GetDescription(IptcDirectory.TagKeywords);
} catch (NullReferenceException e) {
    imageFileInfo.Keywords = "valor padrao"
}
```

<strike>Inclusive é melhor usar `try catch` do que `if` para testar se o erro existe, desse modo o processamento é reduzido quando não há erro.</strike>

#### Observação

Você está recebendo `NullException` na linha

```
if (IPTCDirectory.GetDescription(IptcDirectory.TagKeywords) == null)
```

provavelmente porque o objeto `IptcDirectory` não possui a propriedade `TagKeywords`, o jeito certo de testar seria:

```
if (IptcDirectory.GetProperty('TagKeywords') == null) {
    imageFileInfo.Keywords = "valor padrao";
} else {
    imageFileInfo.Keywords = IPTCDirectory.GetDescription(IptcDirectory.TagKeywords);
}
```

<strike>Porem esse código com `if` é menos eficiente que o `try catch`.</strike>

## EDIT

Como apontado pelo Maniero, na verdade Exceções em C# são muito caras, então a estrutura `if else` nao é menos eficiente a princípio (tudo depende do quão caro `GetProperty` é em relação ao lançamento de exceções)

Comment: Por que é menos eficiente?

Comment: No caso do `try catch`, quando não há erro, apenas a instrução `imageFileInfo.Keywords = IPTCDirectory.GetDescription(IptcDirectory.TagKeywords);` é executada. Já  no caso do `if` sempre serão executadas no minimo duas instruções, a do `if` e a de atribuição.

Comment: Mas quando dá a exceção é absurdamente (ordens de magnitude) menos eficiente e ele diz que espera que tenha exceções, então não é mais eficiente. Por isso que eu sempre digo, não use exceção para controlar fluxo, use só para situações excepcionais. Toda vez que se captura `NullReferenceException ` está tentando consertar **com** código algo que deve ser consertado **no** código. È erro de programação.

Comment: @bigown, tenho mais experiencia em `python` onde geralmente usamos a filosofia: *it's easier to ask forgiveness than it is to get permission*, mas você tem razão para o caso de C# as exceções são muito caras. Vou alterar a resposta.

Comment: Agora sim ficou mais claro, até o momento acredito que a sua resposta seja a mais adequada. Eu não sei o peso de um try catch, mas provavelmente o if seja menos pesado então vou usar o if. Aliás, sua resposta foi muito satisfatória na duvida do "porque o if indicava que era null sendo que eu estava apenas perguntando se ele era null"

Comment: Não existe a função, GetProperty nessa library: https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti , revisando a documentação [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy(v=vs.110).aspx), parece que a sintaxe correta é: `typeof(IptcDirectory).GetProperty("TagKeywords")`. Veja se funciona... `GetProperty` é um método da classe `Type` e não da sua lilbrary.

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso você deveria separar cada uma das instruções em blocos de `try catch` específicos.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProcessAvailable; i++) {
    var EXIFDirectory = directories.OfType<ExifDirectoryBase().FirstOrDefault();

    try {
        imageFileInfo.LensModel = Convert.ToString(EXIFDirectory.GetDescription(ExifIfd0Directory.TagLensModel));
    } catch (NullReferenceException e){ //tratar excecao }

    try {    
        imageFileInfo.Make = Convert.ToString(EXIFDirectory.GetDescription(ExifIfd0Directory.TagMake));
    } catch (NullReferenceException e){ //tratar excecao }

    try {
        imageFileInfo.Model = Convert.ToString(EXIFDirectory.GetDescription(ExifIfd0Directory.TagModel));
    } catch (NullReferenceException e){ //tratar excecao }
}
```

Dessa forma todos os blocos seriam sempre executados.

PS.: Você poderia tratar esse problema também utilizando a instrução `goto`, mas isso geralmente torna o código menos legível e mais complicado.

Ps2.: Nao tinha deixado explicito por achar obvio.. Mas as exceções devem sempre ser tratadas e ser o mais específicas o possível

Comment: Danilo, isso é uma boa prática?

Comment: Ate onde sei, sim. Dessa forma fica explicito que cada uma das instruções pode falhar, mas que as outras devem ser executadas. Esse código é bastante eficiente uma vez que ele não processa nada a mais caso nenhuma exceção ocorra.

Comment: Obrigado Danilo, me ajudou muito, eu sempre evito repetição de código mas nesse caso será necessário !

Comment: Caso o numero de variáveis não seja conhecido ou seja muito grande você pode colocar o bloco `try catch` dentro de um loop que itera sobre elas.

Comment: Esta resposta é péssima.

Comment: LINQ, uma critica mais construtiva me ajudaria a melhorar.