# Quais os impactos do uso excessivo do Try/Except (tratamento de exceções)?

Tags: python, exceção

Eu crio bastante programas com interface gráfica e bastante interação com o usuário. Eu sempre exagero no `try`/`except`. Quais os impactos do uso excessivo?

Comment: Relacionadas: [Exceções consomem muito processamento. Verdade ou lenda?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5888/5878) | [Melhor maneira de lidar com Exceptions](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13303/5878) | [Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/5878)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em Python a cultura é deixar o erro acontecer e depois tratar, então meio que não tem muita escolha no que já existe e provavelmente em bibliotecas de terceiros que seguem a mesma filosofia. Você poderia fazer diferente nas suas coisas.

Geralmente há perda de performance, mas Python não é a linguagem da performance. E em Python o custo nem é tão alto assim porque ele tem um modelo de exceção simplificado. O custo ocorre até mesmo se não usar nada, o prejuízo já está feito você capturando ou não. E claro, se o erro acontecerá você tem que capturar.

Eu ainda acho que se puder evitar o erro antes de ocorrer acho vantajoso fazê-lo.

Um dos problemas de abusar disso é que exceção é um `goto` que você sequer sabe para onde vai. Isto desestrutura o código, não é tão fácil fazer certo, a não ser que saiba organizar muito bem. Aí a exceção seria, em teoria, menos necessária.

Tenho aprendido coisas novas de Python e estou achando que este é "o menor" dos problemas nela. Eu ainda não abusaria, mas não é um crime capital.

Não vi código, não vi exemplo do que é exagero. Se for exagero mesmo o código vai ficando convoluto e isto nunca é bom. Se usa no lugar de um simples `if` está complicado o código usando o mecanismo errado. Tudo o que você usa tem que ser justificado, se você não sabe porque usou, e é uma justificativa válida, não use. Melhor fazer errado por omitir algo que não sabe usar do que errar porque usou algo sem saber porque.

Um problema maior é abusar da captura sem sentido. Se capturar erros que não sabe tratar obviamente que está só fazendo de conta que tem cuidado. Provavelmente piorará a experiência do usuário deixando de fazer o que precisa ou fazendo de forma genérica algo que é específico. Imagina seu usuário recebendo uma mensagem "deu erro!". A orelha da sua mãe esquentará.