# Qual a função do "try" e do "except"?

Tags: python, exceção

Alguém poderia me responder o que significa o parâmetro `try:` e o `except`?

Estou precisando fazer um programa e estou com uma dúvida sobre isto.

Comment: Conhece o conceito de exceção?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/314111/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%c3%a7%c3%a3o?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Answer (score 21, accepted):

O `try/except` serve para tratamento de exceções.

Exceção é quando uma coisa não ocorre da forma como foi planejada. Pode-se dizer que os programas tem um fluxo normal, e um fluxo excepcional que são as exceções.

A sintaxe é

```
try:
    código a tentar
except AlgumaExcecao:
    código a executar no caso da exceção
else:
    código a executar caso não ocorra exceção em try
finally:
    código que é executado sempre, independente de haver uma exceção em andamento ou não
```

As funções do python já sobem exceções automaticamente quando algo acontece, como por exemplo se tentar abrir um arquivo e ele não existir:

```
try:
    f = open('arquivo')
except OSError:
    print('Nao deu pra abrir o arquivo')
else:
    print('Arquivo aberto!')
```

Você mesmo pode subir exceções no seu código, para notificar o usuário das suas funções de algum comportamento excepcional

```
class DeuProblema(Exception): pass

def faz_alguma_coisa():
    ...
    if ...:
        raise DeuProblema()
    ...
```

Daí quem está usando:

```
try:
    faz_alguma_coisa()
except DeuProblema:
    tenta_outra_coisa()
```

Um outro uso muito comum é ter certeza que um certo código vai rodar:

```
d = abre_banco_de_dados() # precisa ser fechado
try:
    ...
finally:
    d.close() # garante que o banco será fechado mesmo em caso de erro
```

Pra finalizar, uma dica importante. **Não use `except` puro** desta forma:

```
try:
    ...
except:  # pega qualquer exceção (EVITE!)
    ...
```

Esse tipo de construção esconde todo e qualquer erro tornando muito difícil desenvolver o programa, porque os erros serão silenciados. Além disso pode pegar exceções que você não quer capturar como por exemplo `KeyboardInterrupt` ou `MemoryError`. Ao invés disso sempre passe a exceção que quer pegar, ou use `Exception` para pegar a maioria das exceções.

```
try:
    ...
except ValueError:  # pega somente ValueError
    ...
except Exception:  # não pega MemoryError, SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt
    log.exception()
    raise # sempre suba novamente a exceção não tratada, 
          # para que seja visível
```

Answer (score 4):

A ideia do try except é testar pontos críticos do código, ou seja, lugares que onde há grande possibilidade de erros.

São muito utilizados em leitura de arquivos ou dados de entrada do usuário. Por exemplo, você deseja que o usuário digite um inteiro para realizar uma operação matemática, caso ele digite uma string, a operação não funcionará.

```
def div(a,b):
    try:
        x = a/b
        return x
    except:
        return "Nao foi possivel realizar a operacao"
```

Ao chamar a função desta maneira, o retorno será um valor inteiro(no caso, 4)

```
div(20,5)
```

Quando chamar por

```
div('a','b')
```

O retorno será a mensagem **Nao foi possivel realizar a operacao**

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi responder como complemento (por isso não vou ex0licar o mecanismo) porque uma das respostas usa o mecanismo de maneira que funciona, mas é equivocada. Quando você tem dados que podem ser erros de programação o correto é o uso do `assert` e não da exceção.

Mesmo que fosse um dado que pode variar de acordo com a execução ainda o correto seria usar um `if` e não deixar a estourar a exceção. Mas o exemplo da resposta que deixa vir tipos ou valores errados só sabe que veio errado, não sabe em que condições, então é erro de programação, e só o `assert` é o mais adequado, mesmo que outra forma funcione, não é assim que se programa em códigos robustos.

Obviamente que se está fazendo um *script*, ou se o cenário é de um programador que cuida de tudo e sabe muito bem o que está fazendo é possível não usar o `assert`, tanto quanto pode deixar sem tratar exceção em casos assim.

Eu dei uma [resposta sobre o `assert`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/568316/101), já que lá também induz o uso dele equivocadamente.

Você não é obrigado fazer o código o mais perfeito possível, mas quando se ensina qual é o correto não pode ensinar errado. Se não fizer o jeito mais robusto é ok, desde que a pessoa saiba o que está fazendo, mas se quer a robustez garantida precisa fazer da forma mais correta possível.

O exemplo da pergunta aceita aqui não é dos melhores mas está correto (do `open()` é bem correto e o melhor motivo para usar um `try/except`, o problema é o exemplo posterior que induz ao uso da [exceção para controle de fluxo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101)).

Aproveito para dizer que não gosto do uso do `else`, ainda que não seja errado. Porque o que ele executa pode estar dentro do `try`, e será executado se não der a exceção.

Não deixe de ver [Quais os impactos do uso excessivo do Try/Except (tratamento de exceções)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/314111/101) e ou mesmo [tudo sobre exceções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o?sort=votes&pageSize=50).

Entender como usar bem o mecanismo é mais importante que só saber o que o mecanismo faz.