# Problemas no try (Python)

Tags: python, sintaxe

Quando uso o try e coloco 3 operações, se a primeira dá errado ele já passa pro except. Tem alguma maneira de "melhorar" isso fazendo com que ele pule para a próxima ação? Não da pra fazer um código onde tem try em toda instrução.

Comment: para você não receber pontos negativos, melhore ao máximo sua pergunta, dê exemplos, tentativas, demonstre o erro, fazer uma boa formatação em suas perguntas é essencial para ter votos positivos e também para os usuários te ajudarem!

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível o `try` continuar na próxima linha, depois de um erro, pelo simples motivo de que a linguagem não tem como adivinhar o que fazer depois de um erro.
O programador descreve o comportamento depois de um erro na cláusula `except`.

Se você tivesse dado um exemplo do que quer, ficaria mais fácil ilustrar - mas deve ser bem difícil dar um exemplo disso, já que nem faz sentido no mundo real: em Python, bem como em outras linguagens imperativas, o programa é executado de forma sequêncial - uma linha depende das linhas que rodaram antes dela no mesmo bloco (função, laço, etc...) se algo deu errado nas linhas anteriores, a linguagem não tem como adivinhar o que fazer a seguir (mesmo que o que você queira seja sempre ignorar o erro).

Você não deu nenhuma dica do tipo de programa que está tentando fazer - então também não é possível dar muitas sugestões do que você pode fazer para: ou não precisar de uma cláusula `try...except` a cada linha, ou a cada duas três linhas, ou, como refatorar o seu código de forma que um padrão que repita instruções críticas depois de um erro seja re-escrito com blocos `try/except` que sejam reutilizáveis.

Essa segunda coisa - refatorar para um try/except ser usado em várias situações, pode ser usada dentro de um `while` por exemplo - ou, dentro de uma função que receba "o que perguntar" e "o que fazer com a resposta" - então, em vez de, para cada questão você ter um bloco:

```
try:
    print("Pergunta...")
    resposta_bruta = input("...")
    resposta_tratada = float(resposta_bruta)
except TypeError:
    print("Por favor, entre uma resposta numérica...")
try:
    print("Pergunta 2...")
    resposta2_bruta = input("...")
    resposta2_tratada = resposta_bruta.split()[1]
except IndexError:
    print("Por favor, entre uma resposta com pelo menos um espaço...")
```

perceba que (1) a  linguagem não tem como adivinhar o que você quer fazer se der erro - se quer repetir, ou passar pra próxima pergunta, e (2) essa forma linear não permite nem a repetição da pergunta em caso de erro (a não ser que você repita o `input` dentro do próprio `except`, mas aí se a resposta continuar incorreta, você tem que colocar outro `try/except` dento do except, ad infinitum.

Se você em vez disso faz uma função que receba como parâmetros o que muda de uma pergunta pra outra, a própria função pode fazer não só a captura do erro, como também repetir a pergunta se algo der errado:

```
def pergunta(texto, transformacao, erro_esperado, mensagem):
    while True:
        print(texto)
        resp_bruta = input()
        try:
             resp = transformacao(resp_bruta)
        except erro_esperado:
             print(mensagem)
        else:
             # Cláusula "else" do "try/except",  só é executada se
             # não ocorreu nenhum erro
             break  # Este comando encerra o "while True"

        return resp

pergunta("Entre com a medida", float, TypeError, "por favor, digite um número para a medida")
pergunta("Bla bla bla", lambda x: x.split()[1], IndexError, "por favor, inclua pelo menos um espaço")
...
```

Pronto, agora seu programa chama essa função para cada pergunta - só há um "try/except" no programa todo, mesmo que ele tenha 100 perguntas, e mais ainda, está codificado o que deve ser feito em caso de erro (re-apresentar a pergunta).

Na pergunta você sugere "três operações": vocẽ pode usar a mesma ideia, e executar as operações em si dentro de uma função que receba a operação como parâmetro - basta aproveitar a capacidade da linguagem de passar uma função como parâmetro - e , se for uma única expressão, ela pode ser como uma função lambda, como fiz no exemplo acima.(O mesmo padrão funciona, você só não precisa incluir o "while True" para retentativa. Mas perceba que no caso de falha, a função vai ter que retornar algum valor que vai ficar na sua variável, de qualquer forma - não é possível simplesmente "ignorar o erro"  e deixar a variável indefinida.

Então, se sua estrutura onde você não quer deixar três blocos de "try/except" for assim:

```
try:
   op1 = <expressão que realiza cálculos e pode dar erro>
   op2 = <expressão que realiza cálculos e pode dar erro>
   op3 = <expressão que realiza cálculos e pode dar erro>
except ...:
   ...
```

dá para fazer:

```
def reactor(operacao, default=None):
    try:
        return operacao()
    except Exception:
        return default

op1 = reactor(lambda: <expressão que realiza cálculos e pode dar erro>)
op2 = reactor(lambda: <expressão que realiza cálculos e pode dar erro>)
op3 = reactor(lambda: <expressão que realiza cálculos e pode dar erro>)
```

Perceba que a linguagem tem características de introspecção tão poderoasas que até seria possível criar um decorador que modificasse uma função automaticamente para ela ter automaticamente um `try/except` em volta de cada linha - e ignorar qualquer erro e continuar na próxima linha. Só que isso não faria sentido - por que no final das contas, no final de uma função, se algum erro ocorreu, a resposta da função não está correta.

Answer (score 1):

@RetroNietzsche Acredito que deva ser sua sintax que esteja errado, tentei reproduzir o seu problema e não aconteceu comigo:

```py
try:
    pergunta = input('Quantos anos tem? ')
    if pergunta == 'aaa':
        print('Resposta inválida: aaa')
    if pergunta == 'bbb':
        print('Resposta inválida: bbb')
    if pergunta == 'ccc':
        print('Resposta inválida: ccc')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Processo interrompido!')
```

É um exemplo bem simples, mas acredito que deve lhe servir de exemplo.

---

A ideia do `try, except` é testar pontos críticos do código, ou seja, lugares que onde há grande possibilidade de erros.

Seguindo o que você disse, acredito que não tenha como, pois a cada erro terá de ter uma except

```py
try:
    print(oi)
except:
    print('1º erro')

try:
    print('oi')
except:
    print('2º erro')

try:
    print(OI)
except:
    print('3º erro')

try:
    print('OI')
except:
    print('4º erro')
```

> Estrutura do tratamento de erro:

```py
try:
    código a tentar
except AlgumaExcecao:
    código a executar no caso da exceção
else:
    código a executar caso não ocorra exceção em try
finally:
    código que é executado sempre, independente de haver uma exceção em andamento ou não
```

Neste [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316516/qual-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-try-e-do-except) você encontra um pouco mais de informação e exemplos.

Comment: Magno, cara, iae ! Acho que não fui muito claro.

Comment: try:
 print(oi)
 print('oi')
 print(OI)
 print('OI')
except Exception as e:
 print(e)

Vai dar pau logo na segunda linha, acusando erro de variável não definida. Ele não vai printar "oi" e "OI", por exemplo. Quero saber se tem como "otimizar" o try pra durante um bloco de instruções, se uma estiver incorreta, ele tentar efetuar a próxima.

Comment: @RetroNietzsche entendi o que quis dizer agora, editei minha resposta, dê uma olhada com calma, possa ser que tenha algum outro usuário que saiba mais informações para te passar.

Comment: Mas para isso edite sua `pergunta` pois isso irá ajudar o pessoal a entender melhor sua dúvida, dê exemplos, use o poder do Markdown para editar seu post!

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a estrutura que esteja citando, possa ser algo como:

```
def acao(n):
    if n == 2:
        raise ValueError('n == 2')

try:
    acao(1)
    acao(2)
    acao(3)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Onde a função `acao` com parâmetro `n=2`, dispara uma exceção.

> O **tratamento de exceção**, na ciência da computação, é o mecanismo responsável pelo tratamento da ocorrência de **condições que alteram o fluxo normal da execução de programas de computadores**. <sup>[1](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tratamento_de_exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o)</sup>

Ou seja, pensando em controle de fluxo, o tratamento de exceção, **desvia o fluxo normal de execução**.

Como se o código acima pudesse ser representado:

```
acao = lambda n: n != 2
if acao(1):
  if acao(2):
     acao(3)
```

Creio que deseje um **fluxo contínuo**, onde `acao(3)` seja executado independente do resultado de `acao(2)`: `acao(1); acao(2); acao(3);`

Falando especificamente do primeiro exemplo, creio que uma boa solução seja um [wrapper para a função](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function) como:

```
def safe_acao(n):
    try:
        acao(n)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return True

sucedidos = list(map(safe_acao, [1, 2, 3]))
```

Pensando em um ***catcher geral***, onde todas as exceções poderiam ser direcionadas, o mesmo não é possível em Python,  mas muitas formas fazendo uso dos [decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators) podem ser encontradas, uma delas até mais parecido com uma [brincadeira](https://github.com/ajalt/fuckitpy). <sup>[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860705/how-to-ignore-all-potential-exceptions-in-python)</sup> <sup>[6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572288/general-decorator-to-wrap-try-except-in-python)</sup> <sup>[7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39905390/how-to-auto-wrap-function-call-in-try-catch)</sup>

Por isso, lembrem-se, **as exceções são fundamentais, bem como seu correto tratamento**. Todo e qualquer sistema está sujeito a elas, já que seus recursos são limitados (e.g. memória, disco, ...). <sup>[8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety)</sup>

Vale aqui citar a abordagem **EAFP** (É mais fácil pedir perdão do que permissão), em contraste à **LBYL** (Olhe antes de pular), mas não vou entrar em detalhes. <sup>[9](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python#Tratamento_de_exce%C3%A7%C3%B5es)</sup>

Das diversas maneiras, dê preferência a uma que faça uso de `logging`, como por exemplo: https://gist.github.com/diosmosis/1148066

Ainda, me chamou a atenção o uso do [suppress da contextlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress), conforme [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572288/general-decorator-to-wrap-try-except-in-python/53800868#53800868).