# Como definir quais os inputs serão aceitos pelo codigo?

Tags: python, string, lista, variáveis, input

Tenho um código em que conforme o usuário for inserindo dados, quero criar uma lista que será usada para operações posteriormente. O input de saída seria a tecla `"f"` que interrompe a estrutura de repetição e dá início as operações com a lista.

Minha duvida é como eu faço para que se o usuário não tenha digitado um número seja ele `float` ou `int` ou a tecla `"f"`, gere uma mensagem e que esse valor não entre no lista como string ?

Exemplo: No código abaixo, eu consigo chegar aonde eu queria mas se eu digitar qualquer valor diferente de número ou da tecla `"f"`, a lista será gerada de qualquer maneira com os valores indesejados dentro dela.

```
list = []
number = -1

while number != 'f':
    number = (input())
    list.append(number)

    if number == 'f':
        list.remove('f') 
        break

print(list)
```

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar.

Comment: Depende do que vc quer aceitar como entrada válida. Se usar `float` (como uma das respostas sugeriu), ele também vai aceitar strings como `'inf'` e `'nan'` (respectivamente se tornam "infinito" e "not a number"), além de `1_000.123_4` que vira `1000.1234` - [veja](https://ideone.com/S8ywhz). Se quiser aceitar somente números em determinado formato, aí a regex (sugerida em outra resposta) restringirá mais os valores possíveis.

Answer (score 2):

Basta utilizar um [`try-except`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/316516/157404) para tentar converter a string em um `float`.  Caso não seja possível realizar a conversão, será gerado um `ValueError` e isso significará que o valor inserido não era numérico.

Veja abaixo como ficaria o código:

```
number_list = [] # Lembre-se que o nome "list" já existe em Python.

while True:
    number = input("Digite um número: ")
    if number.lower() == "f": break

    try:
        number = float(number) # Converte para float
        number_list.append(number)
    except:
        print("Você deve digitar um valor numérico.")

print(number_list)
```

Comment: MUITOOOOOOOOO OBRIGADO !!!
 salvou meu dia mano, vlw mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução alternativa seria criar uma [expressão regular](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) para validar a entrada como um número inteiro ou um número em formato de ponto flutuante e então usar o método [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) para obter o valor literal da entrada.
Apesar do nome `literal_eval()` lembrar do infame `eval()`, o método `literal_eval()` é seguro pois não permite analisar expressões complexas(não há injeção de código) ele é um avaliador específico para literais e analisa `strings`, `bytes`, `números`, `tuplas`, `listas`, `dicionários`, `sets`, `booleanos`, and `None`

A expressão regular eu peguei pronta dessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/385597/11379709) no [Stack Overflow EN](https://stackoverflow.com/) e adaptei ao código:

```
from re import compile; # Para compilar a expressão regular
from ast import literal_eval; #Para avaliar o literal

result = [] #Lista de resultados

#Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/385597/11379709
re_float = compile("""(?x)
   ^
      [+-]?\s*      #  Que inicialmente, corresponda a um sinal opcional seguido ou não de espaço(s)
      (             
          \d+       # Ou corresponde a um ou mais digitos...
          (\.\d*)?  # ...seguido(s) ou não de um ponto e zero ou mais digitos
         |\.\d+     # Ou um ponto seguido de dígitos
      )
      ([eE][+-]?\d+)?  # Podendo ou não ter a notação exponencial
   $""")

while True:
    print("Digite um número ou f para sair:")
    entrada = input()
    if entrada.upper() == 'F': break; #Se a entrada for f ou F abandona o laço
    entrada = re_float.fullmatch(entrada) #Tenta validar a entrada como numérico
    if entrada: 
      #Se houver exito na validação
      result.append(literal_eval(entrada.group(0))) #Adiciona o valor literal da entrada na lista de resultados
    else:
      #Caso não haja exito na validação
      print("Entrada inválida...")   

print(result)
```

Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/Inputs)

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou atualizar o codigo. Essas informções foram muito uteis.