# Custo da utilização de exceções com PHP e ValueObjects

Tags: php, desempenho, exceção, ddd

Sempre ouvi dizer que exceções tem um alto custo de processamento e tornam a aplicação lenta.

No caso especifico do PHP, o quanto podemos abusar da utilização de exceções?

No caso de validação de dados em Value Objects por exemplo, faz sentido a utilização do throw para lançar exceptions quando os valores recebidos não satisfazem a regra de negócio? Ou seria melhor a implementação de uma lista de violações? Digo isso em termos de performance.

Agradeço antecipadamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se estiver usando em *Exception* para o que ele deve ser usando, ou seja, exceções, não tem porque se preocupar com perfomance. A ideia é, tratar o código ao máximo para evitar erros (testar objetos null, por exemplo) e, caso algo inesperado ou que não foi mitigado aconteça, ai sim disparar um *Exception*.

No caso da sua pergunta, você está pensando no cenário da validação de um objeto de negócio e disparar um *Exception* caso não esteja válido. Isso o @Maniero já colocou bem na resposta dele, se é uma regra de validação, não deveria disparar um *Exception*, e se assim fosse, você deveria criar um exception customizado para cada tipo de validação.

Não adianta nada disparar um exception e o chamador ficar sabendo que "algo deu errado na validação"!
Ah, mas tem uma mensagem, algo como "CPF inválido", mas vamos avaliar mensagem? Não parece bem, ainda mais porque as mensagens podem mudar... deveria disparar um exceção customizada, uma classe que estenda `Exception` e disparar, algo como:

```
class ClienteCPFInvalidoExceptionextends Exception { ... }


if (!CPFValido($cliente)) {
   throw ClienteCPFInvalidoException();
}
```

E depois usar um `catch` específico:

```
catch(ClienteCPFInvalidoException$e){ ... }
```

Mas ai teria de criar um tipo para cada validação, para que quem executar o código possa "pegar" a exception correta e saber como tratar, mas ai, quanto de código teria de implementar?

Talvez seja mais prático **nesse caso da sua pergunta**, como você mesmo mencionou uma lista de violações e não se preocupar com o custo de um *Exception*

Answer (score 4):

Isso vale muito mais para linguagens que se preocupam com performance, não é o caso de PHP. Se quer performance procure outra linguagem.

Nunca devemos abusar de exceções por questões semânticas, não por causa da performance. Se a situação não é excepcional, ou seja, se não é uma exceção ao que normalmente acontece, é bastante óbvio, porém extremamente ignorado pela maioria dos programadores, alguns até com argumentos, que o mecanismo de exceção não deveria ser usado, ele passaria ser um controle de fluxo normal.

Validação nunca deveria gerar exceção porque o próprio nome está dizendo, você está querendo saber se é válido ou não, ser inválido não é uma exceção, é algo que é esperado acontecer.

Entretanto eu sei que muitas implementações de DDD incentivam o uso de exceções nesses caso, um dos motivos de eu abominar DDD. Pregar fazer o uso semântico errado já mostra como a técnica não é boa. Mas também acho muito estranho usar DDD em PHP.

Eu adotaria um mecanismo de validação e não de exceção para fazer validação, independente a questão da performance em qualquer linguagem e qualquer situação de validação.

Nem vou considerar que as pessoas capturam exceção de forma errada quase sempre, porque eu não acho que algo deva deixar de ser usado porque as pessoas não usam certo, embora esse argumento tem uma certa força quando se trata de exceção.

Perguntas relacionadas:

- [Exceções consomem muito processamento. Verdade ou lenda?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5888/101)
- [Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101)
- [É uma boa prática lançar exceção nesses casos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101)
- [Exceções devem ser usadas para controle de fluxo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101)